# Como corrigir o EntityValidationErrors

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Oi, preciso de uma ajuda. Após compilar o meu projeto estou recebendo um erro:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Já descobri que esse erro é ocasionado na execução do método savechanges. Depurei o meu código e esta tudo certo até a execução do método. ao revisar o meu código encontrei algo como nas figuras abaixo:

[image: imagem 1]
[image: imagem 2]

Analisei o meu código mas não consegui encontrar o local exato de onde está o problema.

Gostaria de saber se  existe algum recurso no Visual Studio que possa me direcionar para o local exato onde está ocorrendo o erro? Ou há um local que indique onde está o erro?

Segue abaixo um trecho do código onde ocorre o erro.

```
public void inserirAcao(float cpf, string codigo, string empresa, string tipo, DateTime data, string hora, double abertura,
                             double maxima, double minima, double media, double fechamento, double fechamento_anterior,
                             int volume, int volume_financeiro, int negocio, double oferta_de_compra, double oferta_de_venda,
                             int quantidade_ofertada_compra, int quantidade_fertada_venda, double variação, string status, string fase)
    {
        try
        {
            validaInserirAcao(cpf, codigo, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior,
                              volume, volume_financeiro, negocio, oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra,
                              quantidade_fertada_venda, variação, status, fase);
            // instancia o banco
            bancotccEntities bco = new bancotccEntities();
          //  bco.Database.Connection.Open();
            // cria um objeto para receber os dados das ações
            acao obj = new acao();

            //popula o objeto 
            obj.cpf = cpf;
            obj.codigo = codigo;
            obj.empresa = empresa;
            obj.tipo = tipo;
            obj.data = Convert.ToDateTime(data);
            obj.hora = hora;
            obj.abertura = abertura;
            obj.maxima = maxima;
            obj.minima = minima;
            obj.medio = media;
            obj.fechamento = fechamento;
            obj.f_anterior = fechamento_anterior;
            obj.volume = volume;
            obj.v_financeiro = volume_financeiro;
            obj.negocio = negocio;
            obj.ofcompra = oferta_de_compra;
            obj.ofvenda = oferta_de_venda;
            obj.qtd_of__compra = quantidade_ofertada_compra;
            obj.qtd_of_venda = quantidade_fertada_venda;
            obj.variacao = Convert.ToString(variação);
            obj.status = Convert.ToInt32(status);
            obj.fase = fase;

            // adiciona o objeto ao banco

           // bco.AddToacao(obj);
            bco.acao.Add(obj);
            // salva as informações o banco de dados
            bco.SaveChanges();
           // bco.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crie no seu `context` o seguinte:

```
public class MeuProjetoContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entidade do tipo \"{0}\" no estado \"{1}\" tem os seguintes erros de validação:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Erro: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    ...
    // Coloque aqui as declarações de DbSets e outros.
}
```

Você poderá ver as mensagens de erro no console ou colocando um breakpoint dentro do `catch`.

Comment: Não esta reconhecendo o DbEntityValidationException

Comment: @user9090 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx