# Erro ao consumir método de um web service rest

Tags: c#, web-service, rest, wcf

Criei um método onde o meu parceiro além de receber dados proveniente de nossa base, também nos envia. Bem, isso estava funcionando bem. Aí descobri que faltou um campo. Adicionei esse campo na interface e também no método. Bem, não sei se foi isso ou outra coisa, mas não funcionou mais. O erro é esse extraído do log do servidor:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at SuporteTecnicoWS.SuporteTecnicoServiceWS.recebeDadosParceiro(String _idparceiro, String _numos, String _datavisita, String _dataagendamento, String _dataaberturaos, String _datafechamentotarefa, String _datafechamentoos, String _statusos, String _statuspdv, String _tecnico, String _tarefa_fechada) at SyncInvokerecebeDadosParceiro(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet) 
  SerializedException <Exception><ExceptionType>System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.</Message><StackTrace> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at SuporteTecnicoWS.SuporteTecnicoServiceWS.recebeDadosParceiro(String _idparceiro, String _numos, String _datavisita, String _dataagendamento, String _dataaberturaos, String _datafechamentotarefa, String _datafechamentoos, String _statusos, String _statuspdv, String _tecnico, String _tarefa_fechada) at SyncInvokerecebeDadosParceiro(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp;amp; outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at SuporteTecnicoWS.SuporteTecnicoServiceWS.recebeDadosParceiro(String _idparceiro, String _numos, String _datavisita, String _dataagendamento, String _dataaberturaos, String _datafechamentotarefa, String _datafechamentoos, String _statusos, String _statuspdv, String _tecnico, String _tarefa_fechada) at SyncInvokerecebeDadosParceiro(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp;amp; outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString></Exception> 
  AppDomain /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/WebServiceSuporteTecnico
```

Essa é minha interface

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET", // Tipo de request
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, // Identação do retorno
            UriTemplate = "pegastatusparceiro/{_idparceiro}/{_numos}/{_datavisita}/{_dataagendamento}/{_dataaberturaos}/{_datafechamentotarefa}/{_datafechamentoos}/{_statusos}/{_statuspdv}/{_tecnico}/{_tarefa_fechada}" // Url do serviço, onde cada {} = parametro
            )]//Filter para tratar REST
        T_OsParceiro recebeDadosParceiro(string _idparceiro, string _numos, string _datavisita, string _dataagendamento, string _dataaberturaos,
                                                string _datafechamentotarefa, string _datafechamentoos, string _statusos, string _statuspdv,
                                                string _tecnico, string _tarefa_fechada);
```

E esse o meu método, pois ele só faz gravar no BD

```
public T_OsParceiro recebeDadosParceiro(string _idparceiro, string _numos, string _datavisita, string _dataagendamento, string _dataaberturaos,
                                                string _datafechamentotarefa, string _datafechamentoos, string _statusos, string _statuspdv,
                                                string _tecnico, string _tarefa_fechada)
        {
            using (WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities())
            {
                T_OsParceiro parceiro = new T_OsParceiro();

                parceiro.IDTarefaParceiro = Convert.ToInt32(_idparceiro);
                parceiro.NumOs = Convert.ToInt32(_numos);
                parceiro.DataVisita = Convert.ToDateTime(_datavisita);
                parceiro.DataAgendamento = Convert.ToDateTime(_dataagendamento);
                parceiro.DataAbertura = Convert.ToDateTime(_dataaberturaos);
                parceiro.DataFechamentoTarefa = Convert.ToDateTime(_datafechamentotarefa);
                parceiro.DataFechamento = Convert.ToDateTime(_datafechamentoos);
                parceiro.StatusOS = _statusos;
                parceiro.StatusPDV = _statuspdv;
                parceiro.Tecnico = _tecnico;
                parceiro.Is_Tarefa_Fechada = Convert.ToBoolean(_tarefa_fechada);

                db.T_OsParceiro.Add(parceiro);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return parceiro;
            }
        }
```

O erro dá no SaveChanges(); O que eu acrescentei foi: `_datafechamentoos`
Olhando o log do erro sei que o problema está na minha entidade. Só não sei o porque está dando esse erro, pois o que foi acrescentado, na minha opinião, não fez nada de diferente do que já existia. Antes tudo funcionou, inclusive o teste foi feito pelo Web Service com o parceiro consumindo o WS ou API(REST). O log pede para eu ver isso: `'EntityValidationErrors'` , mas não sei como fazer.

Não sei se isso é o problema, mas quando coloquei tudo no watch, e fui abrindo cada item, lá no Entry >> Entity, mostra os atributos da minha entidade, ok? Bem, eu possuo um campo Identity chamado IDOsParceiro, ele deveria estar com 11, pois eu o max value de IdOsParceiro é 10 e lá estava com 0. Bem, acho que no momento do SaveChanges(), creio que o Identity já deveria ser disparado, certo? Essa foi a observação que fiz, que achei diferente.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, modifique seu `db.SaveChanges` seguindo o roteiro dessa resposta para poder ver os erros: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors/17648#17648

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar conforme vc me enviou, Cigano. O base.SaveChanges() dá erro

Comment: A ideia é cair dentro da Exception pra que você possa ver os erros, usando breakpoints e as janelas de Watch.

Answer (score 1):

Com debug não se tem bug,. Descobri o problema. Como eu gero minhas entidades pelo ERWin, eu fiz um entidade com alguns campos string de tamanho tal. Precisei alterar e o fiz pelo ERWin, por alguma razão ele não atualizou o novo tamanho e o erro espirrou. Resolvido.

Comment: Mas veja o seguinte. Havia encontrado o erro e é esse mesmo. Fui no banco e alterei o tamanho do campo de 18 para 255. Bem, removi o edmx e criei outro. Fiz um insert pelo BD e ok. Porem pela aplicação(WS) continua o erro The field StatusOS must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '18'. Não é mais varchar(18), mas sim varchar(255) e continua com os 18. Já dei um build e nada.