# Como interceptar exceções quando se trabalha com o Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, exceção

Quero fazer o tratamento dos erros retornados pelo Entity Framework.

Neste exemplo estou forçando a inserção de um registro duplicado (Nome já existente no banco sendo que a coluna da tabela está configurada como uma *Unique Index*):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorization(Roles = "Editar")]
public ActionResult Gravar(Domain.Cidade obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try {
            if (new App.Cidade().Gravar(obj))
                return RedirectToAction("Listar");
        }
        catch (SqlException e) {
            TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
        }
        catch (EntitySqlException e) {
            TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
        }
        catch (EntityException e) {
            TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
        }
    }
    return View("Cadastro", obj);
}
```

Veja que separei em três tipos básicos de tratamento de erros: `SqlException`, `EntitySqlException` e o `System.Exception`.

Mas a exceção retornada esta sempre caindo no tratamento para `System.Exception`.

Meu método gravar:

```
public bool Gravar(Domain.Cidade obj)
{
    var record = context.Cidades.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == obj.Id);
    if (record == null)
        context.Cidades.Add(obj);
    else
        context.Entry(record).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);

    context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

Como faço para obter o retorno correto do tipo de Exceção?

Answer (score 6):

Vou te dar uma resposta que não responde diretamente o que você deseja mas que vai ajudar você e outras pessoas para outros problemas com exceções.

Primeiro começamos conceituando corretamente as coisas.

> Mas a exceção retornada esta sempre caindo no tratamento para `System.Exception`

Uma exceção não é retornada, ela é lançada. Pode parecer bobagem mas conceituar corretamente ajuda a entender o problema e achar uma solução.

Uma exceção não pode ser acessada sem que ela seja explicitamente capturada através de um `catch`. Então vamos refazer a frase:

> A exceção capturada é sempre `System.Exception` e não uma mais específica

Se você quer capturar uma exceção mais específica, por que está capturando a exceção mais geral de todas?

Não conheço bem o EF mas de acordo com a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21281/101) parece que você está querendo capturar a `DbUpdateException`. E você poderia ter descoberto isto por conta própria.

Há dois requisitos para que um programador usar um `catch`:

- saber qual exceção deseja capturar
- conseguir fazer alguma coisa útil com a exceção, possivelmente recuperando a situação.

Fora o uso em um dos primeiros métodos executados (primeiros níveis, talvez o `Main`) e basicamente para *logar* a falha, é quase 100% certo que capturar a `Exception` é um erro.

- Por que deseja capturar especificamente uma `Exception`? Dizer que é porque não sabe qual é a exceção correta é exatamente o melhor argumento para **não** capturá-la.
- E o que você pode fazer para se recuperar de uma exceção qualquer indefinida? Muito provavelmente nada.

Quando o programa captura uma exceção mais geral está escondendo um problema ao invés de solucioná-lo. O abuso de `try/catch` parece ser uma tendência, especialmente a captura de `Exception`. Por alguma razão os programadores adotaram a crença que quanto mais `catch` existe no programa, menos *bugs* ele terá. E é exatamente o oposto que ocorre. Vou repetir: **capturar uma exceção geral impede que o programa consiga resolver um problema específico**.

No seu problema você tentou capturar `SqlException`, `EntitySqlException`, `EntityException`, e elas não foram lançadas, então outra exceção foi lançada e como qualquer exceção é derivada de `Exception`, caiu ali.

Comece resolver o problema **tirando esta captura e deixe o programa quebrar, aí você vai saber qual foi a exceção que causou o problema**.

Você **pode** até ser surpreendido e descobrir que o problema era em outro lugar que você não imaginava, que era um erro de programação, ou ser falta de memória (que pode ocorrer mesmo tendo memória suficiente, mas isto é outro assunto). Você simplesmente não sabe o que está causando o problema e está capturando uma falha possivelmente não relacionada com o que você está fazendo.

Vamos ver se deu para entender o que escrevi: depois que descobrir a exceção correta, deve colocar o trecho abaixo de volta no programa?

```
catch (Exception e) {
    TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/Exception.cs).

Tentei mostrar como achar a solução por seus próprios meios, assim você pode se virar em outras situações. Para entender melhor o funcionamento de exceções já respondi em outros lugares: [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101) e [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101).

Comment: Eu entendi tudo isto que você está falando. Eu gosto de dar respostas que sejam a vara de pescar. Como vai pescar é questão de cada um. Nada me causou transtorno, só queria ajudar a todos porque este é um recurso relativamente básico que há o pior entendimento em programação hoje em dia. Não estou reclamando do seu código, até porque não vou trabalhar com ele. Esta outra pergunta citada daria um post interessante. Todo mundo aprende que é melhor lançar uma exceção que **retornar** um código de erro.Lá mostra que código de erro não é o problema.O problema é o **retorna** ao invés do **lançar**.

Comment: @TremDoido eu fiz o seguinte coloque esse questionamento no META: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1531/6026

Comment: @TremDoido Na outra não consegui achar uma maneira de respondê-la do jeito que eu gosto sem sair completamente do escopo dela. Nesta aqui eu dei um jeito de ser uma resposta para sua pergunta. Lá está servindo mais de exemplo que **ter** código de erro não é problema, mas não cabe explicação, porque não é sua dúvida. Gosto de ajudar o máximo de possível de pessoas mas não posso deixar de responder de alguma forma, dando alguma forma de resolver o problema da pergunta específica. Se surgir um oportunidade que caiba uma explicação melhor sobre códigos de erro genericamente, eu posto algo.

Comment: @TremDoido tentei dar uma resposta que ajuda no outro assunto. Não está diretamente ligado, mas foi inspirado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21767/por-que-devemos-evitar-retornar-c%c3%b3digos-de-erro

Answer (score 4):

Para erros de atualizações no *Entity Framework 6+* utilize o [DbUpdateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```cs
catch (DbUpdateException e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

*Referência:*

- [DbUpdateException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode interceptar toda e qualquer exceção no seu `Controller` comum implementando um `override` para o seguinte método:

```cs
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    /* A exceção fica em filterContext.Exception */
    /* Os detalhes da execução ficam em filterContext.Exception.StackTrace */
}
```

Se você quer apenas interceptar apenas exceções do Entity Framework, siga o roteiro [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors/17648#17648).