# Como obter o tipo específico de erro retornado pelo EntityFramework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, exceção, entity-framework-6

Seguindo a pergunta: [Como interceptar exceções quando se trabalha com o Entity Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21278/como-obter-o-tipo-da-exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quando-se-trabalha-com-o-entityframework#21281)

É possível obter algum identificador de tipo de erro? Como por exemplo, Violação de Chave Primária, Inconsistência de Chave Estrangeira e, no meu caso específico, quando é uma violação de chave única.

Enfim, trabalhando com EntityFramework estou interceptando as exceções lançadas da seguinte forma:

```cs
try {
    ...
}
catch (DbUpdateException e) {
    TempData["Mensagens"] = "Ocorreu um erro enquanto ...";
}
```

**Como identificar o tipo de erro específico do EF e então poder tratar a mensagem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim:

```cs
try {
    ...
}
catch (DbUpdateException e) {
    switch (((SqlException)e.InnerException.InnerException).Number)
    {
             case 547:
                 {
                     //FK exception
                     TempData["Mensagens"] = "Chave Estrangeira";
                 }
             case 2627:
             case 2601:
                 {
                     //primary key exception
                     TempData["Mensagens"] = "Chave Primária";
                 }
             default:
                 {
                     TempData["Mensagens"] = "Erros";
                 }
    }
}
```

*Ai você coloca a mensagem de sua preferência.*

Todos os erros contidos no [MSDN Microsoft Developers - System Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

*Referência:*

- [Handle exceptions in entity framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042107/handle-exceptions-in-entity-framework-4)
- [System Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Entendi vou editar

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx olha isso ...

Comment: Sim, pelo que eu entendi sim os erros seguem um padrão, isso é bom, porque ai não depende do banco

Comment: @TremDoido, vou fazer uma pesquisa mais profunda e conversar com uma galera sobre o entity e seus exceptions se descobri coisa nova te aviso no (@)