# Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?

Tags: exceção, estilo-de-codificação

É comum dizer que deve-se evitar retornar códigos de erro em uma função quando alguma operação falha. Não é difícil perceber que códigos de erros são confusos (é um valor válido ou um erro?) e não fornecem informação relevante.

A recomendação é utilizar o lançamento de exceções ao invés de códigos de erro. Por que as exceções são melhores que o retorno de códigos de erro? Há casos onde esta solução é pior?

O título obviamente não implica que uma afirmação ou outra esteja correta. A dúvida é esta.

Comment: Prefiro retornar uma `exception`. Utilizar um `try catch` e no `catch` tratar essa `exception`, mostrando uma mensagem ao usuário, gravando o erro em um `log` no banco de dados ou arquivo texto. Acredito ser uma ótima prática de proramação utilizar `try catch`.

Comment: E de que forma você acha que responde a pergunta de forma objetiva e acrescenta algo útil além de informar o que você gosta?

Comment: Verdade........

Comment: Sendo sincero na empresa onde trabalho as aplicação são em Delphi com Firebird e não tem tratamentos de erro. Graças a isso as falhas são geralmente fáceis de ser identificadas, assim a resolução ganha tempo.

Comment: @DaniloAraujo agradeço o comentário, mas pode ser mais específico?

Comment: Pelo contrário, a "moda" hoje é retornar erros em vez de lançar exceções, algumas linguagens modernas nem possuem o mecanismo de exceção.

Comment: @epx conforme eu respondi Go, Rust e outras são linguagens que adotaram isso, mas não dá para chamar de moda., primeiro porque a adoção foi feita com consciência e não porque outros estavam fazendo, e isso é a definição de moda. Essas linguagens quebram a moda, o costumo, o etilo vigente. E essa definição errada que as pessoas usam de ser algo popular também não é moda.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Esse é mais um dos mitos que foram criados porque as pessoas decoram frases e não entendem os motivadores.

É verdade que retornar códigos de erros não costuma ser uma ideia muito boa. Mas se bem feito, se a semântica adequada para o problema for o código de erro, não há problema em fazê-lo. As linguagens vivem incentivando isto. Os maiores especialistas, incluindo os criadores das linguagens que possuem o conceito de exceções recomendam o uso de códigos de erro. Elas não fazem isto de forma tão explícita, então os demais programadores não percebem. Vamos ver alguns casos.

Há quem diga que tem alguns problemas em usar códigos de erro. Vou mostrar abaixo que isso é invenção na maior parte dos casos. Ou então a pessoa não sabe criar o mecanismo de forma adequada. Mostrarei que há utilidade para exceções, mas houve um momento que começaram abusar delas e que o jeito moderno de programar é usar códigos de erro, **quando eles são adequados**.

O fato da pessoa não saber fazer do jeito correto é que fez as pessoas acharem que essa forma não é correta. As primeiras tentativas foram mal feitas mesmo, aí procuram uma solução para outro problema ao invés de resolver esse problema. Exceções também são usadas de maneira errada o tempo todo, seja para criá-las, seja para capturá-las. Não existe mecanismo mágico que resolve o problema da pessoa não saber programar.

Todo lugar onde cabe uma exceção, cabe um outro mecanismo mais simples e feito de forma que dá as mesmas garantias da exceção, ou até melhores. O que pode acontecer é de não ser o mais conveniente, só isso. Por isso eu dou todas as opções aqui, até mesmo a exceção.

## Retorno de null

Apesar de eu não gostar do seu uso indiscriminado, o `null` está presente na maioria das linguagens. O `null` costuma funcionar como uma referência para nada e em algumas linguagens até mesmo como um valor não esperado no domínio do tipo. Ou seja, o `null` é usado para indicar que não há valor válido. Você define que uma função/método deve retornar um tipo e ela retorna outro tipo, em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica, ou retorna um estado inválido do tipo, em linguagens de tipagem estática.

O `null` é um código de erro. Não parece, mas é. É confuso porque você pode receber coisas com semânticas diferentes. Mas tem uma informação relevante. Ele diz que não há um estado válido. E é apenas isso que você precisa saber.

Mesmo os maiores proponentes do fim do `null` (eu não sou relevante no mundo da computação, mas é uma das coisas que mais desejo em uma linguagem) admitem que em muitos casos uma forma de obter uma solução semelhante é necessária, provavelmente por tipos `nullable`, `option` ou `maybe` usados opcionalmente em cima dos tipos principais.

Você não pode ignorar esse erro. Não pode usar o objeto sem decidir o que fazer com um nulo. Algumas pessoas dizem que não se pode ignorar exceções. Pode sim, o tempo todo as pessoas ignoram, mas não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso.  Quando se ignora a exceção é um erro de programação em tempo de execução, igualzinho ao mecanismo de uso do `null`.

Verificar se é nulo é igual ou menos verboso que tratar uma exceção.

De uma forma ou de outra, retornar um código de erro dessa forma é considerado aceitável. Não sou eu que está dizendo, "todo mundo" usa isto.

#### *Null Object*

Esse é um caso que pode ser usado também, mas ele tem uma tendência maior de dar algum problema já que [ele se confunde com um objeto válido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88741/101). Essa é uma alternativa que eu não usaria nunca. Ou quase, sempre pode existir alguma situação que seja adequada.

Normalmente isso é o oposto de usar o objeto como indicador de erro, é criar confusão com objeto válido e inválido.

Não estou dizendo que esse padrão seja necessariamente ruim. Digo apenas que ele não serve para indicar invalidade.

## Booleano e múltiplos retornos

Se uma função retornar mais que um valor separadamente, um deles sendo o código erro e o outro o valor efetivo que a função/método deveria retornar, parece ser aceitável também.

- Isso é possível em linguagens que permitem realmente o retorno de múltiplos valores (Python ou C# 7, por exemplo);
- ou em linguagens que permitem parâmetros passados por referência que podem ser usados para receber valores extras da função/método (quase todas as linguagens, algumas com limitações ou forma esquisita de fazer);
- ou ainda todas as outras linguagens que permitem retornar uma estrutura de dados composta de tipos variados, uma tupla, por exemplo. Também há linguagens que permitem efeito semelhante com [Union Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) que é apenas uma otimização.

Normalmente o retorno do erro é feito com um tipo booleano. Porque só o que você precisa saber é se houve erro ou não. Se não houve erro o programa sabe que pode usar o outro valor de alguma forma, caso contrário, o valor deve ser ignorado.

Com o retorno múltiplo elimina-se o problema do valor relevante se confundir com o código de erro e a única informação importante sobre o código de erro que o programa precisa é se deu erro ou não. Não precisa de nada além disto. A solução de retornar código de erro é boa.

Podemos ver no exemplo do [TryParse() do .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) uma solução assim. A criação deste método ocorreu após muita reflexão. É uma solução melhor retornar um código de erro do que lançar uma exceção.

Existem linguagens modernas que estão preferindo esta solução para a maioria dos casos. Me vem à cabeça agora [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) ([exemplo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html)) e [Go](https://golang.org/) ([exemplo](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)).

## Retorno de enumerações

Isto é uma variação da forma anterior. Também seria feito através de múltiplos retornos.

Eu não vejo muitos exemplos dele, mas por coerência não existe nenhum motivo para não usá-lo. Se você considerar que um booleano é uma enumeração que possui os membros `true` e `false`, retornar uma enumeração apenas dá informação mais granular. E muitas vezes é necessário apenas saber superficialmente qual o erro ocorrido, ou seja, saber qual é o erro, mas nada além de um indicativo simples disto. Exceção é muito pesada.

## Retorno de um código como parte do domínio esperado

Esta não é uma das melhores formas de retornar um código de erro mas se você espera que algo dê errado, que uma função não consiga o resultado que o programa espera, mas precisa comunicar isto, uma exceção pode ser um exagero. Além do problema da performance em uma situação não excepcional, há um provável acréscimo no tamanho do código para lidar com a exceção. Além disto a exceção estará criando um fluxo anormal para um dado apenas inválido.

Se ele faz parte do domínio esperado não cria um monte de tabelas de erro. Algumas pessoas não entendem isso, talvez porque leram genericamente isso em algum lugar e não entende o funcionamento do mecanismo.

#### Exemplo

Um bom exemplo são as funções/métodos que buscam a posição/índice de uma *string* dentro de outra ([`IndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_)). Elas costumam retornar um valor entre 0 e o tamanho da *string* menos um. Mas se não achar nada, o retorno é -1. Isto é um código de erro retornado. A documentação indica para você como lidar com esta situação e você deve tomar providências apropriadas no seu código como parte do fluxo normal. Seria uma loucura lançar uma exceção para algo esperado.

É possível argumentar que então deveria verificar antes se a *string* existe dentro da outra e só se ela existir é que deve procurar saber qual posição ela está, assim seria garantido que o retorno seja positivo e se isto não fosse possível, seria um erro de programação. É um argumento válido. Mas provavelmente não vale esse esforço. E não seria performático. Teria que varrer a *string* duas vezes. E dependendo da maneira como a *string* é implementada, pode haver problema de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) em ambientes concorrentes.

#### Abuso

Evidentemente que isso pode ser abusado. Um dos problemas de usá-lo é que em algum caso mal pensado, um dia um número negativo pode passar ser um valor válido de retorno.

Outro abuso é retornar -1 para um erro, -2 para outro, e assim por diante. Mas há situações que isto ainda é melhor que lançar exceções. Lembre-se que uma exceção só deve ser lançada em casos excepcionais, quando acontece algo que não é esperado. Exceção não é sinônimo de erro, de invalidade.

A boa documentação é fundamental nesses casos.

#### Em busca da perfeição sagrada

Esqueça que a programação vai ser perfeita. Depois de décadas de experiência as APIs ainda precisam ser deprecadas porque alguma coisa não foi prevista antes e programadores esquecem de fazer todo dever de casa. Não existe bala de prata que resolverá isso. Pense muito antes de tomar uma decisão, mas não deixe de usar uma solução porque alguém disse que é ruim. Você provavelmente estará apenas trocando de problema.

## Retorno de objetos com informações do erro

É outra variação que deve ser usado com múltiplos retornos. Mas tem mecanismo que pode ser usado de forma melhor ainda, como já foi falado anteriormente

Uma exceção é custosa, ela só deve ser lançada quando realmente é a melhor solução para aquele problema. Pior, ela é pouco previsível. Uma exceção é um controle de fluxo. Mas é um controle de **fluxo anormal**. É difícil ter certeza que você está tratando todas as exceções que deveria nos locais certos.

Há casos que faz mais sentido **retornar** uma classe que se parece com uma exceção mas é apenas um código de erro cheio de informação adicional que podem ser necessárias para o programa saber o que fazer. Não há confusão e há informação rica do que é o erro.

Não vejo isto ocorrendo, mas deveria. Provavelmente há pouco uso porque usam a mesma ferramenta para tudo.

#### `Result` ou derivados

Com ele o erro e o correto passa ser uma coisa só, mas sem causar confusão.

Usa-se um objeto que encapsula o objeto correto e o objeto de erro. Em alguns casos é uma união, o que economiza memória. Há casos que o objeto de erro é um simples nulo. Desta forma para acessar o objeto que é o resultado é obrigatório desencapsulá-lo do objeto opcional. Exemplo abstrato:

```
union Result<T, E> {
    Ok(T),
    Error(E),
}
```

Uma função fictícia poderia criá-lo:

```
Result<string, string> Read(string name) {
    string resultado = "";
    if (File.Open(name)) {
        foreach (linha in handler.ReadLine()) {
            resultado += linha;
        }
    } else {
        return Error("O arquivo nem foi aberto");
    }
    return Ok(resultado);
}
```

Aí para acessar o objeto:

```
var = textoLido = Read("arquivo.txt");
match textoLido {
    Error(msg) => print("Deu problema:" + msg);
    Ok(texto) => print(texto);
}
```

Obviamente que aqui não é o caso de fornecer a implementação exata, mas dá para notar que não pode usar `textoLido` de forma direta, tem tratar **obrigatoriamente**, antes de usá-lo. Dá para fazer isto na maioria das linguagens com mais ou menos conveniência.

É claro que o programador pode tratar errado, mas com exceção nem obrigado é. Só descobre quando executa e não funciona, desta forma o compilador já pega o problema.

## Lançar exceções com código de erro embutido

Aqui já muda um pouco. Obviamente não há confusão porque não há um retorno no caso de uma ocorrência de erro. A exceção é lançada e não retornada. É diferente do retorno de múltiplos valores porque não há um retorno. Uma função/método que deveria retornar algo, sequer retorna, afinal ela não é nem terminada, ela é interrompida pela exceção. É fluxo anormal. Além disto onde esta exceção será tratada pode variar bastante. A função chamadora não tem obrigação de tratar o erro. Mesmo em linguagens com `checked exceptions` o tratamento efetivo pode ser delegado para outros métodos.

Ninguém que defende o uso de exceções pode dizer que há falta de informação relevante em uma exceção bem feita. O que talvez possa ser questionado é se deveria haver códigos de erro dentro da exceção.

Os mais puristas vão dizer que ao invés de ter vários códigos de erro dentro de uma exceção, deveria ter várias exceções especializadas. Mas tudo é uma questão de semântica. Se a exceção é mais geral, se o tratamento importante é ela e não os códigos, ou seja, se o programa deve capturar a exceção um pouco mais geral mesmo, por que capturar uma mais especializada? Só para tornar o programa maior? Para ter que colocar dezenas ou centenas de `catchs` para fazer a mesma coisa na maioria deles? Acho que um exemplo explica melhor.

#### Exemplo

A pergunta [Como obter o tipo específico de erro retornado pelo EntityFramework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21283/como-obter-o-tipo-espec%C3%ADfico-de-erro-retornado-pelo-entityframework) motivou este post. Lá vemos a resposta do user6026 que a [SqlException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) possui códigos de erro. Olhando a documentação até assusta com a quantidade de [códigos de erro possíveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645603(v=sql.105)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Ninguém pode dizer que falta informações relevantes. Não dá para argumentar que o código de erro não tem significado. O número do erro é apenas uma das informações disponíveis.

Se a semântica da exceção é notificar um erro do SQL, então é isso que ela faz. Se o erro do SQL tem algo mais específico, é possível tratar de forma mais específica. Até mesmo lançar outra exceção **apenas nos casos pertinentes** como é o caso da `DbUpdateException`.

Essa é uma solução que deve ter sido muito bem pensada. Certamente não foi feita por programadores inexperientes. Eu tenho minhas dúvidas se ela é tão boa assim, mas parece ser válida.

## Sistema global de erros

Nesse mecanismo dentro das funções que podem gerar um erro uma variável global é assinalada, muitas vezes através de uma função/método *wrapper*, com as informações do erro. Qualquer código pode acessar esta variável, provavelmente pelo *wrapper*, e verificar a existência e detalhes do erro.

Ele pode ser útil em situações bem específicas. Eu tinha que listá-lo, mas **ele é ruim**.

O principal problema é que ele exige [estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101).

A comunicação do erro não é feita pela API diretamente. Mas este é um problema que a exceção tem também. Evidentemente que o compilador pode lidar melhor com a criação de novas exceções do que com novos códigos de erros globais. Desacoplamento demais pode ser problemático também.

O que ele pode ser usado, e tem linguagens mais novas que estão fazendo, é quebrar a aplicação e chamar um tratamento global quando o erro é de programação ou de ambiente. Pra que lançar exceção de algo que não poderá ser contornado?. Exceção tem um propósito próprio e não inclui esse tipo de coisa. Uma linguagem achou que era elegante usar exceção para todo tipo de erro, outras gostaram, copiaram, mas agora muita gente, que não é teimosa, já aceita que foi um erro usar exceção para tudo.

## Quando a exceção é melhor

Primeiro, entenda que exceção não é nada simples. É um desvio incondicional que vai te levar para um local totalmente indeterminado. Isso é uma loucura. Muita coisa pode dar errado. Tem que seguir um monte de regra para funcionar. E a prática mostra que poucos programadores sabem usar do jeito certo. Então pra que usar algo complexo se tem algo mais simples?

Algumas linguagens mais modernas até estão evitando ou limitando o uso de exceções. Há alguns bons motivos para usá-la e muitos motivos para evitá-la. Exceções são virais e pouco ortogonais. O *design* da linguagem fica incrivelmente complicado por causa delas. Essas linguagens têm preferido usar um sistema de retorno de códigos de erro ou alguma forma semelhante, ou parar a execução abruptamente dando a chance de uma saída personalizada, e deixar a exceção claramente para casos excepcionais.

Em [Melhor maneira de lidar com Exceptions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13303/melhor-maneira-de-lidar-com-exceptions/13611#13611) eu mostro alguns casos como uma exceção deve existir e ser tratada no C#. É uma boa base para se pensar no que é caso excepcional ou não.

#### Erros de programação não são exceções

Se considerar que falhas gerais de ambiente e erros de programação não devem ser tratados pelo programa em si, provavelmente deveria ter alguma forma diferente da exceção de indicar uma falha irrecuperável do programa. Isso provavelmente evitaria abusos de `catch` que vemos todos os dias em programas. Deveria haver um local centralizado para tratar dessas falhas. Nelas, o que dá para fazer é *logar* a falha e apresentá-la ao usuário de uma forma personalizada. Ok, se a linguagem não tem uma forma especial para representar essas falhas, então lançar uma exceção é adequado. Capturá-la e tentar salvar o programa, não é.

Não, você não pode recuperar um erro de divisão por zero. Qualquer solução nesse sentido será uma maluquice. Se você sabe como resolvê-lo, então não deixe a exceção ocorrer. Uma exceção não deve substituir o controle de fluxo normal de um programa. Uma exceção de divisão por zero é um erro de programação dizendo que o programador esqueceu de verificar uma situação antes de fazer a divisão.

Não vou tratar aqui dos casos de APIs mal feitas que lançam exceções quando deveriam claramente retornar códigos de erro. Na resposta *linkada* acima fala sobre isso.

#### Exceções legítimas

Eu não sou contra o uso de exceções em certas operações externas, que dependem de recursos que a aplicação não tem controle. Um acesso a um arquivo é um bom exemplo. Note que eu disse código de erro e não verificar antes se uma operação será possível.

```
if (File.Exists("arq.txt") {
    handler = File.Open("arq.txt");
    foreach(linha in handler.ReadLine()) {
        print linha;
    }
} else {
    print "Não foi possível executar a operação";
}
if (handler != null) {
    handler.Close();
}
```

O exemplo acima (escrito em linguagem genérica) é problemático. Ele pode ter uma *race condition*. Ele se vale de uma informação verdadeira que pode se tornar falsa entre a verificação e a operação seguinte de abertura do arquivo. Isto nunca deveria ser feito. Mas tem como fazer o mesmo sem risco:

```
if (File.Open("arq.txt", @handler)) {
    foreach(linha in handler.ReadLine()) {
        print linha;
    }
} else {
    print "Não foi possível executar a operação";
}
if (handler != null) {
    handler.Close();
}
```

Nesse caso você tenta abrir o arquivo e a leitura só ocorrerá se a abertura for bem sucedida. Um retorno de código de erro (o `@handler` que é passado por referência) funciona muito bem. Mas há um problema. A leitura também pode falhar. Vamos melhorar:

```
if (File.Open("arq.txt", @handler)) {
    foreach(linha in handler.ReadLine()) {
        if (linha != null) {
            print linha;
        }
    }
} else {
    print "Não foi possível executar a operação";
}
handler.Close();
```

Esta API não está muito coerente, mas usei esta forma para mostrar formas diferentes de retorno de código de erro. Neste caso há uma tentativa de leitura de uma linha, se falhar, a linha é nula. É um código de erro e funciona bem. Fiz uma mudança no exemplo retirando o `if` final considerando que o `close()` apenas não faria nada ao invés de falhar se não há nada para fechar.

É claro que a API poderia ser algo como `bool deuCerto = handler.ReadLine(linha);` mas não sei se seria vantagem. Talvez um `FileErrorCode erro = handler.ReadLine(linha);` fosse melhor. Neste caso o `FileErrorCode` é uma enumeração para dar mais informação sobre o erro. Mas poderia ser uma classe (não excepcional) com informações mais detalhadas sobre o erro, essencialmente as mesmas informações que teria no caso de uma exceção.

Isto **funciona muito bem em muitos casos**. Pode haver problemas em outros. Em C sempre foi assim e nunca houve grandes problemas. Não é por causa disto que há problemas em C, a não ser que programadores relapsos.

De qualquer forma pode existir várias situações de falha no acesso a este ou outros arquivos na mesma tarefa e você não queira encher sua função/método de `if`s para verificar o sucesso de cada operação. É provável que você queira ter um tratamento genérico para todas as falhas de acesso em todos os arquivos envolvidos. Este é um caso que deixar o erro acontecer e capturar uma exceção pode ser uma boa escolha. Evidentemente a API deve lançar a exceção.

Mas como não é uma boa ideia ter duas APIs fazendo a mesma coisa ou ter duas formas de tratar o erro na mesma API, seria confuso, a API escolhe a que atende todos os casos e você fica sem escolha. Deve usar a exceção.

Curiosamente este é um caso em que ter muita informação sobre a exceção não ajuda em nada. Mas pode haver outras situações que estas informações são úteis.

Usando exceções o exemplo poderia ficar, simplificadamente assim:

```
try {
    handler = File.Open("arq.txt")) {
    foreach(linha in handler.ReadLine()) {
        print linha;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    print "Não foi possível executar a operação";
} finnaly {
    handler.Close();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/ErrorCodes.ptg).

A única **vantagem** que vejo neste caso é separar o tratamento de erro da lógica normal. Claro que se uma linguagem possui exceções isto se torna praticamente obrigatório. É a única forma de garantir o fechamento de arquivo. A existência de exceções obriga o uso de exceções.

#### Crítica e alternativa

Algumas linguagens permitem manipular essas várias situações de falha de outra forma. Além de Rust e Go já citadas, consigo lembrar de [D](https://dlang.org/) com seu `scope`.

Exceções são boas para tratar anormalidades. Uma exceção é um controle de fluxo como é o `if` mas ela só deve ser usada para fluxo anormal, quando você precisa subverter o fluxo normal e é raro precisar disto quando não há erro de programação.

O mecanismo de exceção é desestruturado por natureza. E ele só deve ser usado quando você tem uma situação desestruturada de tratamento de erro.

- Quando você pode evitar o erro com eficácia, evite, não deixe uma exceção ocorrer.
- Se tiver uma situação clara e previsível de tudo o que pode resultar em erro, se o erro é algo normal, possível, esperado, porém inválido, e não algo excepcional, trate o erro e não uma exceção.
- Se uma exceção é adequada e não pode ser tratada de forma minimamente especializada, não a trate localmente. Deixe para um tratamento geral, que pode ser até o definido por padrão pelo *framework*.

Exceção não é panaceia. A dificuldade de lidar com erros não ocorre por usar códigos de erro. Mas há casos que ela é útil para encurtar código. Você ter que escrever código para lidar com erros pode tornar o algoritmo longo, complexo ou confuso. São casos em que você não quer ou não pode lidar com erros, pelo menos de forma individualizada, exceção pode ser útil.

#### Exceção poderia ser melhor

Há uma [proposta de implementação de exceção em C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf) que vai no caminho mais adequado, e pode atender melhor vários cenários. Não sei se ela é ideal e muito menos se realizará, mas claramente é uma forma melhor e resolve vários problemas da exceção.

## Conclusão

Quando se trata de criar uma API ou uma função simples, retornar códigos de erro não é algo tão grave. Use-os quando eles fizerem mais sentido. Use da forma que mais se adapta à linguagem que você está usando e à situação específica. Use exceções com parcimônia. Use-as quando o seu mecanismo ou sua semântica faz mais sentido para o problema. Use-os quando o problema é de programação.

#### Abuso de exceções

Aqui não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o abuso na captura de exceções existentes. Critico isto em diversos *posts*. Procure entre [minhas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D) e [outras do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Quando não se sabe ao certo o que fazer com exceções mais especializadas é possível capturar um exceção de um nível mais alto na hierarquia. Com códigos de erro isso não é possível. Eles não possuem hierarquia. Em tese. Talvez seja possível criar uma, mas não vou entrar nisto aqui.

#### Possibilidade de ignorar o erro

Há quem argumente que códigos de erros podem ser ignorados. Exceções também, e infelizmente é comum ver códigos que as capturam apenas para engoli-las. Programador ruim produzirá códigos ruins, não importa o que se faça para proibir. Se não testar corretamente poderá ter problemas no código não importa o mecanismo para tratamento de erros.

Além disto, é possível fazer uma linguagem que obrigue o tratamento dos códigos de erro. Ou fazer uma ferramenta de análise estática que verifique se os códigos de erro estão sendo tratados.

#### Cultura

É claro que algumas linguagens forçam mais a cultura de um mecanismo sobre o outro, mas não conheço nenhuma que não aceite em suas bibliotecas padrão o retorno de códigos de erro em alguma situações.

#### Exception considered harmful

Exceções são o `goto` do nosso tempo. E pior, ninguém reconhece isto. Pelo menos existem mais motivos para usar exceções do que usar `goto`. [Exceção é um `goto` na sua pior forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101).

[Artigo do Joel Spolky sobre o assunto](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html).

#### Nomenclatura

Eu sei que algumas pessoas vão dizer que alguns dos códigos de erro que eu citei não são na verdade códigos de erro. Ok. Chame eles do que quiser mas não troque-os por exceções quando não há uma situação excepcional.

Referências:

- [Um sujeito que "manja pouco"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050114-00/?p=36693&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Note como ele mostra que C# é mais imprevisível que C++.
- [Você só está aqui por causa dele](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Não concordo com tudo que ele diz, mas a essência é esta.
- [Alguém ainda mais radical](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/exceptionsharmful/).
- [Bons argumentos para usar exceções](https://www.yosefk.com/blog/error-codes-vs-exceptions-critical-code-vs-typical-code.html).
- [Pencas de argumentos](https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AvoidExceptionsWheneverPossible).
- [Mais um artigo interessante](https://www.ckwop.me.uk/Why-Exceptions-Suck.html).
- [Proposta do C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf) para fazer a exceção ser mais útil e agir como um código de erro *done right*.

Comment: A minha dúvida é: você quer dizer que não  se deve usar rotinas de erros ?. Até quase não uso nos meus software, mas basicamente é isso?

Comment: @HarryPotter Não sei o que você chama de rotinas de erros. O que eu disse é que não há problemas em retornar códigos de erros. Mostrei que isto ocorre o tempo todo nas APIs. Disse que deve-se evitar exceções ao máximo. Mas evitar não é deixar de usar.

Comment: Também depende da linguagem né? PHP por exemplo é um gueto de tantos tipos de erro diferentes e despadronizados. nele é até interessante converter tudo pra Exceptions. Eu até criei um mecanismo que lida automaticamente com Exceptions de uma forma que elas dificilmente quebram o fluxo como normalmente fazem.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Sim, eu até *en passant* falo que depende. Meu conhecimento de PHP é pré 5.x e mesmo assim nunca fiz nada sério com ele, então não sei como está funcionando tudo isto. Sei que o PHP é a campeã da desorganização e discrepância. Não sei se o que você fez é uma boa ou não, já que não sei como ele funciona. Parece algo interessante.

Comment: De forma bem resumida, todos os erros lançam exceções, inclusive nos *Controllers* se algo der errado. Porém, nos *Controllers*, conceitualmente um único tipo de exceção deve(ria) ser lançada pois o *Dispatcher*, responsável por intermear o *Front Controller* e os *Action Controllers*, transforma essa Exception em particular numa variável de template. Daí o fluxo não quebra pois volta-se automaticamente para página anterior sem necessidade de um redirecionamento manual.

Comment: É que evitar ou não tudo depende e não vejo isso como fator importante. É muito baseado em opinião e um texto assim demonstra somente opinião.

Comment: Nas linguagens dinâmicas (onde os retornos não têm tipo definido) é fácil retornar `false` ao invés do retorno esperado (`int` ou `string`, por exemplo). Mas nas linguagens estáticas, não fica pouco legível o código retornar uma estrutura de dados ao invés do valor esperado diretamente?

Comment: @Andrey, sim, o ideal é que a linguagem permita que se retorne as coisas de forma separada e não em uma estrutura de dados. Porém sito tem uma vantagem. Você não pode usar o valor diretamente. Uma das críticas que se faz ao retorno de código de erro é que ele pode ser esquecido. Desta forma, você pode até não tratar adequadamente (exceções também pode) mas vai ter que fazer isto de forma consciente. O retorno seria uma estrutura, mas você imediatamente separaria o que é erro e o que é o resultado e depois só precisa lidar com o resultado, uma *string* por exemplo, não lida mais com a estrutura

Comment: @Andrey mas é um erro achar que é mais fácil lidar com isto em linguagens dinâmicas. Como você disse, é fácil retornar, mas lidar dá no mesmo. E na verdade, não obriga o tratamento do erro, então pode ser pior nelas. Você deve ter lido a resposta sobre linguagens estáticas X dinâmicas, lá eu falo que na prática as linguagens dinâmicas sempre retornam estruturas, o programador não tem que lidar com elas, o compilador faz isto para ele, mas está lá. Claro, eu entendo que é mais fácil, mas não melhor.

Comment: @bigown Li sim, até porque fui eu que fiz a pergunta. Só que com tantas respostas gigantes fica difícil lembrar de tudo sempre. hahaha A questão das estruturas eu já tinha esquecido. =)

Answer (score 22):

Tal recomendação tem razões muito fortes. Irei exemplificar algumas...

### Evitando pressuposições

Na hora de desenvolver ama API de cálculos financeiros, foi pressuposto que algumas rotinas retornariam apenas números positivos em caso de sucesso, portando decidiu-se usar valores negativos para denotar erro.

Depois de um período de desenvolvimento, foi verificado que na verdade números negativos são válidos.

A API terá que ser alterada completamente e todos as chamadas (que podem estar espalhadas por diversos projetos) precisarão ser revisadas.

O problema aqui não é ter que mudar, mas usar um "objeto de erro" (número negativo) que pertence à mesma classe de um "objeto de sucesso". Isso faz com que mudanças tenham mais impacto.

### Programação defensiva

PHP é conhecido por conter funções que retornam tipos de dados diferentes de acordo com o resultado da função. Buscar um caractere num texto pode retornar a posição ou `false`, por exemplo.

Isso resolve nosso primeiro problema, mas gera outro, a saber, repassa a responsabilidade para cada chamada de verificar o valor retornado.

É por isto que sempre há muitos bugs relacionados a usar `==` ou `!=` ao invés de `===` ou `===`, já que PHP  considera verdadeiras comparações como `false == 0`, por exemplo.

Algumas pessoas podem argumentar que é culpa do programador não ter cuidado ou não ler a documentação devidamente. Ora, mas os bugs não sempre culpa de algum programador?

Programação defensiva significa programar buscando sempre minimizar a possibilidade de introdução de bugs involuntários. Códigos de erro frequentemente causam esse tipo de confusão.

### Padronização no tratamento de erros

Outro problema em retornar códigos de erro começa quando começamos a ter tabelas e mais tabelas de possíveis erros.

Em linguagens com tendência procedural, é comum ter APIs que precisam definir rotinas especificamente para obter descrição dos erros, verificar se o tipo do erro, etc.

Logo, cada API acaba utilizando-se de um método diferente de tratamento de erros e o ônus de verificar cada valor retornado é de quem faz a chamada, o que aumenta a curva de aprendizado e também a probabilidade dos programadores cometerem equívocos.

Exceções são mais "simples e seguras", no sentido de que a execução é interrompida e o programador pode capturar genericamente erros de diversas APIs, especializando o tratamento quando achar necessário.

### Evitando erros ocultos

Considere a afirmação:

> Mostrar uma exceção para o usuário é sempre melhor do que um resultado incorreto.

Em alguns campos de trabalho, você não pode se dar ao luxo de errar. Imagine um sistema financeiro calculando juros incorretamente porque a rotina que nunca deveria retornar zero retornou um zero como código de erro. Acredite, já vi várias vezes ocorrer algo parecido.

Por causa dessas coisas, programadores experientes de alguns ramos preferem muito mais ter uma exceção interrompendo a execução e que gere um erro genérico do que ter a possibilidade de um resultado que possa dar prejuízo, multa ou alguma possível consequência negativa para o negócio em questão.

## Sobre o `null`

Retornos nulos são considerados ruins pelos mesmos motivos citados acima.

Por exemplo, retornar `null` requer, mas não obriga, o programador a tratar o retorno.

Então, se eu *assumo* que a rotina não vai retornar nulo e não faço o devido tratamento, estou introduzindo um *bug em potencial* no código, pois qualquer mudança futura pode introduzir mudanças que tornem minha pressuposição incorreta. Isto é um tipo de quebra de encapsulamento, pois quem invoca a rotina pressupõe algo sobre ela.

O correto então, seria sempre verificar o retorno, porém o código ficaria muito verboso.

## Alternativas

### Objeto vazio

Algumas situações, como rotinas que retornam arrays, listas ou outras coleções, devem simplesmente retornar uma coleção vazia caso não hajam elementos encontrados.

Já vi códigos que lançam `NenhumItemEncontradoException` ou que retornam `null` e isto só causa mais problemas como os mencionados acima.

Em Java:

```
return Collections.emptyList();
```

Para outros casos, há algumas pessoas que argumentam contra e à favor do padrão [*Null Object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), que basicamente consiste em criar um objeto para representar um retorno nulo, evitando assim `NullPointerException`.

Particularmente, não gosto deste *design*, dadas as outras alternativas abaixo.

### Retorno opcional

Em rotinas que retornam um objeto, mas que em determinadas ocasições o objeto pode não estar presente, pode-se usar um *wrapper* que pode ou não conter o objeto.

Em Java:

```
Optional<Cliente> getCliente(long id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(daoCliente.findClienteById(id));
}
```

Qual a vantagem? Para você acessar o objeto cliente que pode ou não estar dentro do `Optinal`, é necessário testar a presença do objeto, caso contrário, uma exceção é lançada.

Em outras palavras, você obriga quem chamar o método a fazer algum tipo de tratamento, o que torna sua API mais defensiva a erros.

### Retorno exclusivo

Caso você precise ou queira um objeto excepcional retornado, a forma "segura" é retornar um objeto composto, que obrige quem chama o método a verificar o retorno.

Uma das formas é algo muito usado na programação funcional é uma classe ou entidade `Either`. Não existe tal conceito na API do Java 8, mas você [implementar a sua versão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164155/1683070) ou usar uma biblioteca como [Fugue](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/fugue/wiki/3.0).

Exemplo em Java:

```
Either<PlanoDeFuga, PlanoB> getPlanoDeFuga() { ... }
```

Ou ainda:

```
Either<ResultadoOperacao, ProblemasProcessamento> processarOperacaoFinanceiraComplexa() { ... }
```

## Considerações

Note que o primeiro termo da minha resposta é *recomendação*. Tudo isto são recomendações vindas de pessoas que desenvolveram certas práticas após muitos anos de experiência.

Infelizmente, há muita distorção e tentativa de aplicar tudo isto como se fosse lei, o que não funciona.

Ao mesmo tempo, é importante procurar entender o que está por trás de regras ou práticas. Mesmo que você não concorde ou aplique, ainda assim estará a par do risco para a qual ela foi criada.

Neste caso, os principais riscos são: misturar tipos de retorno os diferentes (afeta linguagens com tipagem fraca) e esperar que o tratamento de um possível valor de erro retornado seja sempre feito da forma correta sem, no entanto, ter garantia de que isto vá ocorrer.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Sim, saiu um igual a mais. Obrigado por avisar.

Answer (score 13):

Pessoalmente prefiro retornar códigos de erros (ou true/false) ao invés de lançar exceções por uma questão de segurança, pois alguém pode esquecer de tratar uma exceção.

Em projetos em que trabalhei onde eram desenvolvidas APIs (normalmente DLLs escritas em C) para uso por vários sistemas ou por múltiplas linguagens de programação (Java, Delphi e C#) era padrão retornar "0" como "ok", um número negativo para erros de sistema operacional (exemplo: erro na abertura de um arquivo) e um número positivo para erros de "lógica de negócio" (exemplo: conta não cadastrada).

Nesse tipo de projeto cada função da API possuia uma tabela de códigos de erro/descrição para consulta pelos programadores e para documentação do sistema. Além disso, procurávamos padronizar os códigos de erro: se "425" era o código usado para "conta não cadastrada" em uma função, todas as demais que fossem retornar esse erro usariam o mesmo código.

Já em funções usadas dentro de sistemas prefiro retornar true/false como retorno e uma variável do tipo "out" com a mensagem de erro (a qual estará vazia caso retornado "true" - sem erro).

Answer (score 0):

> Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?

A pergunta é antiga, mas o dilema é presente! A extensão do artigo prova o vasto conhecimento do autor, algo louvável, mais ainda quando decide compartilhar. Obrigado **[Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero)**!!!

Antes de responder é preciso considerar alguns aspectos fundamentais:

1. Quem deveria decidir sobre isso?
2. Como deve-se implementar a decisão?
3. Considerar a tríada sagrada Q/C/T para responder as anteriores (Quality, Cust, Time)
4. Quem vai receber os erros, afinal?

Dito isto, devemos remover a parte tendenciosa da pergunta "...evitar códigos de erro...",  pois não há como evitá-los. Precisamos dedicar boa parte do tempo de planejamento decidindo como lidar com eles, não importando o meio/métodos a ser utilizado, pois isso vai variar conforme a linguagem, basicamente.

Para pergunta 1: Sendo assim, quem deveria decidir: arquiteto de software, analista de negócios, analisa de sistemas, nesta ordem ou combinados. Em último caso, por omissão dos anteriores, o desenvolvedor.

2: Claro, o desenvolvedor, mas amparado por um padrão pré-definido, claro e flexível, devidamente previsto nos documentos de fluxo/caso de uso/outros que se utilizar para especificar o desenvolvimento da solução. Inclusive, fazer parte do plano de teste.

3: Para considerar a tríada citada, sabemos que as variáveis Q/C/T mudam conforme a fase em que se encontra o projeto, mas deve ser considerada desde da primeira fase, levantamento de requisitos! E em alguns casos, decidir sobre isso de forma tardia é a pior escolha.

4: Finalmente, decidir o "como fazer" e o "o que mostrar" vai depender da natureza da aplicação. Pois, comunicar um erro a um usuário é bem mais custoso que comunicar erro entre aplicações. Tome como exemplo tratar as mensagens de erros para aplicações desktop, com usuário final lidando com as exceções e no caso de micro serviços web trocando mensagens entre si, nestes casos o "quem vai receber os erros" já pré-define o método de tratamento (frendly, tipificado, rest, HttpStatus, etc).

Concluindo, não há resposta nem direção a ser apontado de maneira 'prévia', logo, devemos compreender as variáveis para decidir como lidar com erros, sejam eles previsíveis ou não.