# Como e quando usar exceções no PHP?

Tags: php, exceção

No PHP, a maioria das funções nativas retorna um booleano `false`, inteiro `0` ou `NULL` caso seja encontrado algum tipo de inconsistência no valor passado à mesma. Exemplo:

```
$exemplo1 = explode("","tente me explodir"); // false
//ou
$exemplo2 = count(NULL) // 0
```

Este tipo de solução acaba deixando o trabalho de validar a função para o desenvolvedor, que decide como (ou se) deve tratar o mesmo.

Por outro lado, se todas as funções disparassem `exceptions` o desenvolvedor teria muito mais trabalho tendo que usar `try/catch` em todas as funções que ele utilizasse para não estourar o código.

Então, se nem o PHP utiliza `exceptions` com frequência, quando então o desenvolvedor deve utilizá-las? É preferível utilizar o mesmo método utilizado pela linguagem, ou seja, retornar false nas funções e tratar elas quando for necessário? Ou sempre disparar uma `exception` quando o input não for o esperado?

Comment: Você leu isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21767/por-que-devemos-evitar-retornar-c%c3%b3digos-de-erro

Comment: Eu acredito que devemos sempre procurar usar como forma de previnir e identificar erros.
Pessoalmente eu uso sempre que utilizo O.O. em meu código, bem como nas consultas a base de dados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Quando deve usar exceções?

Você utiliza uma exceção para indicar uma condição excepcional, isto é, algo que impede que um método satisfaça o seu propósito e que não deveria ter ocorrido a esse nível.

Por exemplo, você pode ter um método que salva as alterações em um registro num banco de dados. Se por alguma razão isso não pode ser feito(por exemplo, ocorre algum erro no banco de dados), então você pode lançar uma exceção para indicar a falha.

### Quando não deve usar exceções?

Considere um método que verifica a existência de um arquivo, isso provavelmente não deverá lançar uma exceção se o arquivo não existe, uma vez que o objetivo do método foi verificar a existência.

No entanto, um método que abre um arquivo e executa algum processamento poderia lançar uma exceção, uma vez que se espera que o arquivo exista.

```
function fileContent($file)
{
  if (!file_exists($file))
   throw new Exception("O arquivo não pode ser encontrado", 1);

  return file_get_contents($file);  
}
```

Ou com tratamento de exceções com `Try/Catch`:

```
function fileContent($file)
{
  try {
        return file_get_contents($file);
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Você sabe que o primeiro exemplo cria uma *race condition*?

Comment: Para fins demonstrativos acredito que seja válido o exemplo. =)

Comment: De que modo, @bigown ?

Comment: @Sunstreaker até é mas seria bom deixar isto claro porque muita gente copia estas coisas achando que está tudo ok.

Comment: @TassoEvangelista Porque você verifica se o arquivo existe, aí você vai ler o conteúdo e ele pode não existir mais.

Answer (score 3):

> Exception handling is the process of responding to the occurrence, during computation, of exceptions – **anomalous or exceptional events requiring special processing** – often changing the normal flow of program execution. It is provided by specialized programming language constructs or computer hardware mechanisms. [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)

Exceptions devem ser utilizadas para tratamento de eventos que alteram o *fluxo normal* de execução de um script PHP. Geralmente assumimos que estes eventos são erros lógicos ou em tempo de execução (*runtime*), mas também são úteis em falhas de asserção, como erros de validação da entrada de dados do usuário ou do próprio programador.

Entretanto, cabe lembrar que exceções foram introduzidas apenas no PHP 5, enquanto as funções citadas na sua pergunta são de versões anteriores. Algumas classes antigas que você vai encontrar também vão utilizar o retorno de `false` ou `null` em alguns métodos para sinalizar erros.

Existem muitas vantagens em se utilizar exceptions, mas, pessoalmente, acredito que o debug de erros com elas é muito superior. Uma vez que uma exceção é lançada exatamente onde um erro ocorre, a *stack trace* vai te fornecer uma cadeia de chamadas precisa de em quais linhas de código a exceção passou. Um retorno de `false` de um método complexo não vai te dizer onde a execução falhou, a menos que você faça debug linha a linha. Não é raro eu ter que tratar exceções lançadas mostram mais de 15 métodos executados.