# PHP tem exceptions mais específicas?

Tags: php, exceção

Eu geralmente vejo que todo mundo usa PHP com *PDOException* ou a mais genérica Exception `$e`, mas PHP possui *exceptions* mais específicas? como em JAVA *NullPointerException* ou *ArithmeticException* ou *NumberFormatException*

E eu uso elas da mesma forma que exception $e? Só que substituindo o exception pelo mais específico

Comment: E a segunda parte da pergunta @Wallace Maxters?

Comment: Sim, a sintaxe não muda de uma exceção para a outra. Relacionada: [Como e quando usar exceções no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21914/5878)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Cada exception tem métodos próprios que são adequados para a tarefa. Por exemplo a `PDOException` tem uma propriedade que retorna o `SQLSTATE` que é util para saber qual o tipo de erro aconteceu com a consulta ou banco, que não nada adequado para o tratamento de um arquivo.

Comment: Caso precise de algo mais específico, é só criar suas próprias exceções...