# Pegar conteúdo dentro de string

Tags: c#, .net, string

Terei uma lista de *string* no seguinte formato: **NOME DA PESSOA(** (**LOGIN**), um exemplo seria esse: `ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (zackson.morgan)`

Logo, eu precisaria obter apenas o que estaria dentro dos parenteses, ou seja, **zackson.morgan**.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Detalhe: todas as strings da lista sempre seguirão esse formato.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isto é localizar a posição dos dois parênteses e pegar a parte interna, assim:

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (zackson.morgan)";
        WriteLine(pegaTexto(texto));
        texto = "ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (zackson.morgan";
        WriteLine(pegaTexto(texto));
        texto = "ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (";
        WriteLine(pegaTexto(texto));
    }
    public static string pegaTexto(string texto) {
        texto += ")";
        texto = texto.Substring(texto.IndexOf("(") + 1);
        return texto.Substring(0, texto.IndexOf(")"));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8eTxzS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4MgZjw). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/GetSubstringDelimiter.cs).

Com o advento do [`Span`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é possível fazer isto de forma mais otimizada.

Comment: Bem melhor que a mania de regex do povo!

Comment: Perfeito, não conhecia esse site. Ainda sou novo em programação .net, e estou gostando muito. Quero me aprofundar no assunto. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @ZackMorgan bem vindo então. Não se esqueça de dar uma olhada no [tour] para entender o básico. Aqui o pessoal gosta de fazer tudo com qualidade.

Comment: @bigown É realmente necessário colocar um `)` no final da string antes de tirar o texto desejado?

Comment: @mutlei é, porque vai que esqueceram de fechar. Aí funciona também.

Comment: @bigown Outra dúvida, por que ocorre uma *exception* quando você tenta fazer a operação em uma linha só, com os índices do `(`+1 e do `)`?

Comment: Não sei, teria que ver o código.

Comment: Procurei a documentação do método e vi só um motivo tolo pra lançamento dessa exceção... Ele lança exceção nesses casos: `startIndex mais length não indica uma posição dentro dessa instância.` ou `startIndex ou length é menor que zero.` O segundo eu entendi, mas o primeiro... WTF.

Comment: @mutlei não sei como está testando mas eu fiz uma alteração e mais testes.

Comment: Eu tentei com `texto.Substring(texto.IndexOf("(") + 1, texto.IndexOf(")"))`, que funcionaria em Java. Mas como eu li na documentação, gera uma exception `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` por que a soma dos índices é maior que o comprimento da String.

Comment: Ah, você está fazendo outra coisa. É perigoso fazer isto porque aí você corre o risco de ter um parêntese fechando antes de ter uma aberto. E tem outros problemas nesse código. Eu dei uma solução que funciona sempre. Pode nem ser o ideal, pode ser que informe um problema se não tiver um parêntese fechando. Mas eu não informaria isto com exceção: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101

Comment: Isso é coisa da própria linguagem. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Enquanto que a solução do @Maniero soluciona amplamente a questão, fica a versão com expressões regulares para resolver o problema:

```
private static Regex regex = new Regex("^.*\\((?<login>.*)\\)$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

public static void Main()
{
    WriteLine(GetLogin("ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (zackson.morgan)"));
    WriteLine(GetLogin("ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN (zackson.morgan"));
    WriteLine(GetLogin("ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN )"));
    WriteLine(GetLogin("ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN ("));
    WriteLine(GetLogin("ZACKSON MOREIRA MORGAN"));
}

private static string GetLogin(string input)
{               
    var res = regex.Match(input);
    if(res.Success)
        return res.Groups["login"].Value;
    else
        return "No matches found";
}
```

Neste caso, a sintaxe `(?<input>.*)` captura todas os caracteres entre os parêntesis (definos por `\\(` e `\\)`).

Veja a funcionar no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vm6d48).

Comment: Show de bola. Obrigado!