# Melhor opção a ser usada em tratamento de erros?

Tags: php, exceção

Estou criando uma biblioteca em PHP para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados e manipular dados do mesmo, mas não sei qual a melhor opção para tratar os erros, se é melhor usar `try/catch`, `echo/return` ou `die`.

Atualmente estou usando vários `if/else` para percorrer (validar) os dados, em caso de erro exibo um `echo` com o erro e dou um `return false` (para não executar o código restante), caso não tenha erro, apenas continuo minhas verificações e no fim retorno `true` ou `array` (dependendo da função). Veja um exemplo da minha função mais simples (a `deletar`):

```
function deletar($tabela, $where = NULL)
{
    if(!function_exists("conectar"))
    {   //falta include de conexao.php
        echo "Não há uma conexão ativa com o seu banco de dados!\n<br><i>Inclua a página ../conexao.php<br>";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //conexao feita
        if($tabela)
            $tabela = "DELETE FROM ".$tabela." ";
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Não foi indicada nenhum tabela.<br>";
            return false;
        }
        
        $where = minwhere($where);

        echo $sql = $tabela.$where;
            
        if($conn = conectar())
        {
            if($result = $conn->query($sql))
            {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
                if($result = $stmt->execute())
                        echo "<br>Deletado!<br>";
                else
                    echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
                
                $conn = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
                return false;
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados!<br>\n<i>Verifique as variáveis do arquivo ../conexao.php</i>";
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Segue o [restante da biblioteca](https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO) (para se alguém quiser analisar outros funções).

O que pode melhorar no tratamento de erros? O modo que estou fazendo é uma alternativa válida ou um código ruim?

Comment: Aproveite e [veja isso](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo) e [aqui](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) tem um exemplo de um query builder feito por usuário do SOen que responde muita coisa sobre php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente está certo, só poderia ser mais organizado. Eu poderia organizar mais ainda do que fiz abaixo, mas fugiria do estilo que está sendo feito.

Esse monte de `echo` é sempre uma forma rasa de tratar o erro. Em aplicações sérias, o tratamento seria feito de forma totalmente diferente, jamais jogaria um texto de qualquer jeito na página. Mas pra isso teria que reestruturar toda a aplicação, não só esse trecho. Eu até entendo que a maioria das pessoas fazem assim, mas é o jeito "porco" de fazer.

Sinceramente, por ser uma biblioteca, achei um código horroroso. Parece código de quem está iniciando em programação. Eu não seguiria ela para aprender.

```
function deletar($tabela, $where = NULL) {
    if(!function_exists("conectar")) {
        echo "Não há uma conexão ativa com o seu banco de dados!\n<br><i>Inclua a página ../conexao.php<br>";
        return false;
    }
    if(!$tabela) {
        echo "<br>Não foi indicada nenhum tabela.<br>";
        return false;
    }
    $tabela = "DELETE FROM ".$tabela." ";
    $where = minwhere($where);
    echo $sql = $tabela . $where;
    if(!($conn = conectar())) {
        echo "<br>Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados!<br>\n<i>Verifique as variáveis do arquivo ../conexao.php</i>";
        return false;
    }
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        echo ($result = $stmt->execute()) ? "<br>Deletado!<br>" : "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
        $conn = null; //isto provavelmente é um erro
        return true;
    }
    echo "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
    return false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/HandlingError.php).

Trato do assunto em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, eu também não acho que seja um jeito correto de se fazer, mas faço porque não sei fazer de outro jeito. Seria legal ter uma biblioteca de erros e códigos de erros, mas não sei como fazer por isso perguntei. Os `echo` são a única forma que achei para informar diretamente o erro. Percebi que comentou uma linha, a variável `$conn` é minha conexão com o banco de dados, igualando ela a `null` seria o fechamento da conexão (segundo uma pergunta que vi aqui no Stack)

Comment: É, aqui tem um monte de coisa errada sendo disseminada, principalmente em PHP. Uma biblioteca que gerencie a conexão não deveria nunca dar `echo`, deveria informar quem vai consumir a conexão para apresentar de um jeito que se encaixe naquele site. Por isso que eu falei que precisaria reestruturar todo o código. Tem que separar a lógica da conexão, da lógica de apresentação. Você pode até fazer um *log* aí, mas não pode escrever nada na página, você não sabe como ela será apresentada, não sabe nem se é uma página mesmo ou outra coisa.

Comment: No caso, fazer o tratamento criando `Exception` seria mais adequado que o `if/else` e `echo` ?

Comment: Eu acho que não, tem gente que acha que sim, mas especialmente em PHP, sou contra o uso de exceções. Eu falo sobre isto no *link* que coloquei na resposta. Quase ninguém sabe usar exceções direito, e isto por si só já é um bom motivo para não usar. Tem motivos melhores.

Comment: Existem várias formas de lidar com os erros, pode-se usar até `trigger_error` e direccionar com o `set_error_handler`, ou ainda com o `try catch`, mas utilizando esses métodos ficas sujeito a outras complicações, dependendo do que se deseja no final, na maior parte das vezes é recomendado armazenar erros numa variável específica para que tenhamos maior controle sobre quando e onde devemos apresentar esse erro. Mas até essa forma de lidar com os erros possui contras. A pergunta linkada possui informações mais detalhadas sobre alguns métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Solução utilizando `try catch`

```php
try {

    if(!function_exists("conectar")) {
        throw new Exception( "Não há uma conexão ativa com o seu banco de dados!\n<br><i>Inclua a página ../conexao.php<br>" );
    }
    if(!$tabela) {
        throw new Exception( "<br>Não foi indicada nenhum tabela.<br>" );
    }

    $tabela = "DELETE FROM ".$tabela." ";
    $where = minwhere($where);
    echo $sql = $tabela . $where

    if(!($conn = conectar())) {
        throw new Exception( "<br>Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados!<br>\n<i>Verifique as variáveis do arquivo ../conexao.php</i>" );
    }

    $result = @$conn->query($sql);

    if(!$result) {
        throw new Exception( "<br>Query inválida!<br>" );
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    echo ($result = $stmt->execute()) ? "<br>Deletado!<br>" : "<br>Query inválida!<br>";
    $conn = null; //isto provavelmente é um erro
    return true;

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porém criei uma classe `Exception` vazia, apenas com outro nome, no funcionamento muda algo? Ou só o nome mesmo?

Comment: Depende se essa nova classe estender da Exception dai o funcionamento continua sendo o mesmo.

Comment: Eu acho que não muito boa ideia lançar excepções a torto e a direito...