# Para que serve -EPERM em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, null

Para que serve o `-EPERM`, depois que compara se o ponteiro `p` é `null`

```
 if(p == NULL) return -EPERM ;
```

E tenho que colocar essas duas bibliotecas.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentação dessa biblioteca de erros padrões](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html).

Lá diz que este código representa um erro de operação não permitida, talvez por falta de privilégios para executar.

No caso específico, ou o `null` ocorre quando há algo errado que aconteceu quando tentou executar uma operação, ou o código foi usado para indicar que a aplicação de `null` aí está errado, o que me parece que seria um uso errado dele, já que esses códigos são para operações de IO.

Obviamente tem que acrescentar a biblioteca onde contém sua definição. Lá tem os nomes dos erros que é um pouco melhor que usar um número sem significado.

Pode estar se perguntando porque precisa usar o negativo. O código é positivo, mas em muitos casos um número positivo pode indicar que funcionou e os negativos indicam erro. Vários códigos se baseiam no sinal para determinar se a ação falhou.

Fora isso precisaria de mais contexto do código para explicar.

[Leitura complementar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).