# Retorno de referência com possibilidade de objeto inválido

Tags: c++

Tenho uma classe de uma árvore B que possui um método de busca, o método de busca deve retornar uma referência para o valor associado a chave buscada, assim o user pode altera-lo se quiser, esse é um par usado na árvore:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class Pair{
public:
Pair(){
    key = Key();
    value = Value();
}

Pair(Key key, Value value){
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
}

Key key;
Value value;
};
```

O problema é que não sei o que fazer quando a busca não encontrar nada. Então o que eu quero é um método que possa retornar uma referência para algo e de alguma forma informar se o valor é valido ou não, existem algumas formas de fazer isso, vou listar as que eu encontrei e porque não quero usa-las:

1. Disparar uma exceção: acho que é uma ação muito exagerada para um resposta simples, e sinceramente acho que foge ao escopo de exceções que deveriam apenas informar erros.
2. Colocar um parâmetro adicional que informa se o valor é valido ou não: bom e simples, mas como disse queria um método com uma única resposta, adotarei esse método se não encontrar outro.
3. Usar uma estrutura adicional que guarda a referência e informa se é válida ou não: achei esse método interessante, o problema é que o objeto dentro da estrutura é uma referência e deve apontar para algum lugar mesmo quando a busca não retornar nada.

Se puderem me dizer como resolver isso eu agradeço.

Comment: Relacionado ou duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101 ou se não for, talvez seja baseada em opinião.

Comment: Bem relacionado, não sei se é duplicata mas é quase, hehe, de qualquer forma obrigado pelo link, vou optar pelos múltiplos retornos. A questão foi baseada em múltiplas "opiniões" mas vim aqui na busca de uma resposta definitiva, por isso listei as "opiniões" que eram possíveis, mas acho que deixei aberto a novas possibilidades :s

Comment: Eu também não acho que seja uma duplicata, mas concordo um pouco com o @bigown em ela ser baseada em opinião. Eu diria que a opção 1 é fácil de argumentar contra de forma concreta, mas as opções 2 e 3 são igualmente factíveis e vão depender, essencialmente, do que cada um prefere. Particularmente, eu escolheria a 3 porque faz exatamente como vc deseja: indica a falha do resultado em um único lugar (na própria classe `Pair`). Sobre o objeto precisar "apontar pra algum lugar", cria uma referência vazia, já que ela não importa.

Comment: Realmente, acho que não tem forma única e mais recomendada de fazer isso, eu disse que ia usar a segunda opção mas vou utilizar a terceira(com um `std::pair`), porque no caso da referência inválida o usuário pode se manter mais afastado dela, é só ele verificar o `pair.second` pra saber se pode ou não usar o `pair.first`

Answer (score 0):

Consigo pensar nestas duas soluções simples componteiros.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
V *find(K key)
{
    ...
}
int *v = find(key);
if(v) ...
```

Ou

```
template<typename K, typename V>
bool find(K key, V **value)
{
    ...
}

int *v;
if(find(10, &v)) ...
```

Uma solução melhor seria criar um iterador: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/