# Lançamento de exceções em função de número primo

Tags: java, exceção, booleano

> Escreva uma função que recebe um número, joga uma exceção caso o número não seja positivo e devolve verdadeiro se ele é primo, ou falso, caso contrário.

Minha resposta:

```
public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    if(n <= 0){
        throw new Exception("Número não pode ser menor ou igual à zero!");
    }
    else{
        primo(n);
    }
}
public static void primo(int n){
    int contador = 0;

    for(int j = 1; j <= Math.sqrt(n); j++){
        if(n % j == 0){
            contador++;
            if(contador == 2){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(contador == 1){
        System.out.println("Verdadeiro");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Falso");
    }
}
```

Como eu posso reescrever minha resposta na forma de uma única função booleana?

Ex: `public static boolean f(int n)`

Comment: Normalmente eu usaria `IllegalArgumentException`. Usar apenas `Exception` genericamente é uma má prática de programação.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente eu não usaria exceção para isso, acho um abuso, é bom fazer a função não imprimir nada e retornar o resultado para imprimir fora dela, assim separa as responsabilidades. Não acho exceção adequado em muitas situações, lançar `Exception` menos ainda que é genérica demais. Mas se quer fazer, seria isto:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        try {
            System.out.println(primo(n) ? "Verdadeiro" : "Falso");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static boolean primo(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Número não pode ser menor ou igual à zero!");
        int contador = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= Math.sqrt(n); j++){
            if (n % j == 0) {
                contador++;
                if (contador == 2) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z6AQ7P). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/scqnghbf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/ThreeState.java).

Leia isso: [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Procure mais sobre o [assunto no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 3):

Pode simplificar até bastante:

```
public static boolean primo( int n )
{
    int contador = 0;

    for( int j = 1; j <= Math.sqrt( n ); j++ )
        if( n % j == 0 )
            if( ++contador == 2 )
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar](https://ideone.com/vSrQf1)

Comment: Pelo que entendi parece que ele está preocupado com a exceção.

Comment: @bigown pois eu não percebi assim. Deixa ver o que ele diz ;)

Comment: Essa questão é de uma lista de exercícios da faculdade. Pelo que eu entendi, o professor quer que seja escrita uma única função que joga uma exceção caso o número seja negativo(IllegalArgumentException) e devolve verdadeiro caso o número seja primo. Porém eu percebi que é necessário também verificar se o número recebido é zero.

Comment: @Caio_Ignatz então a resposta do bigown responde à sua pergunta.