# Chamada de métodos e captura de exceção

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, exceção

Criei três classes, uma classe abstrata chamada Forma, uma classe `Retangulo` que estende `Forma` e uma classe `programa`, que contém o método `Main`. Minha intenção é na classe "programa" receber os parâmetros "largura" e "comprimento" e então utilizar a classe `Retangulo` para criar um objeto com as dimensões recebidas e imprimi-lo na tela.

classe Forma:

```
public abstract class Forma {
    public void imprime(){
        System.out.print("Área: "+area());
        System.out.print("Perímetro: "+perimetro());
    }
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double perimetro();

}
```

Classe Retangulo:

```
public class Retangulo extends Forma {
    private double comprimento;
    private double largura;

    Retangulo(double comprimento, double largura) throws Exception{
        if(comprimento <= 0 || largura <= 0){
            throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU LARGURA E/OU COMPRIMENTO NEGATIVO?");
        }
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
        this.largura = largura;
    }


    @Override
    public double area() {
        return comprimento*largura;
    }
    @Override
    public double perimetro() {
        return 2*(largura + comprimento);
    }
    public double getComprimento(){
        return comprimento;
    }
    public double getLargura(){
        return largura;
    }
    public void setComprimento(double comprimento) throws Exception{
        if(comprimento < 0){
            throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU COMPRIMENTO NEGATIVO?");
        }
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
    }
    public void setLargura(double largura) throws Exception{
        if(largura < 0){
            throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU LARGURA NEGATIVA?");
        }
        this.comprimento = largura;
    }
}
```

Classe programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double comprimento = sc.nextDouble();
        double largura = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Como chamar os métodos da classe `Retangulo` na classe `programa`, imprimir o resultado e tratar possíveis exceções?

Comment: Caio, atente-se à formatação quando colocar seu código aqui. Selecione o código e clique no ícone "{ }", senão a identação é confundida com marcação e vira uma bagunça.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem que instanciar a classe jogando os dados pedidos nela dentro de um `try-catch`. Para simular a exceção pode usar o método que troca o valor de uma das propriedades. Dá para fazer isto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Forma {
    public void imprime() {
        System.out.println("Área: " + area());
        System.out.println("Perímetro: " + perimetro());
    }
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double perimetro();

}

class Retangulo extends Forma {
    private double comprimento;
    private double largura;

    Retangulo(double comprimento, double largura) throws Exception {
        if (comprimento <= 0 || largura <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU LARGURA E/OU COMPRIMENTO NEGATIVO?");
        }
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
        this.largura = largura;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        return comprimento * largura;
    }
    @Override
    public double perimetro() {
        return 2 * (largura + comprimento);
    }
    public double getComprimento() {
        return comprimento;
    }
    public double getLargura() {
        return largura;
    }
    public void setComprimento(double comprimento) throws Exception {
        if (comprimento < 0) throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU COMPRIMENTO NEGATIVO?");
        this.comprimento = comprimento;
    }
    public void setLargura(double largura) throws Exception {
        if (largura < 0) throw new Exception("ONDE JÁ SE VIU LARGURA NEGATIVA?");
        this.comprimento = largura;
    }
}

class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double comprimento = sc.nextDouble();
        double largura = sc.nextDouble();
        try {
            Retangulo retangulo = new Retangulo(comprimento, largura);
            retangulo.imprime();
            retangulo.setComprimento(-comprimento);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JfYmHw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hrgakedv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Validation.java).

É só um exercício, mas algumas podem ser feitas melhor. Começando por consistência de formatação. Também seria melhor não usar `Exception` para isso conforme disse na [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148017/101). Também precisa tomar cuidado com herança. Muita gente usa esse exemplo de Forma/Retangulo para ensinar herança. Em geral isso é um erro, pelo menos nessa forma. Ok, funciona, nesse exercício não tem nada errado, mas vai ensinando herdar de coisas que [não possuem de fato uma relação de mãe/filha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Por exemplo, outras não possuem comprimento e altura.