# Lidar com erro 404 sem utilização de try/catch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, exceção, try-catch

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que faz um HTTP *request*, só que as vezes a URL não funciona, ai vai ser lançada uma exceção pelo *framework*.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;

// vai ser lançada uma exceção nessa linha
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Achei exemplos na internet que o pessoal adiciona um bloco `try/catch` para controlar o fluxo do programa quando der esse erro, exemplo:

```
try
{
  HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
   response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Há outra forma de não parar o fluxo do programa mas sem utilizar `try/catch`? Só quero usar `try` se for a única solução.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há uma forma de resolver isso sem capturar a exceção já que este foi o mecanismo adotado pela API.

Em tese é possível usar uma outra API ([HTTPClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), por exemplo, que por sinal é mais moderna e talvez mais adequada ao que precisa, [veja as diferenças](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737601/221800)) ou criar uma própria. Mas ninguém fará isso.

Talvez exista algum malabarismo que evite isso, mas não consigo lembrar de nenhum e duvido que seria viável. Na verdade até imagino encapsular esse API em outra que capture a exceção e [gere um código de erro para seu código consumir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Não vejo vantagem alguma em fazer isso e nesse caso nem sei se é o mais adequado a fazer.

[Segundo a documentação 4 exceções são possíveis nesse método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_GetResponse). Imagino que vá considerar que as outras devam ser tratadas por um mecanismo mais geral, certo? Só não vá capturar `Exception` para pegar todas, aí é duplo erro.

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não muda para o [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)? O retorno das requisições é um [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx) que não lança exceções em caso de falhas, exceto se você usar o método `EnsureSuccessStatusCode`

```cs
        // client é uma instancia da classe HttpClient, que 
        // deve ser instanciada apenas uma vez por aplicação conforme 
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#examples
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //...
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado por lembrar, @AugustoVasques. 
Mesmo não tendo muitos 'upvotes' na minha resposta, fiz a correção e observação que vc mencionou, para não incentivarmos o uso errado.