# Como faço para criar um diretório através da linguagem Harbour?

Tags: diretório, harbour

Como faço para criar um diretório através da linguagem Harbour?

Por exemplo, quero criar uma pasta `temp` dentro do diretório atual de onde o programa está sendo executado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, não recomendo criar coisas temporárias na pasta do programa. O OS normalmente já tem uma definição de `temp` para isso.

A função para criar um diretório é

```
hb_DirCreate( 'temp' )
```

Exemplo:

```
IF hb_DirCreate( cDir ) == 0
   ? "Diretório criado com sucesso"
ENDIF
```

Que equivale ao antigo `MakeDir` do Clipper. De curiosidade, quando a flag `HB_COMPAT_C53` está ativa ao se construir o Harbour, ela ativa esta linha:

```
HB_FUNC_TRANSLATE( MAKEDIR, HB_DIRCREATE )
```

<sub>isso fica em `src/rtl/dirdrive.c`</sub>

Se quiser um caminho mais complexo (criação recursiva):

```
hb_DirBuild( 'caminho/composto')
```

Sobre a observação do local dos temporários, pense que muitas vezes a aplicação está instalada em um local, como um SSD, e o temporário num HD normal para evitar desgaste prematuro, ou mesmo em um RamDisk para maior velocidade de execução. Seria bom respeitar as preferências do administrador do sistema.

Para obter a localização do `temp` do sistema:

```
cLocal := hb_DirTemp()
```

E tem também a `hb_FTempCreate`, que já cuida de tudo isto que eu mencionei e cria o arquivo temporário, e é abstraída pelo

```
TempFile([<cDirectory>], [<cExtension>], [<nFileAttr>])
```

https://harbour.github.io/doc/clct3.html#tempfile

<sup>A documentação está no endereço https://harbour.github.io/doc, mas está num processo de reorganização geral, um pouco confuso para deixar permalinks no momento</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Usando a função [`MakeDir()`](https://harbour.github.io/doc/harbour.html#makedir). Então é só fazer:

```
MakeDir("caminho desejado")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/MakeDir.prg).

Lembrando que Harbour é *case-insentive* e em tese pode escrever o nome da função como quiser. Ela retorna 0 se a criação ocorreu ok, ou o número do erro retornado pelo sistema operacional. O Harbour [não costuma usar exceções para comunicar erros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), apensar de ter um mecanismo para isto. A função [`FError()`](https://harbour.github.io/doc/harbour.html#ferror) pode ser usada de forma auxiliar.

A função é compatível com Clipper. Há alguns aliases da função.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma é usando a função [`MAKEDIR`](http://www.fivetechsoft.com/harbour-docs/api.html#makedir)

```
MAKEDIR("temp")
```