# Como converter um texto para número?

Tags: c, c++, string, conversão-de-tipo, int

Como devo converter um texto que eu sei que é um número inteiro vindo externamente? Seria algo como um `ToInt()` ou algo parecido.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Em C++

No header `<string>`, no manespace `std`, são definidas funções que convertem `string` para tipos numéricos. O nome das funções é uma abreviação de **s**tring **to** **i**nt (`stoi`), **s**tring **to** **f**loat (`stof`), **s**tring **to** **u**nsigned **l**ong (`stoul`), e assim por diante, dependendo do resultado desejado:

`stoi`, `stol`, `stoll` : Conversão para inteiros `int`, `long` e `long long`

`stoul`, `stoull` : Conversão para inteiros sem sinal `unsigned long` e `unsigned long long`

`stof`, `stod`, `stold` : Conversão para números de ponto flutuante `float`, `double` e `long double`

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/1HUiMg):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string S1("3.1415");
    std::cout << "int   : " << std::stoi(S1) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "float : " << std::stof(S1) <<std::endl;
}
```

Essas funções ignoram todos espaços em branco antes do primeiro caractere que pode ser convertido e ignoram se houver texto depois do número convertido (ou seja, a string `"   -5.12tex"` será considerada como `"-5.12"`).

#### Mudança de base e argumentos extras

Cada uma dessas funções aceita três argumentos, o segundo deles é um ponteiro para uma variável do tipo `size_t`, essa variável receberá o índice do primeiro caractere não convertido (se esta informação não é requerida, pode-se passar `nullptr`).

O terceiro argumento é a base da conversão, por padrão `10`. Podem ser usadas bases entre `2` e `36`, inclusos. Para bases maiores que dez, as letras do alfabeto, em ordem, são consideradas os algarismos depois do `9`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\"junk\" em base 36 : " << std::stol("junk", nullptr, 36);
}
```

Saída:

`"junk" em base 36 : 926192`

#### Em C

Em C, que não possui tipo específico para strings, arrays de chars podem ser convertidas para inteiros pelas funções `strtol` e `strtoll`, de funcionamento semelhante, mas que recebem um ponteiro `char*` como primeiro argumento ([Maniero elaborou melhor a resposta para o C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185346/7322)).

No C, o segundo argumento é um ponteiro para um ponteiro de char `char**`, e ao invés de retornar a posição do primeiro caractere não convertido, a função escreverá o endereço deste (pode ser passado `NULL`, que será ignorado, caso esta informação não seja desejada).

#### Erros

Como nem toda *string* pode ser transformada em um número, a funções pode falhar para algumas entradas. No C++, duas exceções são possíveis:

- `std::invalid_argument` se não for possível converter a *string*
- `std::out_of_range` se for possível fazer conversão, mas o número resultante não couber no formato desejado (overflow).

No C, os erros são os seguintes:

- É retornado zero (`0`) caso não possa ser feita conversão (o que dificulta diferenciar erros de zero)
- `errno` recebe o valor `ERANGE` caso ocorra overflow, e é retornado o valor máximo possível para o tipo numérico requisitado (positivo ou negativo, dependendo da direção do overflow)

#### Outros tipos de strings

*Strings* que usam `w_chart` podem ser convertidas da mesma maneira no C++ (que possui *overload* das funções para classe `wstring`), ou com as funções de nome levemente diferente em C:

`wcstol`, `wcstoll`, `wcstoul`, `wcstoull` : abreviações de ***w**ide **c**har **s**tring **to*** : **l**ong, **l**ong **l**ong, **u**nsigned **l**ong e **u**nsigned **l**ong **l**ong, respectivamente.

Comment: Muito boa resposta.

Answer (score 7):

A função [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) é o que procura. Existe ainda a `atoi()` que é considerada obsoleta. Se deseja um `int` obtenha o `long` com a primeira função e depois faça a conversão, se for possível (verifique antes).

Não esqueça que se o dados for inválido ela vai falhar, então verifique se a ação foi bem sucedido. Infelizmente tem uma péssima forma de [retornar códigos de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), o que fez algumas pessoas que só acompanham receita de bolo considerar que códigos de erro são ruins (eles são ruins se mal usados e usados em situações que existe um mecanismo melhor).

Dá para escolher a base de cálculo binário, decimal, hexadecimal, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(void) {
    char *end;
    printf("\" 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\" em decimal --> %ld - ", strtol(" 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", &end, 10));
    printf("Erro: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("\"1010\" em binário --> %ld\n", strtol("1010", NULL, 2)); //sem tratamento de erro
    printf("\"12\" em octal     --> %ld\n", strtol("12", NULL, 8));
    printf("\"A\"  em hex       --> %ld\n", strtol("A", NULL, 16));
    printf("\"junk\" em base 36 --> %ld\n", strtol("junk", NULL, 36));
    printf("\"012\" detecção    --> %ld\n", strtol("012", NULL, 0));
    printf("\"0xA\" detecção    --> %ld\n", strtol("0xA", NULL, 0));
    printf("\"junk\" detecção   -->  %ld - ", strtol("junk", &end, 0));
    printf("Erro: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5rYRqt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ejzklkxe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ConvertToNumber.c).