# Arquivo binário sendo escrito de forma incorreta

Tags: c, arquivo, tipagem

Criando o arquivo binário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  FILE *BIN;
  BIN = fopen ("BIN.bin","wb");

  if (BIN!=NULL)
  {
   for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
      fwrite( & i,sizeof(i),1,BIN);
    }

    fclose (BIN);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Lendo o arquivo binário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
char* filename = "BIN.bin";
char x[100];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen (filename,"rb");

fread(x,sizeof(x),1,fp);


for (size_t i = 0; i <sizeof(x); i++) {
  printf("\n%u",x[i]);
}
fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}
```

O problema é que o binário contem 3 zeros a cada numero criado, aonde foi que errei?

Output:

```
1
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
5
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
7
0
0
0
8
0
0
0
9
0
0
0
10
0
0
0
11
0
0
0
12
0
0
0
13
0
0
0
14
0
0
0
15
0
0
0
16
0
0
0
17
0
0
0
18
0
0
0
19
0
0
0
20
0
0
0
21
0
0
0
22
0
0
0
23
0
0
0
24
0
0
0
25
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está gravando números (`i` é `int`) como binário e está lendo textos (`x` é `char[]`) como binário. São incompatíveis. Você grava algo com 4 bytes e depois mandar ler caracteres (que tem apenas 1 *byte*). Então em números baixos assim você terá 1 caractere com um número e 3 zerados.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca e permite um dado ser lido como outro.

Geralmente o uso de [`fprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) e [`fscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) são mais apropriados para trabalhar com dados binários assim. A não ser que prefira fazer todo o tratamento. Claro, é possível juntar 4 bytes de cada vez para criar um inteiro.

Em qualquer situação uma diferença de arquitetura onde leu e gravou dará problema, binário só pode ser usado na mesma arquitetura ou se você gerenciar essas diferenças na mão.

Pode ser útil: [Como converter um texto para número?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185345/101) e [Diferentes exibições de uma mesma variável em Linguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266079/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char x[4] = { 0, 127, 0, 0 };
    printf("%u\n", *((unsigned int *)x));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/P0yHvT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mfygselw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/CharSequenceToInt.c).