# Devemos desprezar o retorno de funções em C que já recebem o valor desejado pelo parâmetro por referência?

Tags: c, c++, funções, return

Olhando a documentação do [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) vi que ela retorna um valor, mas vejo os códigos usando ela sem fazer uso desse retorno. Isto está certo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De fato está errado. Mas o uso do `scanf()` costuma estar errado em outros pontos, até mesmo o uso dele já é um erro. Ocorre que em geral o pessoal está só fazendo um exercício e pouco importa, mas se a pessoa quiser fazer certo deveria verificar o retorno que é um código erro.

Justamente porque as pessoas costumam ignorar isso elas têm medo de [códigos de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Claro que o programador pode cometer erros muito mais graves que ignorar o código de erro e que as pessoas apenas consideram que o programador tem que fazer certo. Aqui vale o mesmo. Se ele ignora o código é um problema dele. Admito que idealmente seria o caso de retornar algo que não pode ser usado diretamente sem verificar se está ok, mas esta não é a filosofia do C.

O problema ocorre com diversas funções. Um exemplo é o [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). Se ele retornar um `NULL` não pode usar aquilo, mas em exercícios é comum a pessoa não verificar se a alocação deu certo, o que será uma tragédia se der errado.

Isso vale para inúmeras funções do C.

O mais correto seria algo assim:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *texto = malloc(10);
    if (texto == NULL) {
        printf("Houve um erro de alocação de memória");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int x;
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
        printf("Houve um erro de leitura do dado");
        free(texto);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%d", texto);
    free(texto);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MOPy7H). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tchtugca-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/IgnoringReturn.c). Note que é para dar erro mesmo.