# Declaração simples de uma variável para scanf()

Tags: c, variáveis, declaração-de-variável, scanf

Eu já sei como declarar uma variável da maneira tradicional usando o `scanf()`, mas estou pensando em uma maneira que possa utilizar menos linhas e deixar mais organizado o código (foi o que tentei com a variável `valor`).

Acontece que quando vou rodar o programa o valor 1 é sempre imprimido na tela. Por que o valor 1 é impresso na tela?

Existe uma maneira mais organizada de usar o `scanf()` sem que eu utilize uma outra linha (parecido com o que eu estou tentando fazer)?

[Código no replit](https://repl.it/LHoF) ->

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
  int resultado = 1;
  printf("Coloque um valor: ");
  int valor = scanf("%d", &valor);

while (valor > 0){
  resultado = resultado * valor;
  valor =  valor - 1;}


  printf("O exponencial é: %d\n", resultado);


}
```

Comment: Se o problema é o numero de linhas: Saiba que da para escrever tudo em uma unica.

Comment: O `scanf` devolve a quantidade de elementos preenchidos no argumento, no seu caso o `"%d"` lê um valor logo por isso devolve sempre 1. Tem [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) a referência para confirmar.

Comment: Acabei de perceber que o que se está calculando é o fatorial, não o exponencial... seria adequado corrigir a redação da pergunta para quem vir aqui no futuro consultar essa questão e suas respostas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito o que fazer. Vou demonstrar ao mais organizado e com menos linhas, além de menos caracteres.

Note que o `scanf()` não [declara variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) alguma.

Na verdade [o `scanf()` nem deve ser usado assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101). A gente usa em exercícios. Esta função retorna uma informação de sucesso e não o que foi digitado. O que foi digitado sempre é colocado na variável usada como argumento da função. Por isso que precisa passá-lo como referência.

Antes de usar qualquer função leia a documentação e entenda todos os aspectos dela. [Documentação do `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Não tente diminuir o número linhas a qualquer custo, só diminua as que ficam mais organizado assim.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Coloque um valor: ");
    int valor;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    int resultado = 1;
    while (valor > 0) {
        resultado *= valor;
        valor--;
    }
    printf("O exponencial é: %d\n", resultado);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uF0dPx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/obzcvlzt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Refactoring.c).

Uma alternativa com `for`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Coloque um valor: ");
    int valor;
    scanf("%d", &valor);
    int resultado = 1;
    for (; valor > 0; valor--) resultado *= valor;
    printf("O exponencial é: %d\n", resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o loop while não está sendo iniciado uma vez que você declarou a variável valor de maneira equivocada. Assim, como declarou o valor da variável resultado, logo no incio do programa, guardando o valor 1 aquela informação será passada para o ultimo printf do programa.

Não há necessidade de assimilar a entrada do usuário na função scanf com o símbolo "=" pois essa é a função do "&" que antecede a variável valor.