# Loop infinito indevido no while

Tags: c, algoritmo, loop

Fiz um programa para calcular dentro de uma sequência a soma dos números positivos e a soma dos números negativos. Quando utilizo o comando `while`, a ideia é que seja dentro de uma sequência de 7 números, e depois o programa saia do `while` e faça condição, porém não está acontecendo isto.

Segue código abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>

int n, num, somaPositivo, somaNegativo, i;

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    printf("\n Digite o tamanho da sequência: "); 
    scanf("%f",&n);

    somaPositivo = 0;
    somaNegativo = 0;
    i = 1;
    while (i <= n)
    {
        printf("\n Digite um número da sequência: "); 
        scanf("%f",&num);
    } 

    if (num > 0)
    {
        somaPositivo = somaPositivo + num;  
    }
    else
    {
        somaNegativo = somaNegativo + num;  
    }

    i = i + 1;

    printf("\n A soma dos números positivos da sequência é: \n",somaPositivo);
    printf("\n A soma dos números negativos da sequência é: \n",somaNegativo);
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Controle condicional (if) está fora do **while**, isso significa que ele não é executado n-vezes, mas apenas uma: após a saída do **while**. Não havendo soma real dos números;
2. O *caractere especificador* "**%f**" é para tipos de ponto flutuante como **float** ou **double**;
3. O dois últimos printfs não possuem o *caractere especificador* de impressão "**%f**" para float/double ou "**%d**" para int;
4. A variável **i**, que será usada para contador, deve preferencialmente ser do tipo **int**, e o **scanf** para isso, deve usar o *caractere especificador* **%d**. Nada impede contudo, de ser float ou double;
5. O loop é infinito, pois não há incremento da variável i, dentro do loop, ou seja, a condição `(i <= n)`, sempre será atendida, suponto que **n** seja >= 1.

Supondo que haja algum motivo justo para se usar o **while** e não outro, como o **for**, o código correto (testado) dever ser parecido com o abaixo, se a sequência de números for realmente de inteiros:

```
 int n, i = 1, num, somaPositivo = 0, somaNegativo = 0;

 int main() {       
   printf("\n Digite o tamanho da sequência: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   while (i <= n) {
     printf("\n Digite o %do número da sequência: ", i);
     scanf("%d", &num);

     if (num > 0) {
       somaPositivo += num;
     } else {
       somaNegativo += num;
     }

     i++;
   }      

   printf("\n A soma dos números positivos da sequência é: %d \n", somaPositivo);
   printf("\n A soma dos números negativos da sequência é: %d \n", somaNegativo);
 }
```

Comment: `%f` é float, enquanto que `%lf` é double

Answer (score 2):

Este código tem vários erros e nem compila, e algumas práticas ruins ,então note todas alterações.

O principal problema é que boa parte do que deveria estar dentro do laço está fora, como não há incremento o laço nunca termina. A acumulação realizada também precisa estar ali no laço.

Preferi usar um `for` que é o mais adequado para este caso. Simplifiquei o código também.

Não resolvi o problema de uso do [`scanf()` não tratando seu retorno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101) porque para exercício está bom assim.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int n;
    printf("\n Digite o tamanho da sequência: "); 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int somaPositivo = 0;
    int somaNegativo = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\n Digite um número da sequência: "); 
        int num;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num > 0) somaPositivo += num;  
        else somaNegativo += num;
    } 
    printf("\n A soma dos números positivos da sequência é: %d\n", somaPositivo);
    printf("\n A soma dos números negativos da sequência é: %d\n", somaNegativo);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5pZOgp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tzzumgbn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Repetition.c).