# Como ler apenas números inteiros no scanf()?

Tags: c, tipagem

É que por exemplo, no código:

```
int main() {
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);          

 printf("%d", x);
}
```

Se digito "A", automaticamente ele converte para inteiro ou apenas encerra o programa (já aconteceu os dois comigo). aí, no caso, ele imprime 39.
como faço para que o programa aceite apenas numeros inteiros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o `#include <stdio.h>` para o scanf e o printf.
Além disso, precisa inicializar a variável "x", senão ela vai ter "lixo".
Se você digitar "A" e enter, o "A" que você digitou não é colocado no "x", o que o printf mostra é o conteúdo "lixo" do "x" que você não inicializou.

No exemplo abaixo, se você digitar "A" o "printf" vai sempre mostrar "-1".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x = -1;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("%d", x);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Existem basicamente duas formas:

- ou cria um mecanismo próprio de leitura de dados e aí pode controlar o que pode ser digitado
- ou verifica que o dado digitado é inválido e pede para que seja digitado novamente. Isto é feito através de um laço verificando se o retorno da função indica que foi digitado algo válido. Isto foi explicado na pergunta [Devemos desprezar o retorno de funções em C que já recebem o valor desejado pelo parâmetro por referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Colocando o que já obteve nas outras respostas em código, pode testar o retorno do `scanf` até que dê `1` que sinaliza que conseguiu ler `1` inteiro com sucesso:

```
int x;
while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1){ //enquanto não ler 1 inteiro
    static char temp[256];
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin); //limpa tudo o que ficou na entrada lendo como string
    printf("Digite um numero ");
}
```

Embora possa parecer um pouco chato ter que escrever isto tudo para garantir que lê um inteiro, é algo que você consegue abstrair com facilidade numa função auxiliar:

```
int ler_inteiro(){
    int num;
    while (scanf("%d", &num) != 1){
        static char temp[256];
        fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
        printf("Digite um numero ");
    }
    return num;
}

int main() {
    int x = ler_inteiro();
    int y = ler_inteiro();

    printf("%d %d", x, y);
}
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/iv7iOt)

Outra possibilidade um pouco mais trabalhosa seria ler sempre tudo como string e interpretar os dados que pretende da string lida. No caso de um inteiro poderia tentar interpretar um inteiro à custa de [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) e verificar se não teve sucesso para voltar a pedir outro.

Comment: Boa resposta, pensei em escrever algo assim mas fiquei com preguiça. :) No fgets para limpar o buffer de entrada talvez fosse melhor usar BUFSIZ em lugar de 256. Não sei por que esses cursos ficam insistindo em usar scanf, só dá problemas, e na minha experiência isso nunca é usado em programas "de verdade".

Comment: @zentrunix Obrigado pelo comentário. Sim é melhor usar `sizeof` que é menos um sitio para trocar, e que é o que costumo fazer desta vez nem me ocorreu.