# Números negativos, positivos e zero não retornam o esperado

Tags: c++, formatação

O código está ignorando a variável do tipo `int` e está recebendo valores reais.

Além disso, quando entro com um caractere ele retorna que é zero e não que não é um número válido.

Identificar se é positivo, negativo ou zero funciona.

```
int main(void){
    int Num;

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%f", &Num);

    if(Num > 0){
        printf("O numero e positivo");
    }else if(Num < 0){
        printf("O numero e negativo");
    }else if(Num == 0){
        printf("O numero e zero");
    }else{
        printf("Nao e um numero valido");
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Se se está programando em C (a pergunta indica ser C++), deve usar o formatador de entrada `%d`. mas mesmo não fazendo isto não é para dar problema algum em qualquer compilador (alguns impedirão de compilar, mas se compilar ele ainda pegará a parte inteira do que digitar). Tirei as partes desnecessárias do código e formatei melhor. Eu não fiz maiores validações, se for digitado algo inválido não cairá no `else` como está achando ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101)):

```
int main(void) {
    int num;
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 0) printf("O numero e positivo");
    else if (num < 0) printf("O numero e negativo");
    else if (num == 0) printf("O numero e zero");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bhQsG1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ScanFormatcpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Console/ScanfFormat.cpp).

Se estiver usando C++ mesmo sugiro então usar `cin` e `cout` e não terá esses problemas.

Comment: VI um dos error que cometi, coloquei a variavel para tipo inteiro, e na entrada do dado coloquei do tipo float. Porem o problema ainda continua, se eu digitar por exemplo 9,43243, ele retorna que é positivo, e não era pra retornar, pq isso não é um inteiro. E se eu digitar "abc" ele retorna que é zero, acho que linguagens como vb.net entendem que aquilo não é um numero valido, porem em C++ não

Comment: Neste caso leia a linha e faça todas as verificações que julgar necessárias na string lida e se forem satisfeitas todas elas faça a conversão desejada.

Comment: @GabrielFratucciDosReis eu respondi o que você perguntou e mostrei para você que é preciso fazer validação se você está digitando o dado corretamente, e mesmo não perguntando passei até um *link* para você ver que tem como sabe se o dado é válido, agora pode colocar no seu código a verificação se precisa disso, já que vai insistir em fazer C no C++.