# Como fazer o "strftime()" aceitar uma "std::string"?

Tags: c++, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo

Montei um pequeno exemplo de como tentei fazer, porém a String fica vazia, não recebendo o valor.

**IMPORTANTE** Eu quero mudar apenas o `strftime()`.

**Tentei usar, sem sucesso**

```
Data_Hora.c_str()  
Data_Hora.data.str().c_str()
```

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   time_t Capture = time(0);
   std::string Data_Hora;

   strftime((char*)Data_Hora.c_str(), 20, "%d/%m/%Y %T", localtime(&Capture)); // 25/05/2020 12:51:00

   std::cout << Data_Hora;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando uma referência para essa função preencher com o dado. Você não está passando o dado, até porque nem tem um, então não faz sentido converter um tipo para outro, tem que passar o que ele espera, e se quer usar `string` depois você passa para isso.

Como eu sei disso? Olhando a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime). Ali mostra que esse primeiro parâmetro na verdade é uma forma de retorno de dado e não uma passagem de dado. Acontece que a função retorna o tamanho do que ele conseguiu fazer para você validar. È até um erro desprezar isso, o correto seria validar, falo disso em [Devemos desprezar o retorno de funções em C que já recebem o valor desejado pelo parâmetro por referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101).

E a documentação diz claramente para você passar uma vaiável do tipo `char *`, não pode ser uma *string*. Você não pode passar uma valor desse tipo. Você efetivamente está passando um *buffer*, tem que passar um local para a função escrever nela.

Provavelmente não entende bem [O que é uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Como a variável é só um local de armazenamento e é isso que deseja, você tem que passar ela pura. Quando faz uma conversão e cria um objeto de outro tipo não está passando a variável, não é o que deseja ali. Está criando um objeto que não está armazenado em lugar algum, que é perdido logo depois do uso (não vou entrar em detalhes teria que explicar toda alocação de memória, mostrar que você vai ter o retorno em um objeto que será descartado em vez de retornar o valor em um objeto que está armazenado e referenciado).

Não existe uma forma dessa função que aceite um `string`, então a conversão deve ser feita depois.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   time_t Capture = time(0);
   char text[20];
   strftime(text, 20, "%d/%m/%Y %T", localtime(&Capture)); // 25/05/2020 12:51:00
   string Data_Hora(text);
   cout << Data_Hora;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dkKxks). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/debissfg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/CharToString.cpp).

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas eu não quero mudar a variável, o código que montei é um exemplo. Eu quero aprender a converter dentro do strftime a std::string para o formato que ele usa no caso char* e a pergunta que fiz é pra saber se é ou não possível fazer isso!

Comment: Você tem que mudar, a função funciona assim. Existe um erro claro no seu código e eu dei a solução. Eu usei o código que você postou. Se você queria saber em outro contexto deveria colocar esse contexto, eu só posso responder no contexto que colocou, inclusive porque a pergunta não fala que na verdade você quer fazer outras coisa. Para outro código a solução é claramente outra, ma não foi perguntado isso. E se a pergunta é apenas se é possível ou não fazer algo, a resposta é sim. Ajudou alguma coisa? Não. Por isso esse tipo de pergunta é fechada, não ajuda ninguém, eu achei que queria solução

Comment: Na função strftime eu estou passando sim um DADO. Estou passando para ela a hora capturada pela variável "Capture" que é formatada dentro da função, e esse dado é enviado para a variável Data_Hora também dentro da função.

Comment: Mas a pergunta é sobre a `string`, não importa outras partes.

Comment: Então vc está dizendo que é impossível neste caso fazer essa conversão seria isso? Essa que é minha dúvida!

Comment: Não, eu fiz no código, do jeito certo.