# Tamanho de vetor escolhido pelo usuário, código está correto?

Tags: c, array, memória

Acredito que a solução encontrada abaixo não seja a correta, e uma má prática de programação, para o uso do vetor `vetorNotas[]` (linha 11).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
float soma = 0, media = 0;
int i, notasTot;

printf("Informe o numero de notas a serem coletadas:\n");
scanf("%d",&notasTot);
float vetorNotas[notasTot];

for (i=0;i<notasTot;i++)
{
    printf("Digite a %d° nota:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%f",&vetorNotas[i]);
    soma += vetorNotas[i];
}

media = soma / notasTot;
printf("A media e: %0.2f\n", media);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Existe alguma forma de declarar o vetor no início da função `main()` e receber o tamanho deste com o usuário? Essa forma é realmente ruim? Se sim, teria alguma forma correta de fazer ou seria esse um problema da linguagem C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está correto para um exercício de algoritmo, não para um código real para ser usado indiscriminadamente. Tudo tem contexto.

Para produção isso é temerário, embora passaria ser aceitável se validar a entrada de dados. [Tudo que vem de fonte externa ao código deve ser devidamente validado, sempre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

O que acontece se a pessoa colocar um valor que crie um *array* maior que o espaço disponível na [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)? [Resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101).

Então você precisa saber [qual é o espaço disponível da pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53827/221800), e só permitir uma entrada de dados que crie um *array* que caiba ali e ainda sobre espaço para as outras operações que possam ser necessárias depois. Se não quiser ter esse trabalho tem que [fazer alocação dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101), e [tratar o erro adequadamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189633/101), porque também pode não ser possível alocar.

E se o usuário entrar um valor negativo ou zero?

Isso não é um problema da linguagem C, é uma solução, é problema do programador fazer o que deseja.

Se acha que é má prática deve justificar isso, assim como boa prática também, sem justificativa não é conhecimento, é chute. Um dos maiores males da área é que as pessoas acreditam em boa ou má prática. Pesquise sobre o assunto aqui, eu já falei muito sobre ele.

É uma má prática declarar variável longe do seu uso, e fez assim mesmo, sem questionar.