# Declaração de `var´ como campo do objeto

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, declaração-de-variável

Como eu poderia declarar uma variável `var` pública para que pudesse pegar o retorno dos dados.

Como seria a declaração destas variais sem preenchimento:

```
       var tbuscar = ?;
       var retorno = ?;



public bool CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta)
{
    var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    var retorno = tbuscar.DadosDermaClube("");

    if (consulta != "")
    {
        return retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Desejo realizar a declaração fora do método.

Comment: Você quer uma propriedade, certo? Esses valores serão utilizados por outros métodos da classe?

Comment: Não pode, tem que definir o tipo dela mesmo. Precisa ver o que deseja. Se quer retornar mais de uma coisa, pode usar tupla em C# 7, ou uma classe em versões anterioes. Se é só duas e uma já é o booleaano talvez seja o cado de usar um `out`. Procure que tem sobre isso aqui no site, precisa sair agora, volto pra ajudar mais depois, quem sabe responder se der mais detalhes do que deseja. Não precisa de propriedade a não ser que ela tenha que fazer parte do objeto mesmo.

Comment: Estou aguardando mais detalhes pra poder  ver qual é a melhor solução. Como vai consumir isto?

Comment: Você ainda está com dúvidas sobre esse assunto?

Answer (score 6):

Para fazer estritamente o que deseja seria algo assim:

```
public TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube ProdutosDermaClube {get; set;}

public bool CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta) {
    var buscaProdutosDermaClube = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    Retorno = this.buscaProdutosDermaClube.DadosDermaClube("");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consulta)) {
        return false;
    }
    return Retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta);
}
```

para pegar o retorno seria algo assim:

```
TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube variavel;
if (objeto.CarregaProdutosDermaClube("Sei lá o que")) {
    variavel = objeto.Retorno; //isto é horrível
}
```

#Conceitualmente certo

Mas isso provavelmente é um erro conceitual, é abusar do objeto para algo desnecessário. O mais correto, pelo que entendi, seria:

```
public bool CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta, out TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube retorno) {
    var buscaProdutosDermaClube = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    retorno = this.buscaProdutosDermaClube.DadosDermaClube("");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consulta)) return false;
    return retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta);
}
```

Aí chama assim:

```
TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube variavel;
if (objeto.CarregaProdutosDermaClube("Sei lá o que", out TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube variavel) {
    //faz algo aqui se precisar
}
```

#C# 7
Se estiver usando C# 7 pode fazer melhor:

```
public (bool, TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube) CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta) {
    var buscaProdutosDermaClube = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    retorno = this.buscaProdutosDermaClube.DadosDermaClube("");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consulta)) return (false, null);
    return (retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta), retorno);
}
```

Chama assim:

```
(var ok, var variavel) = objeto.CarregaProdutosDermaClube("Sei lá o que");
if (ok) {
    //faz algo aqui se precisar
}
```

#`Tuple`

Se ainda quiser usar tupla antes do C# 7 pode, mas não é tão conveniente e otimnizado.

```
public Tuple<bool, TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube> CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta) {
    var buscaProdutosDermaClube = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
    retorno = this.buscaProdutosDermaClube.DadosDermaClube("");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(consulta)) return Tuple.Create(false, null);
    return Tuple.Create(retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta), retorno);
}
```

Chama assim:

```
TipoDoRetornoDoMetodoDadosDermaClube variavel;
var tupla = objeto.CarregaProdutosDermaClube("Sei lá o que");
if (tupla.Item1) variavel = tupla.Item2
```

Ainda dá para criar uma classes específica para lidar com os dois valores de forma mais tipada ainda, mas vejo pouca vantagem e algumas desvantagens.

Existe uma [proposta de implementação de `Optional`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/426) que é uma especialização de uma tupla. Pra ser legal mesmo C# precisaria de outro recurso que ela não tem. Para fazer mais ou menos dá para copiar a ideia e você mesmo criar um `Optional` e usar. Mas nesta circunstância não vejo vantagem.

Na verdade talvez apenas retornar o objeto pode ser suficiente. Em vez ter retornar um `bool` e verificá-lo, verifique se o objeto é `null` e garanta que ele é `null` quando não produziu um resultado utilizável.

Existe ainda a possibilidade de usar exceção, mas nem cogito isso, é muito ruim.

Leia mais em [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnTwoValues.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível expor uma variável local fora de seu escopo, para tal será necessário o uso de uma propriedade tipada ex:

```
// Poderá ser acessado por qualquer parte do sistema.
public BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL TBuscar {get; set;}
// Ou poderá ser acessada somente pelos metodos da classe.
private BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL TBuscar {get; set;}

public bool CarregaProdutosDermaClube(string consulta)
{
   this.TBuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();

   var retorno = this.TBuscar.DadosDermaClube("");

    if (consulta != "")
    {
        return retorno[0].idproduto.Contains(consulta);
    }

    return false;
}
```