# Como saber qual exceção pode ser lançada em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, característica-linguagem

Se no Java eu invocar o método `void cadastra() throws SQLException` por exemplo, serei obrigado a adicionar um bloco `try catch` ou a "relançar" a exceção que pode ser lançada por esse método.

Dessa forma, logo de cara sei qual exceção pode ser lançada.

Agora, em C#, como faço para saber quais exceções o método `void Cadastra()` pode lançar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lendo a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou usando [alguma ferramenta](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) que te ajude saber informando quais exceções podem ser lançadas. Ainda que isto não seja tão preciso assim, por isso que capturar `Exception` não é uma boa ideia.

Se for relançar a exceção está fazendo algo errado, se vai apenas relançá-la não a capture. As pessoas capturam muito mais exceções do que deveriam. Quase nunca conseguem fazer nada útil com ela. Então deixe propagar.

Em Java também não tem como saber muita exceções e as que têm são consideradas problemáticas em muitas situações até pela maioria dos programadores Java que sabem do que estão falando.

Por tudo isto eu acho [exceção um mecanismo errado na maior parte do tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

O mecanismo do Java que indica que uma exceção pode ser lançada é bem controverso e a prática mostrou que ele traz mais problemas que soluções.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se tem alguma coisa errada, favor informar para eu melhorar.

Comment: Agora que vi que tem um -1.. Não fui eu.. Não entendi o pq

Comment: @IgorVenturelli sei que não.Teve mais um.

Comment: Eu acho que são pessoas que amam exceções, e qualquer pessoa que pense fora da caixa e saiba que exceções são mecanismos ruins merece um negativo. É a triste realidade da nossa profissão, as pessoas acreditam muito no que é popular, não no que faz sentido.