# NullPointerException em conexão com banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, sql-insert

Enfim, estou recebendo um `nullpointerException` so que eu não faço a mínima ideia em como lidar com isso, dei uma lida na net sobre e aparentemente o problema está em variáveis não iniciadas e coisas do tipo, mas tenho certeza que tudo foi inicializado aqui.

[image: Stack Trace]

Servlet:

```
public ControllerLivros() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //doGet(request, response);
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String nomeAutor = request.getParameter("nomeAutor");
    String nomeLivro = request.getParameter("nomeLivro");
    String nomeGenero = request.getParameter("nomeGenero");

    if(nomeAutor == null || nomeAutor.trim().equals("") || nomeAutor.trim().equals("null")) {
        request.setAttribute("autorNull", "O autor não pode ser em branco:");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Livros.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    if(nomeLivro == null || nomeLivro.trim().equals("") || nomeLivro.trim().equals("null")) {
        request.setAttribute("livroNull", "O nome do livro não pode ser em branco:");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Livros.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    if(nomeGenero == null) {
        request.setAttribute("generoNull", "O genero não foi escolhido:");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Livros.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }


    Livros livro = new Livros(1, nomeLivro, nomeGenero, nomeAutor);

    insertLivros.insertLivro(livro);


    PrintWriter teste = response.getWriter();


    request.setAttribute("nomeAutor", nomeAutor);
    request.setAttribute("nomeLivro", nomeLivro);


}
```

classe insert:

```
public class insertLivros {

public static void insertLivro(Livros livro) {


    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        String query = null;
        query = "insert into livros(nomelivro, nomegenero, nomeautor) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

    //Statement statement = null;

    connection = Conexao.getConexao();
    pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.setString(1, livro.getNomeLivro());
    pstmt.setString(2, livro.getNomeGenero());
    pstmt.setString(3, livro.getNomeAutor());


    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

classe de conexao (nao acredito que o erro esteja aqui)

```
public class Conexao {

public static java.sql.Connection getConexao(){

    Connection connection = null;

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        String user = "root";
        String senha = "guimazx33";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/aula";

        try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, senha);
        return connection;

        }catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("nao conectou");
    }
        return connection;
        }
}
```

Comment: lembrando que se eu criar uma classe com uma main e instanciar um objeto e pedir um insert, isso funciona, mas pelo servlet nao funciona de jeito maneira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro não é bem no código, mas o código está errado justamente porque ele esconde o erro. Assim melhora e pelo menos trata o erro de forma adequada. A falha na conexão você vai ter que ver porque ocorre.

```
public class insertLivros {
    public static void insertLivro(Livros livro) {
        try {
            Connection connection = Conexao.getConexao();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into livros(nomelivro, nomegenero, nomeautor) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, livro.getNomeLivro());
            pstmt.setString(2, livro.getNomeGenero());
            pstmt.setString(3, livro.getNomeAutor());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

public class Conexao {
    public static Connection getConexao(){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //não sei se isto é necessário
        return DriverManager.getConnection("root", "guimazx33", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/aula");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/DbConnection.java)

É óbvio que o erro precisará ser tratado, mas tratar o erro é diferente de escondê-lo, que era o que está ocorrendo no código. Não vou tentar tratar porque não sei qual é o objetivo. Poderia até capturar uma exceção para lançar uma mais significativa, ou poderia transformar em [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), o que muita gente não gosta, especialmente em Java, ou só trataria do erro na classe que cuida da interação com o usuário.

Meus códigos costumam ter um ou outro `catch` na aplicação toda, não sei porque vejo códigos das pessoas um `catch` em cada método, não faz sentido.

Pra falar a verdade tenho sérias dúvidas se a classe `Conexao` tem alguma função.

Comment: Cara eu fiz as alterações conforme você indicou ai, sinceramente funciona e não entendi muito bem o porque, vou continuar dando uma olhada.
obs:apenas peço desculpa por não conseguir subir ali na reputação, sou novo ainda não foi liberado.

Comment: Blz, quando tiver 15 pontos vc pode voltar e votar.