# Por que o retorno da busca linear para elemento não encontrado tem que ser -1?

Tags: java, array

Por que eu devo retornar -1 no final de uma busca linear se o elemento não foi encontrado?

```
int linearSearch(int[] list, int size, int key){
        for(int index=0; index<size; index++)
          if(list[index]==key)
            return index;
        return -1;
      }//linearSearch
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não tem que fazer isso, pode fazer várias coisas, mas precisa informar de alguma forma que não encontrou o elemento procurado. Uma das formas mais usadas é retornar um valor que seria impossível em uma busca que acha o elemento, e geralmente um negativo é adequado, convenciona-se o -1 para ter uma certa consistência.

Há quem critique esse tipo de coisa. [Eu sou defensor sempre que fizer sentido, como parece ser o caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

Comment: O problema de misturar retornos válidos e códigos de erro é que não há nada no sistema de tipos que faça distinção entre ambos. Nestes casos é preferível optar por lançar uma exceção ou retornar um mônada cuja semântica indique a possibilidade de _não haver_ um valor válido. Especificamente na função de busca linear, o uso do `-1` é tão comum que já está cravado na cabeça das pessoas, então é aceitável, mas eu preferiria usar um mônada. O seu post linkado é bem bacana e expande bem o assunto.

Comment: Isto é sua opinião, e você pode tê-la, mas essencialmente todas as linguagens/bibliotecas optaram por fazer diferente, até mesmo as mais modernas que já havia o mantra do "lance exceção" (que na minha opinião e de muitas pessoas, é errado na maioria das situações, e não gostamos de mantras, e sim de fatos). Praticamente todas as linguagem possuem tipagem pragmática e cheio de lacunas, as pessoas precisam lidar com isto. Um sistema de tipos que realmente não deixe nada errado ocorrer torna a linguagem impraticável. Linguagens que abusam da exceção e sofrem c/ performance e cria outros problemas

Comment: [Todas as linguagens?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.findindex%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)

Comment: **essencialmente**

Comment: O uso de `-1` pra indicar a ausência de um índice é muito sedutor porque é algo bem simples e que funciona bem em quase todos os casos. Não é um _problema_ na minha opinião. No entanto, há linguagens com sistemas de tipos que proporcionam tratar facilmente essa situações de maneira mais semântica, e eu aprecio isso. (1/3)

Comment: No caso da busca linear, todos nós sabemos estamos preparados para receber um `-1` como retorno, mas quando estamos dando manutenção em uma codebase gigante, é muito bacana quando o programador antes de nós escreveu `int?` em vez de apenas `int` para tornar claro que o método `buscarReferenciaPlaca` pode não retornar um inteiro válido (especialmente quando estamos lidando com uma API SOAP, por exemplo). (2/3)

Comment: Reitero: Eu não acho que usar `-1` no caso da busca linear é um problema, mas eu aprecio o uso de ferramentas mais semânticas para _este tipo de situação_. O FSharp é um belo exemplo disso, onde existe a função `findIndex` e `tryFindIndex`, que lança uma exception e retorna um mônada, respectivamente, caso o índice não seja encontrado. Isso facilita bastante composição de funções. Não estou dizendo que você está errado, estou apenas extendendo o assunto para as pessoas que lerem a sua resposta. (3/3)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui também podes optar por outras soluções como lançar uma exceção quando falha a pesquisa, ou passar uma flag por paramento que faz um efeito semelhante ao retorno do -1. No entanto esta ultima solução não é recomendada por motivos vários.

Basicamente, como disse o Maniero, o importante é que tu tenhas a indicação de que não encontrou e que esta informação não apresente duvidas.