# O que estou fazendo de errado? Java exceptions

Tags: java

Main (TesteExceptions.java:14):

```
Conta c1 = new ContaCorrente(444, 444);
    c1.setSaldo(5000);
    Conta c2 = new ContaCorrente(444, 445);
    c2.setSaldo(353);

    System.out.println(c1.getSaldo() + "\n" + c2.getSaldo());

    c1.transfere(c2, 1);

    System.out.println(c1.getSaldo() + "\n" + c2.getSaldo());
```

Método transfere (Conta.java:22):

```
public void transfere(Conta destino, double valor){
    if (this.getSaldo() >= valor) {
        if (this != destino) {
            this.saca(valor);
            destino.deposita(valor);
        }
        throw new AccountException("you can not make transfers to your own account");
    }
}
```

Método saca (ContaCorrente.java:25):

```
@Override
public void saca(double valor) {
    if (this.getSaldo() >= valor) {
        super.setSaldo(super.getSaldo() - valor - this.taxa);
    }
    throw new BalanceException("you tried to withdraw a higher amount than the balance in your account");
}
```

Saída console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> 5000.0
>   353.0 Exception in thread "main" br.com.***.***.exceptions.BalanceException: you tried to withdraw a
>   higher amount than the balance in your account    at
>   br.com.***.***.ContaCorrente.saca(ContaCorrente.java:25)  at
>   br.com.***.***.Conta.transfere(Conta.java:22)     at
>   br.com.***.***.TesteExceptions.main(TesteExceptions.java:14)

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Essa exceção não é do java. Forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel verificar o problema.

Comment: Alias, parece uma regra de negocio, não é um erro.

Comment: Na minha concepção está lançando uma exceção onde deveria usar outro mecanismo. Mas já desisti de fazer as pessoas entenderem isso. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101 Sem falar em usar `double` para valor monetário.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você esta sempre passando pelo seu `throw`, entrando ou não no seu `if`.

Coloque ele dentro do `else`

```
@Override
public void saca(double valor) {
  if (this.getSaldo() >= valor) {
    super.setSaldo(super.getSaldo() - valor - this.taxa);
  }else{
    throw new BalanceException("you tried to withdraw a higher amount than the balance in your account");
  }
}
```

Mesma coisa acontece no seu outro método.

```
public void transfere(Conta destino, double valor){
  if (this.getSaldo() >= valor) {
    if (this != destino) {
        this.saca(valor);
        destino.deposita(valor);
    }else{
       throw new AccountException("you can not make transfers to your own account");
    }
  }
}
```