# Pode adicionar a keyword "noexcept" em métodos get/set?

Tags: c++, exceção, c++11

Existe algum problema em adicionar a *keyword* `noexcept` em métodos *getters*/*setters* de uma classe que apenas retorna ou altera valores de variáveis simples (`bool`, `int`, `float`, `double`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre pode existir um problema em adicionar alguma coisa se não souber o que está fazendo.  E sempre é uma solução se souber.

Eu imagino que pelo menos saiba para que o `noexcept` existe. E espero que saiba que exceções costumam ser abusadas, e o mais correto é só usar quando há situações excepcionais.

Você acha que um *getter*, ou seja, um simples método que deve retornar algo deva lançar uma exceção? Geralmente dizemos que não, mas só for garantido que sempre será simples. Se ele puder se tornar complexo pode ser que alguma exceção seja lançada, por exemplo se o acesso ao dado passar a vir de um banco de dados. Um *setter* isto já é menos verdade porque é comum que tenha uma validação. Mesmo assim em casos simples recomenda-se evitar a exceção.

Se estes métodos são usados como acesso à propriedades geralmente deve-se proibir o uso de exceção porque aquilo funciona praticamente como acesso à variável. Neste caso a semântica correta é nunca lançar exceção, portanto é até indicado que coloque o `noexcept` assim vira um compromisso formal no código.

Em métodos que por acaso são *getters* ou *setters*, mas que fazem coisas complexas que seria natural que uma exceção fosse lançada então mesmo que não lance agora pode precisar lançar depois e aí é melhor não dar essa garantia.

Na verdade tem duas coisas aí. Especialmente em C++ *getters* e *setters* são bem menos usado, os programadores (de verdade) desta linguagem estão em nível mais acima dos chamados programadores *enterprise* e entendem que eles não são tão úteis assim e porque eles foram inventados, aí eles sabem que não devem usar como outros programadores o fazem. Mas também sabem quando usar. Inclusive, ao contrário do que as pessoas dizem, ele vai contra os preceitos básicos da orientação a objeto. Não que sejam proibidos, mas na forma que fazem, costuma estar errado.

Outra é que em C++ evita-se muito o uso de exceção, geralmente ele é um mecanismo intrusivo. É mais comum [retornar um erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Geralmente algo não dar erro em um momento e depois passar dar erro já é suficiente pra ter que mudar tudo no software, por isso o contrato deve ser muito bem pensado antes de fazer. Esse é o segredo. Se existe a chance de um dia um erro ser possível quando você pode não tê-lo agora isso já deveria prever. Se faz um retorno de erro, a assinatura do método já tem que estar preparado para isto e vai te acompanhar sempre, mesmo que de fato nunca dê erro de verdade. A escolha da exceção é a mesma coisa. Se acha que um dia pode ter a assinatura deve refletir isso, e aí usar `noexcept` seria errado, mesmo que uma exceção não é lançada.

Algumas pessoas devem pensar que a exceção é uma benção porque ao contrário do retorno de erro que você deve garantir que o contrato está correto, ela pode ser colocada só depois porque o `noexcept` não é obrigatório, aí na dúvida a pessoa faz uma escolha, possivelmente errada, para quem sabe ficar protegido disso. E muitas vezes vai resolver a questão com exceção quando ela não é adequada porque é ficou mais fácil que mudar a assinatura da função. Ou seja, um erro atrás do outro por abuso do mecanismo e desconhecimento do conceito correto.

Exceção é sempre mais problemática do que as pessoas acham, ela tem implicações que "ninguém" enxerga. Também é verdade que no geral as pessoas hoje em dia fazem software tão descompromissadamente, sem qualidade que isto deixa de ser importante. Não à toa que mesmo sendo uma linguagem mais difícil, códigos feitos em C++ costumam ter menos *bugs* que outros códigos, justamente porque os programadores costumam ser mais compromissados a entender o que estão fazendo. Pra tudo tem exceção (desculpe o trocadilho).

Então não tem problema algum em usar o `noexcept`, afinal você sabe o que está fazendo, certo? Não usar não é deixar de tomar uma decisão, é tomar a decisão que pode ter exceção, e isso complica todas as outras decisões sobre o código, sobre as otimizações que o compilador pode fazer.

E você sabe que não é só questão do seu método lançar exceção, se ele chama algum função que pode lançar exceção ele automaticamente pode lançar exceção. E aí colocar `noexcept` é um erro. Daí notamos como é importante, porque ajuda você definir um novo método que usa algo entro dele se terá exceção ou não.

Comment: "os programadores (de verdade)" — Quem? Isso é falácia de *no true scotsman*.

Answer (score 1):

De uma resposta numa [pergunta similar no Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21331592/9629768):

Colocar `noexcept` é um pouco comprometedor. Se no futuro você depender de mudar o tipo de retorno dessa função para algum que possa lançar exceção (`std::string`, por exemplo, que o autor original aponta) pode ser que acabe quebrando a base de código porque em algum ponto alguém assumiu que a sua função não lançaria exceção em nenhum caso.

Basicamente, só adicione `noexcept` se realmente fizer sentido e trouxer algum ganho assegurar para quem usa a função que ela não vai lançar uma exceção.

Pro caso desses getters e setters, é quase redundante colocar, então eu diria que até não tem problema colocar. Só vai servir pra te fazer escrever mais e pode ser que quebre alguma coisa se você decidir usar algum tipo de wrapper (vai que você decide usar um `BigInteger`?) pros valores, mas não como se a gente saísse por aí jogando blocos `try`/`catch` em getters também.