# Capturando erros no MessageHandler

Tags: c#, .net, handler

Olá estou tentando tratar os erros na minha aplicação fazendo o uso do `DelegatingHandler`. Mas estou com um problema, utilizei um `try-catch` para fazer o tratamento dos erros. O `try-catch` engloba o `SendAsync`, acontece que ao lançar qualquer exceção do Controller da WebApi ela é tratada em algum lugar que eu desconheço. Ele me retorna apenas o status 500 no handler.

> Exemplo: ResponseHandler.cs

```
public class ResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
              response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch(MinhaException ex)
        {
             // faz algo
        }
        catch(MinhaException2 ex)
        {
             // faz algo
        }
        catch(MinhaException3 ex)
        {
             // faz algo
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             // faz algo
        }

        return response;
   }
}
```

> Exemplo: MeuController.cs

```
public class MeuController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public string TesteErrorHandler(int erro)
   {
        switch(erro)
        {
              case 1:
                 throw new MinhaException("Erro 1");
              case 2:
                 throw new MinhaException1("Erro 2");
              case 3:
                 throw new MinhaException2("Erro 3");
              case 4:
                 throw new MinhaException3("Erro 4");
        }
        return "Sem erros..";
   }
}
```

Onde essa exceção está sendo tratada? Ela não cai nos meus blocos `try-catch` do `MessageHandler` por qual motivo? Como eu poderia contornar para chegar ao resultado esperado dessa forma, ou de uma forma parecida.

Comment: Está aprendendo que exceção é o mecanismo mais mal usado da programação hoje em dia, bem pior que o `goto` que as pessoas falam mal, justamente por isso que está vendo agora, ela é um `goto` que você não sabe pra onde vai, especialmente em código assíncrono.

Comment: Entendi @Maniero que situação chata, parece que é tratada em alguma camada da WebApi antes de chegar aos MessageHandlers. Eu não sei se a tratativa que desejo realizar é correta fazendo o uso de Handlers, saberia me indicar uma solução de contorno para que eu atinga um resultado equivalente?

Comment: Não usar exceção. Tenho bem pouca experiência com código `async`, só fiz o arroz com feijão, pode ter uma solução com exceção para isto, mas eu acho mais fácil comunicar erros de outra forma como eu falo em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101

Comment: Eu li a resposta @Maniero, parabéns, muito bem explicado! O meu post foi um exemplo, hoje a aplicação que estou trabalhando já encontra-se implementada, ela é enorme e continua crescendo. Nos controllers é passado para as classes de regra e as classes de regras lançam exceções para regras de negócios que são violadas (e os controllers tem os seus try-catch). Os tratamentos nos controllers são iguais para todos os casos, o que gera um over head de + de 40 mil linhas de códigos desnecessários. Meu objetivo com essa solução é diminuir esse over head.

Comment: Ali eu não falo tão diretamente ,mas exceção para regra de negócio é simplesmente um erro. Se algo é igual crie uma abstração que generalize isso. Se fizer certo sem usar exceção tem que ser quase o mesmo tamanho. Aí que entra o trabalho do desenvolvedor, analisar o problema e achar e melhor solução, essa já ficou claro que é problemática. Eu não sei nem se esse `async` deveria existir, até parece que sim, mas não tenho certeza, esse é o segundo recurso mais mal usado da programação hoje dia. Antes dele existir todo mundo se virava bem sem.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu faria algo assim, vê se te ajuda

```
 public class ResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
       private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ResponseHandler));

       protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                  response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch(MinhaException ex)
            {
                 _logger.Error("seu erro": {0}");
                throw;
            }
            catch(MinhaException2 ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("seu erro": {0}");
                throw;
            }
            catch(MinhaException3 ex)
            {
                 _logger.Error("seu erro": {0}");
                throw;`insira o código aqui`
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("seu erro": {0}");
                throw;
            }
    
            return response;
       }
    }
```