# Abrir nova aba no Firefox e Edge com JS

Tags: javascript, null

Devido a restrição que o *browser* faz a *scripts* rodados internos, pedindo a confirmação usando o código:

```
window.open()
```

encontrei a seguinte maneira para retirar essa permissão ao usuário:

```
var win = window.open();
win.location = URL;
win.opener = null;
win.blur();
win.focus();
```

funciona no Chrome, porém no Firefox e no Edge não, dá esse erro:

> Unable to set property 'location' of undefined or null reference

Alguém sabe uma maneira para conseguir executar essa ação em todos navegadores?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Depende do que deseja fazer. Se for olhar a [documentação do método `open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) do objeto `window` verá que tem 3 parâmetros, e 2 deles são obrigatórios, e você não está passando-os, portanto ele não pode produzir um resultado adequado e ele gera um valor nulo, depois disso obviamente não pode fazer nenhuma operação funcionar em um objeto que sequer existe. Abrir uma janela é uma operação que pode falhar muito, no meu navegador falhará sempre, não pode confiar nisso.

Uma coisa que eu vejo muito, principalmente em códigos JS é que as pessoas usam objetos sem ter certeza que eles estão lá. Mesmo que você faça tudo certo tem vários motivos para dar algo errado e qualquer operação deveria ser testada antes de tentar executá-la. Esta técnica adotada por todo JS é de [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) (ele devolve um `null` se algo deu errado) e como foi abusado e dado na mão de programadores pouco experientes em geral dá um monte de problema, por isso é importante mudar a forma de fazer as coisas e não confiar nos resultados que obtém nunca, mesmo quando parece que fez tudo certo. Para isso é necessário ler detalhadamente a documentação de tudo o que vai usar, sob pena de ter um monte de erros inesperados no que está fazendo e nem ter ideia porque ocorre, o que fazer, ou mesmo reproduzi-lo porque pode ocorrer apenas em certos cenários.

Neste caso específico nem é um erro pontual, é erro de programação e embora ainda seja válido e necessário fazer a verificação se objeto foi criado adequadamente, para o seu código antes disso é preciso chamar o método de forma correta passando no mínimo um URL e um nome da janela, conforme instrui a documentação. Mas não quer dizer que feito isso está resolvido, lembre-se que muita coisa poderá falhar, só o fato de você achar que pode sempre abrir um janela é um alerta que se liga no seu código. Se fez algo que depende da abertura de janela para funcionar já fez algo errado, isto não está disponível em todos casos.