# Tem alguma diferença entre as duas formas de lançar uma exceção?

Tags: javascript, exceção, estilo-de-codificação

Entre os dois formatos abaixo, o `throw` pode ser resumido, ou criar um objeto novo, ao lançar exceção, eu só queria entender qual o real significado de escrever isso de formas diferentes, tem algum motivo que torna importante serem diferentes, e porque a segunda me retorna só a mensagem, e a outra me retorna:

> `Error: Falha temporária do servidor at <anonymous>:5:9`?

```
try {

  //...ações
  if(error)
  throw new Error('Falha temporária do servidor');

} catch(e) {
   console.log(e)

}
```

e

```
try {

  //...ações
  if(error)
   throw 'Falha temporária do servidor';

} catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: sim, o segundo será retornado no catch uma string e no primeiro será retornando o objeto Error, que tem a propriedade `.message`, `.fileName`, `.lineNumber`, `.columnNumber` e `.stack` e você ainda pode customizar informando um arquivo ou linha diferente: `new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem um contexto maior mas pra mim é um erro fazer ambas. Se você tem um erro e pode verificá-lo então o faça ali mesmo. Não use `try-catch` a não ser que seja necessário.

Lançar um `Error` quase sempre é um erro. Lançar alguma classe que herda dele pode ser útil em alguns casos.

O primeiro código você está lançando um `Error` se já sabe que existe um erro, isto se dá porque essa variável já indica isso, algum mecanismo que usou te dá um resultado que indica isto. Este erro cria um objeto complexo de erro que é entendido pelo `catch`, portanto o objeto `e` receberá justamente esse objeto que contém uma série de informações, entre elas a mensagem que você usou para criar objeto, então quando manda imprimir esse objeto ele mostra essa mensagem e mais alguma informações relevante que esse objeto tem. Esse objeto ganha informações da situação da execução naquele momento. Tem outras informações que não são mostradas por padrão. Se quiser saber mais sobre este objeto leia a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) (note que a implementação pode não ter nada além da mensagem).

O segundo código lança um erro mas não cria um objeto complexo, ele gera só uma *string*, então quando esse objeto é recebido em `e` no `catch` é esse objeto que seja impresso, portanto só a mensagem sem nada adicional.

O segundo eu diria que é mais errado porque ele não faz nada interessante, é o mesmo que fazer:

```
//...ações
if (error) console.log('Falha temporária do servidor');
```

O primeiro até tem alguma utilidade porque coleta informações sobre a execução que podem ser usadas, mas assim é melhor:

```
//...ações
if (error) console.log(new Error('Falha temporária do servidor'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ExceptionXError.js).

Não use exceções para controle de fluxo, ainda mais para desviar um fluxo que não precisa ser desviado. Leia mais em [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101), eu falo até deste padrão usado aqui.

Answer (score -3):

O primeiro exemplo recebe um objeto com diversas informações importantes, junto com a mensagem de erro.

O segundo exemplo só recebe a mensagem.