# "null" é um valor ou um estado em que a propriedade se encontra?

Tags: null, independente-de-linguagem, ciência-da-computação

Ao checar se uma propriedade/variável/objeto é nula(o), estamos verificando o valor  ou o estado dela? Por exemplo, se tenho o objeto `Quadrilátero` com as propriedades `LadoA` e `LadoB` não será possível acessar as propriedades deste objeto até que o mesmo seja instanciado. Em se tratando de variáveis, se eu tenho uma variável que é populada por um dado do banco de dados e este retornar `null` ela estará com o valor `null`, então `null`neste caso é um valor e não um estado em que a variável se encontra ? Resumidamente minha dúvida é se `null`é um valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um banco de dados não retorna `null`. Um método de alguma biblioteca que está usando pode retornar `null` e você pode guardar este valor em uma variável. Nem todas as linguagens permitem isto, mas entendo que esteja falando de uma que permite. Nem todas as bibliotecas usam esta forma de indicar que nada foi possível retornar do banco de dados. Este é um [código de erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101).

A pergunta parte de uma falsa premissa que um valor e um estado são coisas distintas. Na verdade o valor é o estado da variável naquele momento. Então `null` é as duas coisas.

`null` é um valor que costuma-se dizer ser do tipo dele próprio, um tipo cujo valor só pode ser `null`. Há linguagens que conceituam um pouco diferente, mas nunca é muito diferente disto, algumas até usam outro nome como `nil` ou `none`. De qualquer forma costuma ser a ausência de valor **válido**. Note que não é bem ausência de valor como costuma-se dizer informalmente.

Em algumas linguagens o valor `null` só pode ser usado em tipos por referência já que a referência é que é nula e portanto impede acessar um objeto válido. Em tipos por valor não tem como representar a nulidade de forma direta (dá para criar um tipo composto).

Em linguagens de tipagem estática podemos falar que isto é uma violação da tipagem já que uma variável pode ter dois tipos diferentes de dados, um é o valor válido, o objeto do seu tipo, e o outro é um `null` que no fundo é um valor de outro tipo.

Então uma variável (ou propriedade) tem um valor válido ou inválido (`null`), e está em estado válido ou inválido (indicado por `null`). É só uma discussão semântica, na melhor das hipóteses.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).