# Por que retorna "undefined" em função que tem um "if/else"?

Tags: javascript, if, return, undefined

Tenho essa condição logica usando o `if`/`else`:

```js
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura
    if (area > 20) {
        console.log(`O valor acima do permitido: ${area}m2.`)
    } else {
        return area
    }
}

console.log(area(5, 5)) //retorna no console "25m2 undefined".
```

Até onde sabia caso a condição `if` fosse verdadeira, ele não lia a condição do `else`. Contudo nessa instrução ele está lendo o `else` retornando o resultado `undefined`. Por que isso ocorre?

Comment: esse undefined deve ser o retorno da função area(5, 5), dentro do seu if ele escreve no console e nao retorna nada por isso da undefined

Comment: Entao, mas ele retornou o resultado 25m²...ainda nao entendi pq ele renderizou o else, se a condição do if é verdadeira!

Comment: fez debug para ter certeza de onde está passando e o que esá mostrado undefined?

Comment: Não passou pelo else, o @kervincandido já explicou o problema

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Muito simplesmente o código não está a ler a condição `else`.

O código não está a retornar nenhum resultado dentro da condição `if`, por isso quando a função acaba de ser executada o valor retornado é `undefined`, porque não foi definido nenhum valor.
Quando é feito o log do valor é isso mesmo que ele vai escrever.

```js
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura
    if (area > 20) {
        console.log(`O valor acima do permitido: ${area}m2.`)
    } else {
       return area
    }
}

// Aqui faz print de undefined porque não é retornado nenhum valor da função
console.log(area(5, 5))
```

### [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

O valor global `undefined` representa um valor indefinido. Trata-se de um dos tipos primitivos do JavaScript.

Uma função retorna `undefined` se um valor não for retornado.

### Nota

Editei a resposta e removi a proposta de código considerando os comentários deixados e a questão colocada.

Retornar `undefined`, `false`, `null`, `0`, etc. é subjectivo à intenção do programador e aplicação do código.
Deve ser sempre considerado quem vai usar o código e o que é considerado um comportamento normal ou excepcional.

Inicialmente esta resposta sugeria uma abordagem com `return false`.
Pode encontrar argumentos a favor e contra nos comentários.

Comment: Dois `return` seguidos? Como o segundo será executado?

Comment: Bem visto @Maniero. Estou a alterar a resposta para ter isso em consideração, mas de qualquer forma não se deve deixar passar `undefined`

Comment: Eu gosto da tua explicação, mas como ainda não tenho reputação suficiente não podia deixar comentário na tua resposta relativamente à questão do `undefined`.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para mostrar porque sua resposta não é boa.

Comment: @Maniero agradeço o esforço para dar uma boa resposta, mas a realidade é que os parâmetros de saída devem ser sempre tratados (tal como os de entrada). `undefined` não é uma boa resposta para uma função. Se no código dele não existe retorno para valores superiores a 20, então fazer com que dê erro, não pode ser solução. O erro deve ser tratado de alguma forma. E se ele quiser somar todas as áreas? Nesse caso a tua sugestão não funciona, porque falha com resultados `undefined`. Depende sempre da abordagem do developer. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he1wzncy/2/)

Comment: Sim, quando o cálculo tem parâmetros de entrada errados é para falhar. O objetivo é justamente esse. Esse JSFiddle mostra o absurdo que é retornar qualquer coisa diferente de `undefined`. Ele dá um resultado completamente errado, você não pode somar algo com o que não pode ser calculado, só um erro é aceitável nesse caso. Você está fazendo o inexiste se transformar em 0, mas o inexistente é diferente de 0, zero é um valor válido,inexistente é inválido.Uma resposta errada é uma boa resposta para uma função?È o q a sua responde, você trata o erro como se fosse uma resposta válida e arbitra ser 0

Comment: Como assim `undefined` não é uma boa resposta para uma função? Então a própria API da linguagem está toda errada, tem muitas funções nativas que retornam `undefined` para indicar uma condição excepcional ou valor inválido (e quem chamou a função que trate de verificar o retorno para saber se deu certo - o tratamento do erro, no caso, fica fora da função, pois ela só indica o que aconteceu - até porque o tratamento pode variar, então faz mais sentido ficar fora mesmo).

Comment: @hkotsubo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101

Comment: @Maniero O objectivo de retornar `false` não é para permitir a soma. Não interessa se o JS permite isso (JS tem os seus problemas). O que interessa é que a função dá uma resposta válida. Uma excepção desta função não é "a área ultrapassou o valor", mas sim "não consegue calcular o valor". Ultrapassar o valor é uma questão de lógica de negócio e lógica de negócio não é excepção. Fazer contas directas com "funções que já sabes que podem retornar resultados problemáticos" é outro problema.

Comment: Se o JS tem problemas, você tem que contornar, não causar mais problemas. Sim, o objetivo do seu código é dar uma resposta válida, até quando ela é inválida, isso é um erro crasso. è outro problema? E como você resolve? Como você garante que ele não estrague todo o código sem o consumidor nem perceba?

Comment: problema resolvido @Maniero

Comment: Não é subjetivo, isso é um erro claro. Se você falasse que prefere usar exceção para lidar com isso eu até aceitaria como subjetivo, porque é uma solução, apesar de que a cultura de JS é não usar isso. Uma solução que causa problemas silenciosamente é ruim para todo mundo, não tem subjetividade nisso. Agora não propôs uma solução, mas tudo bem essa página toda foi um problema desde o início e agora está fechada e escondida dos demais, não causará problemas extras para quem está aprendendo.

Answer (score 3):

Ele não entra no `else` em momento algum, e esse é o problema, no `else` retorna alguma coisa, quando entra no `if` ele retornada nada, que é indefinido, e é isso que precisa de verdade.

Acho que é isso que deseja, se não for o problema não está bem definido e todo o código está errado.

```js
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura;
    if (area > 20) {
        console.log(`O valor acima do permitido: ${area}m2.`);
    } else {
        return area;
    }
}

let resultado = area(5, 5);
if (resultado != undefined) console.log(resultado);
console.log(area(5, 5) + 1);
resultado = area(4, 5);
if (resultado != undefined) console.log(resultado);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Area.js).

O `if` é usado para validação do parâmetro, então se ele estiver fora do critério informado ele mostra uma mensagem do *log* e encerra a função retornando nada, e essa parte é muito importante, como ele não calculou nada o resultado da função é um valor indefinido. Imagino que seja isso que quer, caso não seja, o código está completamente errado e não temos como resolver o problema porque não sabemos o que deve fazer, só podemos ajudar o que está na pergunta.

Então esta é uma função que pode ou não dar um resultado, se o parâmetro está ok ele retorna um resultado válido, se o parâmetro passado não for adequado gera um valor ruim e não retorna um resultado válido, portanto retorna um `undefined`.

O que fazer para usar a função se ela pode retornar um valor inválido? Deve testar se o valor é válido antes de usá-lo. Esse é um padrão de projeto dos mais conhecidos e usados.

Então guarda o resultado em uma variável e faz um `if` para ver se o valor é válido, e só se for é que pode usar a variável em algum lugar, como imprimí-la por exemplo.

Mas se não quer que retorne um valor inválido aí teria que tirar a condição e aceitar qualquer valor passado. Claro, tem alternativas, mas não é comum ser usada, especialmente em JavaScript. Poderia lançar uma exceção, que por sorte não está na cultura de JS, e teria que tratar na chamada, só muda o jeito de tratar. Ou teria que retornar um valor válido mesmo sendo inválido, o que fará o código ser inconfiável, não faria sentido.

Note que se fizer uma conta com o resultado indefinido dá um resultado inválido e isso fica óbvio, você terá que fazer algo para lidar com isso.

## Mantenha o `undefined`

Por que a resposta aceita não é boa? Veja abaixo que em um conta ela dá um resultado equivocado silenciosamente, se você não tomar cuidado causa um enorme estrago. A minha solução faz dar um erro claro e óbvio, não dá para continuar com aquele valor.

```js
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura;
    if (area > 20) {
       // Ou retornas false ou null
       console.log(`O valor acima do permitido: ${area}m2.`);
       return false;
    } else {
       return area;
    }
}

console.log(area(5, 5) + 1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Area2.js).

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois quando você executa uma função com `console.log(myFunction())` ele espera algum `return` da sua função.

O seu `if` ocorre corretamente, e executa o seu `console.log()`, mas você executa a função atráves do `console.log()` ele espera algum `return` e não retorna nada.

Com isso o `JS` mostra `undefined`.

Para resolver isso, você poderia trocar o `console.log()` por um `return`, ficaria assim:

```js
function area(largura, altura) {
    const area = largura * altura;
    if (area > 20) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return area;
    }
}

var valor = area(4, 5);

if(!valor)
{
  console.log("Os valores informados são altos demais.");
}else{
  console.log(valor);
}
```

Comment: E se isso for usado em uma conta?

Comment: Não sei o que isso seria, sou iniciante, você poderia me explicar?

Comment: Olhe a minha resposta.

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, ficou melhor?

Comment: melhorou, mas ainda cai no problema que eu falo na minha resposta.

Comment: Não tinha percebido isso, teria alguma maneira de resolver esse problema de uma maneira diferente da sua resposta?

Comment: Tem, mas acho mais complicado, se fosse alguma que acho adequada eu teria postado.

Comment: Ok, marquei a resposta como wiki, muito obrigado