# Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?

Tags: java, exceção

Quem já criou grandes programas em Java sabe de uma dor-de-cabeça muito comum: Não saber pra onde jogar o fluxo das *Exceptions*. Muitos resolvem fazer coisas como:

> Tratar tudo como *Exception* (a superclasse de qualquer *Exception*) e quando uma vir, dar uma mensagem qualquer ao usuário e jogar a *StackTrace* num arquivo de log.

> Tratar tudo como *Exception*, mas, dessa vez, já que o programa é realmente muito grande e o cliente provavelmente não está olhando para o console, imprimir a *StackTrace* e continuar normalmente.

> Avisar o usuário que um erro aconteceu e dar um tratamento genérico.

Entre outros.

Apesar do que eu disse acima estar muito presente no meio profissional essas abordagens acima soam muito "[POG](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Gambiarras)".

Se essas exceções foram lançadas, é porque algo deu errado! Mas o problema é que numa simples operação pode acontecer tanta coisa, que é realmente tedioso dar conta de tudo. Além do que, boa parte dos possíveis "erros" são extremamente improváveis.

Além do mais, o mecanismo de erros do Java não é nada preciso: Uma *IOException* foi lançada? Sim, mas na realidade há tantas subclasses que fica difícil saber o que fazer: *FileNotFoundException*, *EOFException*, etc... Se uma *IOException* foi lançada, como propriamente tratar o erro sem nenhuma especificação do que precisamente aconteceu?

Dentro de tudo isso, eu pergunto: Qual a maneira mais eficiente e elegante de tratar *Exceptions* em Java?

Comment: Muito do que você mencionou atualmente é resolvido com GHP (go horse process) ou [XGH](http://bit.ly/1ssehq2) (extreme go horse), muito adequado pra PHP e Java. Se bem que o próprio PHP é desenvolvido com princípios POG, que é diferente de GHP.

Comment: +1 só pelo link POG :D

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Referências

Eu tenho falado bastante a respeito. Mesmo não sendo específico sobre Java a essência vale para ele. Veja em:

- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101)
- [Como interceptar exceções quando se trabalha com o Entity Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21278/101)
- [Usando as palavras-chave Throws e Throw](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101)
- [Diferenças entre Parse() vs TryParse()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)
- [Melhor maneira de tratar Exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101)
- [Exception vs RuntimeException, quando utilizar um ou outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55624/101)

Evidentemente lembro mais do que eu respondi mas existem casos de outros *posts* bem interessantes nas mesmas perguntas ou outras. É fácil achar no site.

## Importância do assunto

E o assunto é importante porque os programadores realmente não sabem como usar adequadamente. O que mostra o que eu digo que lidar com exceções não é algo trivial. Eu tenho aprendido muito sobre elas escrevendo estes *posts*. O perigo é quem acha que sabe tudo sobre o assunto é não precisa mais aprender nada.

Costuma-se defender as exceções porque ao contrário de códigos de erro elas obrigam o programador tratá-las. Mas não obrigam tratá-las adequadamente. Então vemos tantos `catch (Exception e)`. O programador que não quiser fazer algo não fará. Capturar uma `Exception` deveria ser proibido no fluxo normal de um programa (no `Main()` ou perto dele, pode ser ok para dar a última ação antes da aplicação quebrar).

Capturar exceções muito genéricas escondem erros de programação. Quando o programador tenta capturar algo que ele não sabe bem o porque e o que pode vir ele acaba capturando o que não devia, acaba tratando de algo que não deveria ser tratado ou que deveria ser tratado de outra forma. O programa deve **capturar a exceção mais especializada possível que possa fazer algo útil**.

## Pegando seu exemplo:

Se você está trabalhando com acesso a arquivos e precisa fazer algo quando dá **qualquer** problema na tentativa de manipulação dos arquivos, não importa se o arquivo não existe, se chegou ao seu fim inesperadamente ou não há permissão de acesso, há uma ação única que deve ser feita, qual é a exceção mais especializada necessária? Provavelmente a `IOException`. Mas e se você precisa apresentar uma mensagem de erro na tela quando o arquivo não existe ou tem que fazer uma tarefa específica quando o fim do arquivo for alcançado inesperadamente? Aí as exceções mais especializadas precisam ser capturadas antes e possivelmente a `IOException` em seguida para outros problemas de IO de forma mais geral.

#### Exceção especializada X generalizada

O programador e só ele no caso específico poderá saber se ele precisa escolher uma exceção mais especializada ou outra um pouco menos especializada. Não há receita de bolo. Exemplos até podem ajudar mas muitas vezes eles são interpretados como receitas de bolo e a má utilização se perpetua.

> Tratar tudo como Exception (a superclasse de qualquer Exception) e quando uma vir, dar uma mensagem qualquer ao usuário e jogar a StackTrace num arquivo de log

Isto não é problema se for feito no local correto. Fazer isto no miolo do programa certamente não é certo. O que falou aí é *"e depois deixar quebrar"*. Se o programa capturar uma `Exception` tem uma enorme chance de ter capturado um erro de programação. Aí não tem mais nada o que fazer.

> Tratar tudo como Excpetion, mas, dessa vez, já que o programa é realmente muito grande e o cliente provavelmente não está olhando para o console, imprimir a StackTrace e continuar normalmente.

Programador a procura de problemas. Só tem algo pior, engolir totalmente a exceção.

> Avisar ao usuário de que um erro aconteceu e dar uma tratamento genérico.

Se for totalmente genérico cai no problema acima.

#### Saber o que resolver o problema

> Mas o problema é que numa simples operação pode acontecer tanta coisa que é realmente tedioso dar conta de tudo

A regra básica é não capturar uma exceção que você não sabe ou não pode fazer algo realmente útil, que solucione o problema de alguma forma. Não pode fazer por querer, muito menos sem querer. Por isso não pode usar exceções genéricas demais para a situação. Os programadores se entediam porque eles tentar capturar exceções demais, exceções que não deveriam ser capturadas. Os programadores se condicionaram a acreditar que capturar exceções diminuem os *bugs* dos programas. Indiscriminadamente elas tendem a complicar a solução de *bugs*, elas escondem os *bugs*.

> boa parte dos possíveis "erros" são extremamente improváveis

Improváveis porque? Porque não deveriam acontecer em produção? Se for isto, não trate-os. Se for uma situação inesperada, porém possível, apesar de improvável, aí tem que tratar, não tem escolha para fazer um programa robusto.

O que dá para fazer, é criar **classes utilitárias que centralizam estes tratamentos**. Até para não violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Depois de um tempo, você praticamente não precisa fazer tratamentos novos, só usa a sua biblioteca. Claro, as capturas ainda precisam ser feitas no locais corretos.

> Se uma IOException foi lançada, como propriamente tratar o erro sem nenhuma especificação do que precisamente aconteceu?

É um caso de captura um pouco mais genérica (só o suficiente) e uso das informações mais específicas genericamente (apresentando-as ou *logando-as*, por exemplo). Não é porque o programa captura uma `IOException` que as informações específicas do `FileNotFoundException` não estão disponíveis na variável usada na captura. Não é solução para tudo, mas serve bem em alguns casos. Se a ação pode ser a mesma, mas só a mensagem precisa ser específica, a captura deve ser feita nesta um pouco mais genérica.

> fica difícil saber o que fazer

Ou está mal informado ou é porque não precisa fazer nada com esta exceção específica.

Java tem a vantagem discutível de indicar na API quando uma exceção **deve** ser tratada. Pena que nem todos os programadores usam o recurso corretamente, aí os consumidores de uma API acabam sofrendo para tratar de algo que ele não deveria. Isto é outro problema. Nestes casos, a única coisa que não pode fazer é fazer de conta que não tem nada para fazer e simular uma ação só para atender o requisito da API (o [`throws`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101)).

Quando você sabe o que fazer com a exceção ela normalmente deve ser capturada o mais perto possível de onde ela foi lançada. O tratamento deve ser feito bem perto do erro (claro que o tratamento pode ser delegado para as classes utilitárias).

Tratar exceções específicas pode ser erro também. Capturar uma `NullReferenceException` pra que? Para criar forçadamente uma instância que não conseguiu ser criada antes? O erro está em outro lugar. E ainda há o risco de estar capturando o mesmo erro certo, mas do lugar errado, inesperado. Exceções podem vir de qualquer lugar. No fundo estará tentando usar a exceção para fazer algo que deveria fazer parte do fluxo normal do programa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta, mas há casos em que o uso da exceção é obrigatório, como no tratamento de ficheiros. O que fazer nesses casos?

Comment: Tratar. Chegou falar disto nesta parte final. Mas há uma solução no item "Pegando seu exemplo:". Lá diz que estes casos devem ser tratados tão especializadamente quanto possível. E que em muitos casos isto é apenas capturar a `IOException`. O que fazer, acho que não é a intenção da pergunta, mas normalmente o programador vai tentar novamente algumas vezes e/ou apresentar uma mensagem ao usuário possivelmente dando opções para escolher o que fazer. Existe alguma dúvida específica que eu possa complementar a resposta?

Comment: Por mim fiquei esclarecido. Obrigado

Answer (score 19):

Nota: vou me ater especificamente ao Java e às boas práticas que conheço, pois [esta resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/227) (e outras) já abordam muito bem a questão das exceções de forma geral.

Considero nos tópicos seguintes um sistema desktop ou web, mas não um sistema *batch* sem UI.

## Não mostre erros técnicos ao usuário

Não é incomum um usuário ligar para o suporte e gastar 15 minutos para ler `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ou algo parecido.

[image: Vida de Programador]

Para situações assim, um sistema sempre deve ter uma **captura geral de exceções**, isto é, um `catch (Throwable)` geral para uso em último caso.

Note que isso **não** significa que os desenvolvedores devem delegar todas as exceções para esse tratamento "global", muito pelo contrário.

Este é só um caso de não deixar estourar algo estranho para o usuário na tela. Seria um caso do tipo de erro "desconhecido" ou "inesperado" que exige uma intervenção do administrador e a análise de logs.

## Abuse dos logs

Uma fada morre cada vez que um programador deixa um `catch` vazio:

```java
try {
    //lógica
} catch (Exception e) {
    //nada aqui!!!
}
```

Isso torna achar um erro mais difícil do que jogar na Mega-Sena.

Sempre (repito: sempre!) imprima a pilha do erro, a mensagem e os valores relevantes para um arquivo de log.

Exemplo:

```
try {
    Date data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataStr);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    log.error("Data informada '" + dataStr + "' inválida! " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
}
```

Dessa forma, mesmo que o erro passe desapercebido para o usuário, será facilmente rastreável via análise de log.

## Classifique os erros pertinentes e trate-os

Não gaste tempo demais tentando prever todo tipo imaginável de erro.

*E se o HD do servidor pifar? E se a rede cair? E se o SO travar?*

Erros que não fazem parte da sua regra de negócio em geral não devem ser tratados.

É lógico que há casos onde você depende de um recurso externo e precisa considerar a possibilidade de algo externo ao sistema falhar.

Imagine a situação onde o sistema imprime numa impressora fiscal. Ele precisa avisar se a impressora estiver com problemas, certo? Mas o sistema não é responsável por diagnosticar ou consertar o dispositivo com problemas. Limite-se a um tratamento geral, como o exemplo:

> Ocorreu um erro na impressora e o código retornado foi 123, por favor contate o técnico responsável ou consulte o manual.

## Os casos excepcionais pertinentes deveriam estar previstos nos casos de uso

Foi feito um levantamento de requisitos adequado para o sistema. Se foi, os erros que o usuário deve ser informado provavelmente estarão definidos nos casos de uso ou nos diagramas de atividades.

## O tratamento de erros deve evoluir com o sistema

Na medida em que o sistema vai sendo desenvolvido, testado e avaliado pelo usuário provavelmente surgirão novos possíveis casos excepcionais.

Algumas vezes vale a pena ir acrescentando tratamentos mais específicos para esses casos.

Por exemplo, imagine que o sistema lê um arquivo de uma pasta compartilhada na rede. Na primeira implementação foi feito um tratamento genérico de `IOException`.

Cada vez que ocorre um erro na leitura do arquivo, deve-se verificar se a rede está funcionando, se a pasta está realmente compartilhada, se o servidor não caiu, etc. Porém, após alguns testes notou-se que é comum o usuário esquecer de colocar o arquivo lá, então gasta-se muito tempo verificando onde está o problema.

Num caso assim, vale a pena começar a fazer tratamentos específicos para que o próprio usuário possa tomar uma atitude. Aqui, um `FileNotFoundException` é de suma importância.

## Considerações finais

Cada sistema tem suas particularidades quanto ao tratamento de exceções, então temos que identificar os casos relevantes para lidar individualmente, deixando apenas as exceções das exceções para um tratamento mais genérico.

Comment: Era o complemento necessário que eu estava esperando.