# Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'VINET' para o tipo de dados int

Tags: c#, ado.net, winforms

Tenho esse erro:

```
Falha ao converter o nvarchar valor 'VINET' para o tipo de dados int.
```

Abaixo o meu código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try 
            {
                SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();

                dataConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["consBanco"].ToString();

                string sql = "SELECT * " +
                              "FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerIdParam";

                dataConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Connection = dataConnection;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                //SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@CustomerIdParam", SqlDbType.Char, 5);
                //param.Value = customerID;
                //cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerIdParam", 1);

                // cria o dataadapter...
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                // preenche o dataset...
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                grdTeste.DataSource = dataSet;
                grdTeste.DataMember = dataSet.Tables[0].TableName;


            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Só com estas informações fica difícil ajudar. Onde está dando este erro. Não tem nenhum VINET no seu código, de onde vem isto? Você sabe que este `catch` só está dificultando descobrir qual é o erro? Aqui tem um início e vários links (p/ C#) para entender melhor o funcionamento de exceções (não é tão específico p/ Java): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21933/como-melhor-tratar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-java/21939#21939

Comment: Esse erro tá esquisito, ele está em português mesmo? De qualquer forma, esse VINET que não tem no seu código é um texto (`nvarchar` na nomenclatura do SQL ou `string` no C#) e onde está dando o erro está esperando um `int`, então você tem que convertê-lo provavelmente com `int.Parse(VINET.Text)`, mas é uma suposição já que não há informações suficientes. Ou pode fazer um `CAST` no SQL mas duvido que seja isso que você precisa.

Comment: Quando eu tento carregar o grid, é que da a mensagem de erroi no catch. Não a mínima idéia de onde esse erro está acontecendo. O que eu quero é preencher um grid. Não consegui fazer com DataReader e por isso usei o SqlDataAdapter e não sei se é isso.

Comment: Você não tem ideia porque você está matando o erro com o `catch`. Você leu o que eu te passei? Eu sei, é bastante coisa, mas se não entender como exceções funcionam e continuar usando errado, sua vida vai ficar complicada. E aóí se nem você sabe o que está acontecendo com a sua aplicação, pessoas aleatórias na internet tem menos chance ainda de saber. Fico aguardando você dar informações melhores. Ou você aguarda alguém que teve um problema idêntico que possa te ajudar. Não aparece mais nada na tela, só essa mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1):

Foi resolvido da seguinte maneira. Coloquei um ExecuteReader e aí resoloveu. Outra coisa, a coluna do BD estava errada, era nchar e por isso estava dando o erro de VINET. Eu errei por falta de atenção.

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque sua `grdTeste` está esperando uma coluna chamada `VINET`, representada por um inteiro, mas que a coluna do banco é representada por um `nvarchar` ou algum tipo de dados similar.

Mude a coluna `VINET` da `grid` para `String` que o problema será resolvido.