# Qual o diretório do SQLITE?

Tags: android, sqlite

Aonde fica o banco de dados SQLITE que criei na IDE do android studio ? Procurei e não localizei, e nem no próprio celular achei .

Comment: Em geral fica na pasta `/data/data/nome_do_pacote/databases/`. Mas para acessar de fora do aplicativo é preciso ter **root**. Se quiser pode até criar algo no seu app que exporte para uma pasta no **sdcard** ou no `ExternalStorage` e depois acessar pelo **adb** ou pela conexão usb mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Para isso eu fiz:

```
File f=new File("/data/data/seu.app.package/databases/seu_db.db3");
FileInputStream fis=null;
FileOutputStream fos=null;

try
{
  fis=new FileInputStream(f);
  fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/db_dump.db");
  while(true)
  {
    int i=fis.read();
    if(i!=-1)
    {fos.write(i);}
    else
    {break;}
  }
  fos.flush();
  Toast.makeText(this, "DB OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(this, "DB ERRO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
finally
{
  try
  {
    fos.close();
    fis.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {}
}
```

Der a permisão

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Não é brilhante, mas funciona

Comment: Deu medo da maneira como você usa exceções. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/101

Comment: lol. Isso que foi dito depende da aplicação do try catch

Comment: No caso você está aplicando completamente errado.

Comment: bigown, antes de dizer que está errado, deve-se, por regra, apresentar uma resposta por meio de um código ou uma explicação válida.

Comment: Não invente regras que não existem. Eu expliquei em diversas respostas que eu mostrei para você, você leu todas elas? Se não te satisfez então faça uma pergunta especificamente sobre isto que eu respondo.

Comment: Bigown, peço minhas humildes desculpas pela forma com que manifestei minha indagação. Não percebi que você era o autor da referência. Obrigado pela contribuição no pt.stackoverflow.