# Exceção ao buscar no banco SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, exceção, sqlite3

```
12-10 09:25:36.029: D/dalvikvm(21543): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): Build Date: 03/21/14 Fri
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): Local Branch: AU200+patches_03212014
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): Remote Branch: 
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): Local Patches: 
12-10 09:25:36.279: I/Adreno-EGL(21543): Reconstruct Branch: 
12-10 09:25:36.319: D/OpenGLRenderer(21543): Enabling debug mode 0
12-10 09:25:36.389: D/OpenGLRenderer(21543): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
12-10 09:25:36.389: E/OpenGLRenderer(21543):   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
12-10 09:30:52.759: D/OpenGLRenderer(21543): GL error from OpenGLRenderer: 0x502
12-10 09:30:52.769: E/OpenGLRenderer(21543):   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Segue o meu fonte

```
public Cursor LoginExisteBanco(Context context, DB_Helper objDBHelper, CL_Login objLogin){
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = objDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email,senha FROM usuario", null);
        return c;
    }
    catch(SQLException erro)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ele nem cai no catch por esse motivo não consigo ver qual o erro que está acontecendo. Vai direto pro `return null`.

Comment: Está usando um AVD? Veja se o hardware acceleration está setado.

Comment: Adicione: `erro.printStackTrace();` dentro do seu catch, antes do `return null;`. Depois, compartilhe conosco os detalhes da exceção.

Comment: `Log.e("erro", erro.printStackTrace().toString();)` @Math é Android.

Comment: @JorgeB. ops! valeu

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, se está executando o `return null;` então está caindo no `catch`.

Você não consegue ver o erro porque você está escondendo ele. A solução para isto é simples, pare de escondê-lo. Retire o `try-catch` e deixe a aplicação quebrar. Ela mostrará o erro para você.

Sabendo qual é o erro fica mais fácil resolver o que está causando ele.

Os programadores precisam aprender a não usar as coisas de forma automática. Precisa entender porque colocar ou retirar alguma coisa no código sem seguir fórmulas prontas.

Eu [falo bastante sobre exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/101) e como há abuso delas. Não estou dizendo que este seja um caso de abuso no uso normal, mas para achar o problema ela está atrapalhando.

Siga os *links* para resposta que postei e das subsequentes para entender melhor o uso de exceção. Isto é um recurso complexo que é frequentemente mal utilizado trazendo transtornos desnecessários.

É, eu sei, não resolveu seu problema real, mas isto vai te ajudar em todo seu trabalho mais que esta solução. Na atual forma da sua pergunta ninguém pode resolver o problema, nem mesmo você. Eu não respondi isto esperando que esta resposta seja aceita, apenas para acrescentar uma informação importante.

Neste caso específico pode usar a solução postada nos comentários e apenas imprimir o *stack trace* antes de terminar a execução. Nem sempre isto será o melhor a fazer.

Comment: Há certos casos que o try catch é obrigatório senão nem compila @bigown.

Comment: @JorgeB. Por que?

Comment: Java para Android. @bigown

Comment: O @PauloHDSousa respondeu a pergunta.

Comment: Deturparam o Java por completo? Eu pensei que era apenas diferenças de API. Este caso é obrigatório? Há algum lugar que diz isto?

Comment: O Eclipse quando você da play diz que não vai compilar porque pode dar erro. @bigown

Comment: Ou seja, o Eclise tornou qualquer método como *checked exception* por conta própria? Eu vi uns exemplos usando estes métodos sem o `try-catch`. Então parece que é um problema de um IDE mais atrapalhando que ajudando.

Comment: @bigown existem mesmo alguns `try-catch` obrigatórios, como para leitura de ficheiros. Neste caso especifico não é obrigatório. E não é problema do IDE.

Comment: @JorgeB. e é obrigatório mesmo sem o uso do `throws`? Essa é minha dúvida. Se o Java do Android deturpou isto.