# Try e Catch continuar execução (após exception)?

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

Como eu coloco um bloco `try` e `catch` p/ que continue o laço `for`, mesmo que dê `arrayindexofbounds` e entre outras exception? Eu coloco e ele executa mas a saída de "m" não imprime nada depois!

```
for (String f : filename) {
    String temporario[] = f.split("_");
    Date data = new Date(format.parse(temporario[1]).getTime());

    if (m.containsKey(temporario[0])) {
        if (m.get(temporario[0]).before(data)) {
            m.put(temporario[0], data);
        }
    } else {
        m.put(temporario[0], data);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português! Se explicar o que pretende com isso seria mais fácil alguém ajudar. Qual é a ideia de deixar passar um `arrayindexofbounds`, isso seria no mínimo perigoso...

Comment: Você quer ignorar arquivos que não possuem um `_`, é isso? É mais conveniente - e mais performático - simplesmente testar `if ( temporario.length < 2 ) continue;` em vez de deixar a exceção acontecer e pegá-la depois (mesmo porque, caso contrário, fica difícil diferenciar entre uma exceção ocorrida no seu código ou uma ocorrida nas funções que seu código chama - o que poderia mascarar um erro inesperado).

Comment: Não acho que seja o caso de fechar esta pergunta. Pode até faltar um pouco de contexto mas foi fácil responder. Se ele precisa de algo mais específico, ele poderá melhorar, mas a pergunta é viável por si só. O pessoal que vota por fila, precisa ler tudo antes de votar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Coloque o bloco `try`/`catch` dentro do `for`:

```
for (String f : filename) {
    try {
        String temporario[] = f.split("_");
        Date data = new Date(format.parse(temporario[1]).getTime());
        if (m.containsKey(temporario[0])) {
            if (m.get(temporario[0]).before(data)) {
                m.put(temporario[0], data);
            }
        } else {
            m.put(temporario[0], data);
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        // aqui você faz o que quiser
    }
}
```

Assim o `for` continuará rodando mesmo se uma de suas iterações resultar em uma exceção. Entretanto, conforme comentaram na sua pergunta, é bom você clarificar o que está tentando fazer para propormos uma melhor solução.

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro devo insistir que você não deva fazer isso. Não faz sentido deixar passar um erro de programação. Eu falo bastante sobre o assunto e você pode iniciar a leitura [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/101).

Segundo, não é fácil ajudar desta forma porque não sabemos o que fazer quando o erro ocorre. Dá até para tentar usar a imaginação mas ainda é complicado porque qualquer solução poderá ser errada.

Finalmente se realmente existe alguma razão para continuar funcionando apesar de ter um índice inválido, não deixe o índice ser acessado, ou seja, o previna o erro.

Você só deve capturar exceções que sejam inevitáveis por uma razão ou outra. Exceções não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo normal.

Se uma exceção ocorre e não deveria ocorrer, é erro de programação e ele deve ser corrigido. O máximo que você deve fazer nesse caso é deixar voltar ao início e lá capturar uma exceção, escrever em um *log* que o erro ocorreu para verificação. Tem várias técnicas para escrever no logo, podendo até mesmo alertar o desenvolvedor imediatamente em circunstâncias que a comunicação externa esteja funcionando.

Se a exceção ocorre e você sabe que é normal, que dá para contornar a situação sem um problema de [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), então deixe ela ocorrer, verifique a situação antes e evite o erro.

Vou tentar aqui uma solução do que eu acho que é o que você quer:

```
for (String f : filename) {
    String temporario[] = f.split("_");
    if (temporario.length > 1) {
        Date data = new Date(format.parse(temporario[1]).getTime());

        if (m.containsKey(temporario[0])) {
            if (m.get(temporario[0]).before(data)) {
                m.put(temporario[0], data);
            }
        } else {
            m.put(temporario[0], data);
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/ContinueAfterException.java).

Note que esta solução não me parece robusto. Provavelmente produzirá resultados indesejados se algo não estiver conforme. Mas só você sabe se isso é aceitável ou não.

Comment: Na parte que você fala que exceções só devem ser capturadas caso seja inevitável e que elas não devem ser usadas para controle de fluxo, acredito que existam diferentes "vertentes filosóficas" quanto a isso. É fato que Runtime Exceptions não devem ser tratadas mas exceções que estão mais para o lado das regras de negócio são muito usadas para que o código se pareça com uma descrição do fluxo normal seguida dos vários fluxos excepcionais, evitando que o código fique parecendo um emaranhado de ifs. Isso pode ser visto nas APIs do Java, como a parte de arquivos.

Comment: Claro que só porque está no JDK não significa que é bom design. Só exemplificando caso eu não tenha sido claro.