# Limpeza de memória do programa em uso

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Minha aplicação está acumulando memória, única coisa que ela faz, é isso a baixo.

Após 10-15 minutos, ele chega a consumir mais de 1,5GB de memória, e continua o consumo sem parar.

Executo um `Timer` a cada dois minutos a função dele é:

```
Private Sub postGrupo_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles postGrupo.Tick
    ProgressBarStatus.Value = ProgressBarStatus.Value + 1
    Try
        StartPostGrupos()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Sub StartPostGrupos()
Dim value As Integer = ProgressBarStatus.Value
    Select Case value
        Case 10
            If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Iniciar discussão") = True Then
                For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                    If element.GetAttribute("data-endpoint") = "/ajax/composerx/attachment/group/post/" Then
                        element.InvokeMember("click")
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Case 20
            If postImgGo = 1 Then
                If File.Exists(imgGroupsDir & imgGroupsName) Then
                    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                        If element.GetAttribute("data-endpoint") = "/ajax/composerx/attachment/media/chooser/" Then
                            element.InvokeMember("click")
                        End If
                    Next
                    selecionarIMG.Start()
                End If
            End If
        Case 50
            Dim FILE_NAME As String = "config/msgGroups.txt"
            If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
                Dim texto As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)

                Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
                For Each Elem As HtmlElement In Elems
                    If Elem.Name = "xhpc_message_text" Or Elem.Name = "xhpc_message" Then
                        Dim value2 As String = texto.ReadToEnd.Replace("[tituloGrupo]", WebBrowser1.DocumentTitle)
                        Dim value3 As String = value2.Replace("[codigoRandom]", CInt(Int((999999999 * Rnd()) + 1)))
                        Dim value4 As String = value3.Replace("[urlGrupo]", WebBrowser1.Url.ToString)
                        Dim value5 As String = value4.Replace("[dataAtual]", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                        Dim value6 As String = value5.Replace("[horaAtual]", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"))
                        'Elem.InnerHtml = value6
                        Elem.SetAttribute("value", value6)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next Elem
            End If
        Case 80
            For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
                If elem.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
                    If elem.InnerText = "Publicar" Then
                        elem.InvokeMember("click")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Case 85
            For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
                If element.GetAttribute("className") = "_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" Then
                    element.InvokeMember("click")
                End If
            Next
        Case 99
            If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Publicar") Then
                If Label22.Text = "-------------" Then
                    Label22.Text = 1
                Else
                    Label22.Text = Label22.Text + 1
                End If
            End If

            FlushMemory()
            ProgressBarStatus.Value = 0
            postGrupo.Stop()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu diria que 99% das vezes que alguém usa um *timer* não precisava dele. Um *timer* só deveria ser usado quando realmente precisa que algo seja executado a cada intervalo de tempo. Mas a maioria dos problemas que precisa que algo seja executado é dependente de algum evento específico, algo que aconteceu e nesse momento deveria chamar a aplicação que precisa fazer algo após o evento acontecer, mesmo que seja algo fora da aplicação. Em grande parte das vezes é possível ser notificado que o evento aconteceu mesmo em serviços externos à aplicação.

Não acho que este é o principal causador do problema mas fica a dica que a arquitetura da aplicação provavelmente já está errada aí.

## Exceção

Se você sentir uma dor no braço, o que você faz? Corta o braço? É isto que está fazendo no código.

A primeira coisa que precisa arrumar é parar de engolir exceções. Se uma exceção ocorre, trate dela. Ou conserte o erro de programação que causa ela, ou execute alguma ação que consiga se recuperar dela, mas jamais engula ela como fez aqui:

```
Try
    StartPostGrupos()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Você vai dizer que se tirar isto começará dar erros e a aplicação quebrará. Ótimo, aí você saberá onde deve começar consertar os erros que ela tem. Jogar os erros pra baixo do tapete só causa mais problemas.

Eu falo disto em diversas respostas aqui no site. Leia tudo. Vai seguindo os *links* para aprender a lidar com exceções da forma correta. Mesmo que não seja do VB.NET, a base é a mesma. Comece pelos *links* abaixo, mas não pare neles:

- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/101) (siga os *links* na página!)
- [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101)
- [Outras respostas interessantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D)

## Consumo de memória

Você manipula um objeto `WebBrowser1` que foi criado em outro lugar. Ele é de um tipo que consome bastante memória. Eu fico pensando se você não está deixando ele vivo tempo demais. E pior, se fica abandonando ele vivo e criando outras instâncias sempre que necessário. Não posso garantir mas se o padrão do resto do código for igual ao trecho mostrado tem possibilidade de estar fazendo isto sem perceber. Mas pode ser que não esteja. Que sorte, não?

`Dim texto As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)`. Onde está fechando este *stream*? Em lugar algum. E mesmo que estivesse, desta forma poderia haver um vazamento se uma exceção ocorresse. Estude o comando [`Using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para evitar estes vazamentos. Com ele você evita que eles ocorram mesmo se uma exceção ocorra.

```
Using texto As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    'faz tudo o que precisa com esse stream aqui
End Using
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Clear.vb).

## *Race condition*

O código `If File.Exists(imgGroupsDir & imgGroupsName) Then` não está causando o problema relatado na pergunta, mas tem um potencial de causar uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). O arquivo pode existir neste momento, mas logo depois ele pode deixar de existir e aí sua aplicação vai gerar um erro sem você saber porque. O correto é tentar acessar o arquivo e tratar o erro se acontecer algo. Se continuar fazendo coisas assim, uma hora terá problemas e não saberá nem o porquê.

## Outros pequenos grandes problemas

O código `If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Iniciar discussão") = True Then` não vai causar problemas mas comparar uma expressão booleana com `True` é desnecessário. Falo isto só para você aprender a entender melhor o que está usando e saber quando precisa usar algo ou não. Sem entender todo funcionamento da linguagem, das bibliotecas usadas e da sua aplicação fica difícil produzir um código que resolva algum problema de forma correta. Seria melhor se tivesse escrito `If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Iniciar discussão") Then`.

Nem vou entrar no mérito que isto não é adequado para fazer *parser* de HTML.

Aproveita e tenta padronizar os nomes de variáveis, fica mais fácil de ler e entender o código.

Esta barra de progresso está bem esquisita, mas deixa pra lá.

O código chama outros códigos e certamente tem outras partes rodando que também podem estar criando mais vazamentos de memória.

Em condições normais eu não me preocuparia com isto: `selecionarIMG.Start()`. Mas como este código está cheio de problemas, sei lá se isto está ficando ligado sem querer. Em nenhum lugar tem um `Stop()` nele. Sei lá que problema isto pode causar mas consumir memória em excesso é uma das possibilidades.

Tenho muito medo do que seja isto: `FlushMemory()`. Provavelmente isto está disparando o GC manualmente e causando mais problema que solução. Depois você pode explicar o que é isto, mas quase garanto que não deveria estar aí.

`postGrupo.Stop()` não deve estar causando vazamento mas algo solto assim também me dá medo. O problema é que isto parece *design* ruim e deve estar espalhado por toda aplicação.

Neste pequeno trecho já achei vários erros, imagine quantos outros devem existir no resto da aplicação. E talvez o erro crítico mesmo deve estar em outro trecho não mostrado. Por isso a pergunta foi fechada inicialmente, porque provavelmente só daria para resolver seu problema analisando todo seu código e refazendo sua aplicação inteira.

Eu nem falei que o código está usando eventos e isto pode causar vazamentos em algumas situações quando o publicador sobrevive mais tempo que o assinante. Pode ser que esteja certo. Vamos torcer.

Não sei se vi tudo o que pode estar causando vazamento neste trecho. Mas repito que isto é só a ponta do *iceberg*. Acho que já ajudou.

Comment: É realmente o que você escreveu é um ótimo comentário, e pouco tem oportunidade de ler algo desse gênero... em relação ao que você informou sobre WebBrowser, que está sempre em execução, após utilizar um comando, entrar em páginas, verificar páginas e etc, como faria para talvez limpar cache dele, ou não tem nada haver? obrigado!!!