# É possivel lançar um erro que desencadeia outros?

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

Segue um exemplo:

```
public class Teste
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        func1();
    }

    public static void func1()
    {
        try
        {
            func2();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error 1\n");
        }
    }

    public static void func2()
    {
        try
        {
            int x = 1 / 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error 2\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Error 2

É possível fazer com que assim que ocorrer o erro na `func2` ele printe `Error 2` e desencadeie esse erro para a `func1` printando `Error 1` como no exemplo de saída abaixo?

> Error 2
> Error 1

Comment: Uma dúvida, isso é só curiosidade ou você pretende implementar isso em algum lugar?

Comment: Pergunto porque eu vejo isso como uma péssima pratica, a exceção é pra ser usada quando algo inesperado acontece. O melhor é sempre procurar tratar todos os erros, ao inves de pilhar exceção em cima de outra.

Comment: Leitura relacionada: [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/28595)

Comment: Estou estudando DB, minha classe tem várias funções e todas elas tem tratamento de erro, porem em alguns casos uma função chama a outra e se der erro na ultima função haverá problemas em alguns objetos no final

Comment: Mesmo assim, esta forma vai te complicar futuramente, dependendo da complexidade. Da uma olhada na pergunta que linkei, o post é bem esclarecedor, vale a pena :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível, basta relançar a exceção:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func1();
    }

    public static void func1() {
        try {
            func2();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error 1");
        }
    }

    public static void func2() {
        try {
            int x = 1 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error 2");
            throw e; // <==================== relançou aqui
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QSZzhN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/luuvbqmu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/NestedException.java).

[Só espero que esteja capturando `Exception` como um teste rápido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101). Eu gosto de responder essas questões sobre exceções, mas sempre temo pelo uso. A maioria dos programadores abusam delas.

Veja se realmente tem que capturar a exceção e lançá-la novamente. Raramente isso é necessário. O que mais vejo é fazerem isso por erro. Tem caso que precisa tratar a exceção em mais de uma passo, mas não é tão comum assim. Na maioria dos casos é, ou trata tudo, ou deixa para outro local tratar.

Comment: Sim eu li [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21933/como-melhor-tratar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-java/21939#21939), foi apenas um teste rápido.