# Captura o que o usuário digita e grava em um .TXT

Tags: java, swing

Fiz um programinha em JFrame,  basicamente ele captura o que o usuário digita e grava em um txt, mas  quando vou ver o conteúdo do arquivo esta escrito, o seguinte “null”. O que pode estar acontecendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class testedabeta07 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   Scanner n;

           public testedabeta07() {

        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        panel1 = new java.awt.Panel();
        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        Jcampo2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Bconfirmar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Bsair = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Jcampo1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(360, 237));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        Jcampo2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        Jcampo2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Jcampo2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Jcampo2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 120, 240, -1));

        jLabel1.setText("Chegada");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 70, -1, -1));

        jLabel2.setText("Saída");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 120, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("HALKINGS");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 20, -1, -1));

        Bconfirmar.setText("Confirmar");
        Bconfirmar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BconfirmarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Bconfirmar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 160, -1, -1));

        Bsair.setText("Sair");
        Bsair.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BsairActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Bsair, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(190, 160, -1, -1));

        Jcampo1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Jcampo1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Jcampo1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(80, 70, 240, -1));

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(359, 249));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void BconfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
                     File Ponto = new File ("C:\\Users\\W\\Desktop\\Ponto\\funcionarios.txt");


  try{

  FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Ponto, true);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);

  bw.write("" +n);
  bw.newLine();

  bw.close();
  fw.close();

  }catch(IOException ex){
  }

    }                                          

    private void BsairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        System.exit(0);
    }                                     

    private void Jcampo1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       

    private void Jcampo2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new testedabeta07().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Bconfirmar;
    private javax.swing.JButton Bsair;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Jcampo1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Jcampo2;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private java.awt.Panel panel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Voce abre o arquivo para edição mas nao escreve nada, o que é para ser escrito e como é para ser escrito?

Comment: bom obrigado articulo por responder, basicamente ele deve escrever a chegada e a saída, o modo de escrita deve vir através do usuário !

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está trabalhando com interface gráfica, e não se usa a classe `Scanner` para capturar dados escrito pelo usuário neste caso. Se a intenção é capturar o que é escrito nos campos de textos, utilize `getText()` dos respectivos campos:

```
private void BconfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    File Ponto = new File("C:\\Temp\\funcionarios.txt");

    try {

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Ponto, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write(Jcampo1.getText() + " - " + Jcampo2.getText());
        bw.newLine();

        bw.close();
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}
```

Outra coisa, se não vai tratar a exceção, não adicione *catch* vazio, isso é um desperdício tremendo do recurso e ainda dificulta detectar problemas. Deixarem abaixo um post aqui mesmo no site com ótimas respostas sobre tratamento de exceções.

Fontes recomendadas para estudo:

- [Interfaces gráficas com Swing](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/interfaces-graficas-com-swing/#5-5-comecando-com-swing-mensagens)
- [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/28595)

Comment: Poxa vida, muito obrigado mesmo cara estou um tempinho tentando aqui e não estou conseguindo (agora foi), muito obrigado mesmo ! pode deixar que vou ver os conteúdos ! vlww

Comment: @R2D2 lembrando que se a resposta solucionou o problema voce pode marca-la com aceita, clicando no `v` ao lado dela, dessa forma ela fica refernciada como solução valida.