# Erro de compilação: "Resource leak" ao usar Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, scanner

Estou resolvendo uma questão do livro de Deitel questão 3.17, porém estou com um problema na classe principal (estou fazendo pelo Eclipse, no ambiente Linux).
O código está assim:

```java
public class HealthProfile{

    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String sexo;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int ano;
    private float altura;
    private float peso;

    public HealthProfile(String nome, String sobrenome, 
            String sexo, int dia, int mes, int ano, float altura,
            float peso)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome)
    {
        this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    }

    public String getSobrenome()
    {
        return sobrenome;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo)
    {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getSexo()
    {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setDia(int dia)
    {
        if ((dia >= 1) && (dia <= 31))
            this.dia = dia;
    }

    public int getDia()
    {
        return dia;
    }

    public void setMes(int mes)
    {
        if ((mes >= 1) && (mes <= 12))
            this.mes = mes;
    }

    public int getMes()
    {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setAno(int ano)
    {
        if (ano >= 1900)
            this.ano = ano;
    }

    public int getAno() 
    {
        return ano;
    }

    public void setAltura(float altura)
    {
        if (altura >= 100)
            this.altura = altura;
    }

    public float getAltura()
    {
        return altura;
    }

    public void setPeso(float peso)
    {
        if (peso >= 70)
            this.peso = peso;
    }

    public float getPeso()
    {
        return peso;
    }

    public int idadeEmAnos() 
    {
        return 2019 - getAno();
    }

    public int maximumFrequenciaCardiaca()
    {
        return 220 - idadeEmAnos();
    }

    public double MinFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo()
    {
        return 0.5 * maximumFrequenciaCardiaca();
    }

    public double MaxFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo()
    {
        return 0.85 * maximumFrequenciaCardiaca();
    }

    public float getIMC()
    {
        float IMC = getPeso() / (getAltura() * getAltura());
        return IMC;
    }
}
```

E a classe principal está assim:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main() {

        HealthProfile health = new HealthProfile(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Informe seu nome: ");
        String nome = input.nextLine();
        health.setNome(nome);

        System.out.println("Informe seu sobrenome: ");
        String sobrenome = input.nextLine();
        health.setSobrenome(sobrenome);

        System.out.println("Informe seu sexo: ");
        String sexo = input.nextLine();
        health.setSexo(sexo);

        System.out.println("Informe seu dia de nascimento: ");
        int dia = input.nextInt();
        health.setDia(dia);

        System.out.println("Informe seu mes de nascimento: ");
        int mes = input.nextInt();
        health.setMes(mes);

        System.out.println("Informe seu ano de nascimento: ");
        int ano = input.nextInt();
        health.setAno(ano);

        System.out.println("Informe sua altura: ");
        float altura = input.nextFloat();
        health.setAltura(altura);

        System.out.println("Informe seu peso: ");
        float peso = input.nextFloat();
        health.setPeso(peso);

        System.out.printf("%s ", health.getNome());
        System.out.printf("%s%n", health.getSobrenome());
        System.out.printf("%d anos", health.idadeEmAnos());
        System.out.printf("Sua frequencia máxima é %d%n", health.maximumFrequenciaCardiaca());
        System.out.println("Frequencia Cardiaca Alvo:");
        System.out.printf("A Minima frequencia alvo é : %.0f%n", health.MinFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo());
        System.out.printf("A Maxima frequencia alvo é : %.0f%n", health.MaxFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo());
    }
}
```

Gostaria de entender esse problema que está dando no eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Resource leak: 'input' is never closed  Principal.java
/ComputadorizacaoScannerSaude/src   line 9  Java Problem
```

Ele diz que esse problema está na linha 9 que é essa aqui:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
```

Na função principal.

E isso não está deixando eu compilar o programa.

---

Obs.:
Uma outra forma que eu implementei e não houve nenhum problema foi usando o `JOptionPane`:

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Principal{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dia, mes, ano;
        float altura, peso;

        String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: ");
        String sobrenome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sobrenome: ");
        String sexo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sexo: ");
        dia = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o dia do seu nascimento (em digitos)"));
        mes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o mês do nascimento (como antes)"));
        ano = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o ano do seu nascimento (como antes)"));
        altura = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Altura(em metros): "));
        peso = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Peso(em quilogramas): "));

        HealthProfile health = new HealthProfile(nome, sobrenome, sexo, dia, mes, ano, altura, peso);

        String message = String.format(
                "Nome:%s\nSobrenome:%s\nSexo:%s\nData de Nascimento:%d/%d/%d\nIdade em Anos:%d\nFrequencia Cardiaca Maxima:%d\nFrequencia Cardiaca Alvo:[%.2f;%.2f]\nIMC:%.2f",
                health.getNome(), health.getSobrenome(), health.getSexo(), health.getDia(), health.getMes(),
                health.getAno(), health.idadeEmAnos(), health.maximumFrequenciaCardiaca(), health.MinFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo(),
                health.MaxFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo(), health.getIMC());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como **regra geral**, é importante fechar tudo que você abriu, seja um [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), um arquivo ([`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)/[`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)), uma conexão com uma URL ou com um banco de dados, ou o que quer que seja que possa ser "aberto" e "fechado". É isso que o Eclipse está reclamando: você abriu o `Scanner`, mas em nenhum lugar ele é fechado. Então bastaria chamar o [método `close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) no final do código.

Apenas um detalhe, se você fizer assim:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// usa o Scanner ...

input.close();
```

Isso não garante que o método `close()` sempre será chamado. Se ocorrer algum erro no meio do caminho (por exemplo, o usuário digitou `abc` quando era esperado um número), é lançada uma exceção e o `close()` não é executado (na verdade qualquer exceção que ocorra no meio do caminho, mesmo que não tenha relação com o `Scanner`, provocará esta mesma situação). Para garantir a execução do `close()`, você pode usar um bloco `try` com `finally`:

```java
Scanner input = null;
try {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // usar o Scanner
} catch (Exception e) {
    // tratar os erros
} finally {
    if (input != null)
        input.close();
}
```

Com isso, o método `close()` é chamado, mesmo que ocorra algum erro no meio do caminho (sobre o `catch (Exception e)`, essa não é a melhor maneira de lidar com os erros, mas [esse já é um tópico à parte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052)).

Outra alternativa é usar a sintaxe de [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) (disponível a partir do Java 7):

```java
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // usar o Scanner
} catch (Exception e) {
    // tratar os erros
}
```

Nesse caso, o bloco *try-with-resources* já chama o método `close()` automaticamente ao seu final (mesmo que ocorra uma exceção dentro do bloco `try`).

---

#### Devo fechar `System.in`?

As soluções acima são mais gerais, podendo ser usadas com quaisquer recursos que devam ser fechados (arquivos, *streams* de dados, conexões de rede/banco de dados, etc). Especificamente no *try-with-resources*, qualquer classe que implemente [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) pode ser usada dentro da inicialização do `try`.

Mas falando especificamente do `System.in`, há alguns cuidados extras a se tomar. Quando você fecha o `Scanner`, o objeto encapsulado pelo mesmo também é fechado. No seu caso, o método `close()` acabará fechando o `System.in`, e com isso, ele não poderá mais ser usado pela sua aplicação. Exemplo:

```java
while (true) { // loop infinito
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("digite um número: ");
        System.out.println(input.nextInt());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break; // se der erro, sai do while
    }
}
```

Na primeira iteração do `while`, o `Scanner` lê um número. Logo em seguida (assumindo que um número foi corretamente digitado) este número é impresso, o bloco *try-with-resources* termina e o método `close()` do `Scanner` é chamado, fazendo com que `System.in` seja fechado. E na segunda iteração do `while`, é criado outro `Scanner` com o `System.in`, mas como este está fechado, dá erro na hora de ler o número (o erro ocorre antes mesmo que o usuário possa digitar algo):

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

E nesse ponto as opiniões divergem. Há quem diga que [nunca se deve fechar um `Scanner` que usa `System.in`](https://www.omnijava.com/2018/08/23/if-you-are-using-javas-scanner-class-for-keyboard-input-then-you-might-be-doing-it-wrong/), pois é a JVM que gerencia o `System.in` e você não deveria se preocupar com ele (["*quem abriu que feche*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286690/in-java-is-it-possible-to-re-open-system-in-after-closing-it#comment49989002_27286690)). Até porque [não é possível reabri-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286893).

Mas pesquisando na internet você também encontrará soluções que sugerem criar um `InputStream` cujo método `close()` não faz nada:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in){ public void close(){} });

// ou
public class MyInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public MyInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // não faz nada
    }
}

Scanner input = new Scanner(new MyInputStream(System.in));
```

Assim, você usa o `Scanner` normalmente, e chama o `close()` no final (ou usa o bloco *try-with-resources*), assim o Eclipse para de dar erro de compilação. Mas lembre-se que nesse caso o método `close()` apenas "finge" que está fechando o `System.in`, sem fechá-lo de fato.

Outra opção (que foi sugerida na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380096/112052)) é chamar o método `close()` no final do seu programa, garantindo que o `Scanner` - e também o `System.in` - só será fechado quando ninguém mais precisar dele. Mas nesse caso poderia ter um grande `try` com um bloco `finally` (ou um *try-with-resources*) em torno de todo o seu código, para garantir a execução do método mesmo que ocorra algum erro.

---

Você também pode ignorar o erro do Eclipse, "fingindo que não viu": basta ir nas configurações (*Java* -> *Compiler* -> *Errors/Warnings*) e setar a opção "Ignore" no item "Resource leak" (só que ele vai deixar de acusar o erro para outros recursos que devem ser fechados, como arquivos e conexões - mas se você garante que nunca vai esquecer de fechar nenhum recurso, vá em frente).

Outra opção é deixar esta opção como "Warning" (em vez de "Ignore"), assim o código compila (mas é mostrado um *warning* indicando que há um problema ali). Mas se quiser, dá para ignorar *warnings* específicos com a anotação [`java.lang.SuppressWarnings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Assim você ignora o *warning* do `System.in`, mas não os outros (caso haja arquivos/conexões sendo abertos em outros pontos do código, por exemplo).

---

No caso específico do `System.in`, não acho que é tão grave ignorar o erro e "esquecer" de fechá-lo (mas também não fará mal chamar `close()` no final do seu programa), mas para todos os demais recursos (arquivos, conexões, etc), é importante fechá-los sempre que não for precisar mais deles.

Eu diria que o `System.in` é a exceção desta regra (da mesma forma que [`System.out`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7457723) e `System.err`), por ser "especial" e gerenciado pela JVM, e neste caso específico, até daria para "ignorar" o erro do Eclipse. Mas fique à vontade para escolher qualquer uma das abordagens acima, desde que esteja ciente das implicações de cada uma.

Comment: Bem, eu diria que o que mais vale é a dica do link que você deu, em letras grandes, maiúsculas, negrito e vermelho: "***DO NOT CLOSE A SCANNER OBJECT INITIALIZED WITH System.in !***" - Na minha opinião, fechar o `System.in` ou um `Scanner` que o utilize é algo simplesmente muito idiota a se fazer. Enganar o método `close()` é apenas mais uma forma de fazer gambiarra. Se o eclipse não é capaz de identificar esse caso especial e dá uma *warning*, isso é problema do eclipse, e não do código, e portanto o `@SuppressWarnings` é mais que justificado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Concordo, eu também acho desnecessário fechar o `System.in` (e "fingir" que está fechando é de fato uma gambiarra). Mas optei por uma resposta mais "neutra", mostrando várias alternativas, e aí cada um tira suas próprias conclusões...

Answer (score 0):

No final da sua classe `main`, coloque a chamada `close()`.

```
input.close();
```

> As classes que utilizam recursos que não sejam de memória (no caso a
>   Scanner) devem fornecer maneiras de alocar / desalinhar explicitamente
>   esses recursos. Precisamos explicitamente chamar métodos close () para
>   desalocação de descritores de arquivos em finally {}, já que ele irá
>   executar se uma exceção é lançada ou não.
>   Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573084/why-we-should-i-close-a-java-util-scanner-variable

No caso, sua classe ficaria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

    public static void main() {

        HealthProfile health = new HealthProfile(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Informe seu nome: ");
        String nome = input.nextLine();
        health.setNome(nome);

        System.out.println("Informe seu sobrenome: ");
        String sobrenome = input.nextLine();
        health.setSobrenome(sobrenome);

        System.out.println("Informe seu sexo: ");
        String sexo = input.nextLine();
        health.setSexo(sexo);

        System.out.println("Informe seu dia de nascimento: ");
        int dia = input.nextInt();
        health.setDia(dia);

        System.out.println("Informe seu mes de nascimento: ");
        int mes = input.nextInt();
        health.setMes(mes);

        System.out.println("Informe seu ano de nascimento: ");
        int ano = input.nextInt();
        health.setAno(ano);

        System.out.println("Informe sua altura: ");
        float altura = input.nextFloat();
        health.setAltura(altura);

        System.out.println("Informe seu peso: ");
        float peso = input.nextFloat();
        health.setPeso(peso);

        System.out.printf("%s ", health.getNome());
        System.out.printf("%s%n", health.getSobrenome());
        System.out.printf("%d anos", health.idadeEmAnos());
        System.out.printf("Sua frequencia máxima é %d%n", health.maximumFrequenciaCardiaca());
        System.out.println("Frequencia Cardiaca Alvo:");
        System.out.printf("A Minima frequencia alvo é : %.0f%n", health.MinFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo());
        System.out.printf("A Maxima frequencia alvo é : %.0f%n", health.MaxFrequenciaCardiacaAlvo());

        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Parece que agora desapareceu os problemas. O eclipse não está mais sinalizando. Porém, quando eu vou dou um Ctrl + F11, aparece uma janela pop-up com essa mensagem:
"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches.".
Será que você saberia me dizer o que eu estou errando?

Comment: Bom, isso é problema no launch do eclipse. Procure o botão play  em verde e selecione a classe principal, deve funcionar. Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, marque a resposta como correta, para que outros possam se basear caso passem pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Cara, descobri o problema:
Está bem aqui:
   "public static void main()"
Observe o que estava faltando:
"public static void main(String [] args)"
Agora o programa rodou tranquilamente.