# Erro ao usar scanner.close()

Tags: java, scanner

Estou tentando executar este código em Java, usando o Eclipse.
O mesmo executa uma vez normal.
Ao tentar repetir a operação (escolhendo a opção 1) dá erro conforme imagem abaixo.

Se eu remover o `scanner.close()`; ele funciona normal, executando várias vezes.

Já achei alguma coisa sobre isso na internet, inclusive aqui, mas não entendi e nem consegui resolver o problema.

Alguém poderia ajudar esclarecendo por que dá o erro e como resolver o erro?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercicio{

    public int menu() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcao;
            System.out.println("ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO:");
            System.out.print("1-Imprime opção escolhida\n0-Sair\nOpção:");
            opcao = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close(); //ERRO AQUI. SE REMOVER ESTA LINHA, FUNCIONA.
        return opcao;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int opcao;
        Exercicio exercicio = new Exercicio();

        do {
            opcao = exercicio.menu();

            switch (opcao) {                

                case 0 : 
                break;

                case 1 : 
                    System.out.println("Você escolheu a opção 1.\n");
                break;

            }
        }while (opcao != 0);
    }
}
```

[image: imagem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque, ao fechar o `Scanner`, você também fecha o objeto que ele encapsula. No caso, você acaba fechando o `System.in`.

Só que o `System.in` é um recurso "especial", gerenciado pela JVM, e uma vez fechado, [ele não pode ser reaberto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286893).

Então o que acontece é:

- você chama o método `menu`, que cria o `Scanner`, lê a opção e fecha o `Scanner` (e consequentemente, fecha o `System.in`).
- na segunda vez que você chama o método `menu` (pois está dentro de um *loop*), você cria novamente o `Scanner`, passando o `System.in` (que agora está fechado)
- ao tentar ler os dados, dá erro porque o `System.in` está fechado

A solução é não fechar o `System.in` dentro do loop. Você poderia criar o `Scanner` fora do *loop* e passá-lo para o método `menu`, por exemplo. E usando um bloco [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052), nem precisa chamar `close()`, pois este é automaticamente chamado ao final:

```
// agora recebe o Scanner, em vez de criar toda hora
public int menu(Scanner scanner) {
    int opcao;
    System.out.println("ESCOLHA UMA OPÇÃO:");
    System.out.print("1-Imprime opção escolhida\n0-Sair\nOpção:");
    opcao = scanner.nextInt();
    return opcao;
}

// dentro do main
int opcao;
Exercicio exercicio = new Exercicio();
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {
        opcao = exercicio.menu(scanner);
        switch (opcao) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Você escolheu a opção 1.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (opcao != 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // tratar os erros
}
```

Sobre o fato de precisar fechar `System.in` ou não, eu falo em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052).

---

A sintaxe *try-with-resources* está disponível a partir do Java 7. Para versões anteriores, basta fazer:

```
int opcao;
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        opcao = menu(scanner);
        switch (opcao) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Você escolheu a opção 1.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (opcao != 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // tratar os erros
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```