# Alterar valor da super classe usando método da subclasse

Tags: java, herança

O método `sacar()` não funciona, não altera o valor do saldo.

Faço o depósito usando o método da super classe `ContaBancaria` direto, o `sacar()` é da classe `ContaPoupanca` que estende a super classe, mas digo, `super.getSaldo()` e mesmo assim o valor do saque não é descontado.

Se eu usar `this.getSaldo()` ou `super.getSaldo()` o *Eclipse* mostra que a referência é na classe `ContaBancaria`, mas a subtração não acontece quando eu executo.

```java
public class ContaBancaria {

    private double saldo;

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }
    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public void depositar(double valor) {
        this.saldo += valor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Saldo: " + saldo;
    }
}

public class ContaPoupanca extends ContaBancaria{

    private int diaRendimento;

    public int getDiaRendimento() {
        return diaRendimento;
    }
    public void setDiaRendimento(int diaRendimento) {
        this.diaRendimento = diaRendimento;
    }

    public void sacar(double valor) {
        if (valor < super.getSaldo()) {
            super.setSaldo(super.getSaldo() - valor);
            System.out.println("Saque realizado com sucesso!\nSaldo: " + super.getSaldo());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente.\nSaldo: " + super.getSaldo());
        }
    }

    public void calcularNovoSaldo(int dia) {
        if (dia >= 15) {
            System.out.println("Rendimento: " + (this.getSaldo() + 100));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sem rendimento. Saldo: " + this.getSaldo());
        }   
    }   
}
```

---

```java
public class Ex01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        ContaBancaria conta = new ContaBancaria();
        ContaPoupanca poupanca = new ContaPoupanca();

        boolean sair = false;

        while (!sair) {
            System.out.println("1. Depositar");
            System.out.println("2. Sacar");
            System.out.println("3. Saldo em conta");
            System.out.print("0. Sair\nDigite a opção: ");
            int opcao = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            if (opcao == 1) {
                System.out.print("Digite o valor do depósito: ");
                conta.setSaldo(scan.nextDouble());
            } else if (opcao == 2) {
                System.out.print("Digite o valor do saque: ");
                double valor = scan.nextDouble();
                poupanca.sacar(valor);
            } else if (opcao == 3) {
                System.out.println(conta);              
            } else if (opcao == 0) {
                System.out.println("Saindo.");
                sair = true;                
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        scan.close();
    }
```

Comment: Também não funciona.

O que eu acho que tá acontecendo é que ele tá tentando mexer com o saldo de ContaPoupanca, mas eu estou dizendo no código que é pra ele subtrair da ContaBancaria.

Comment: Testei aqui e está funcionando perfeitamente o seu código... Simplifiquei seu teste para ser totalmente java: `public static void main(String[] args) {
     ContaPoupanca c = new ContaPoupanca();
     c.depositar(100);
     c.sacar(10);
     System.out.println(c);
    }` e o resultado está correto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você criou duas contas diferentes:

```
ContaBancaria conta = new ContaBancaria();
ContaPoupanca poupanca = new ContaPoupanca();
```

Cada uma dessas variáveis é uma instância diferente, e cada uma possui o seu próprio saldo (que por *default*, [começa com o valor zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368176), já que você não especifica nenhum).

Depois você faz o depósito na variável `conta`, o que faz com que o saldo dela aumente. Mas na hora de fazer o saque, você tenta fazer na variável `poupanca`, cujo saldo sempre é zero, já que em nenhum momento você o modifica (você modificou o saldo da variável `conta`, mas da `poupanca` não).

---

Creio que você está fazendo uma pequena confusão.

A classe `ContaPoupanca` é uma subclasse de `ContaBancaria`, então ela herda os métodos `getSaldo()`, `setSaldo()` e `depositar()`. Ambas as classes possuem estes métodos: `ContaBancaria` possui porque ela que os definiu, e `ContaPoupanca` possui porque herdou de `ContaBancaria`.

Fazer `super.getSaldo()` serve para chamar o método da classe pai (que a classe filha também possui, via herança). **Ele não serve para chamar o método em outra variável que tenha o mesmo tipo do pai**.

E neste caso, a classe filha (`ContaPoupanca`) não sobrescreve o método `getSaldo()`, então o `super` é redundante. Você poderia escrever apenas `getSaldo()` (sem o `super`), que o Java verifica se o método existe na classe, e caso não exista, procura na classe pai. No fim, vai acabar encontrando o método em `ContaBancaria`.

Enfim, uma maneira simples de resolver o seu problema seria ter apenas uma conta:

```
// crie apenas uma conta
ContaPoupanca conta = new ContaPoupanca();

boolean sair = false;
while (!sair) {
    ... aqui não muda
    if (opcao == 1) {
        ... 
    } else if (opcao == 2) {
        System.out.print("Digite o valor do saque: ");
        double valor = scan.nextDouble();
        conta.sacar(valor); // sacar da conta
    } else if (opcao == 3) {
       ....
}
```

---

Como adendo, não é uma boa ideia ter um método `setSaldo()`, pois isso permite que se mude o saldo de uma conta com qualquer valor arbitrário (toda conta só deveria ter seu saldo alterado via saques e depósitos).

Uma opção para eliminar isso - e manter o seu modelo de classes - é mudar o `saldo` para `protected` (assim as subclasses podem acessá-lo também):

```
public class ContaBancaria {
    protected double saldo;

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void depositar(double valor) {
        this.saldo += valor;
    }
}
```

E na subclasse você pode usá-lo diretamente:

```
public class ContaPoupanca extends ContaBancaria {
    public void sacar(double valor) {
        if (valor <= this.saldo) { // <-- repare no <=
            this.saldo -= valor;
            System.out.println("Saque realizado com sucesso!\nSaldo: " + this.saldo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente.\nSaldo: " + this.saldo);
        }
    }

    public void calcularNovoSaldo(int dia) {
        if (dia >= 15) {
            System.out.println("Rendimento: " + (this.saldo + 100));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sem rendimento. Saldo: " + this.saldo);
        }
    }
}
```

Também troquei o `<` por `<=` no `if (valor <= this.saldo)`, para permitir que a pessoa saque todo o dinheiro.

Ainda há outros detalhes para melhorar, como verificar se o `nextDouble()` de fato retornou um número (ele lança uma exceção se não for digitado um número válido), e se atentar para o fato de que [não é necessário fechar o `System.in`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380696/112052) (veja uma discussão mais detalhada sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052)).

---

<sup>*Se você quer que uma conta bancária tenha também uma conta poupança atrelada, aí já é outra história. Seria o caso de mudar a modelagem, provavelmente [usando composição em vez de herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/112052). Não vou entrar neste mérito porque já foge do escopo da pergunta.*</sup>