# Retornar a condição inicial após um false

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programa que lê um nome, e caso seja respondido "Thanos", uma mensagem é apresentada e o programa acaba ali.

Porém, caso a resposta seja diferente, uma mensagem de que "você não é bem-vindo" é apresentada e logo em seguida pergunta se quer tentar novamente.

Até ai ficou tudo bem certinho, porém eu não sei como eu posso fazer para que, depois que a pessoa responda positivamente, a condição inicial da pergunta "Qual o seu nome" retorne.

Eu acredito que preciso fazer um laço mas não estou conseguindo pensar em nada. 
Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Qual o seu nome?");
    String t = s.nextLine();

    if(t.equalsIgnoreCase("Thanos")) {
        System.out.println("Bem-vindo, pode acabar com geral <3");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Você não é bem-vindo!");
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Quer tentar colocar novamente seu nome?");
        String n = x.nextLine();
        if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("Sim")) {
            return;
        }
        x.close();
    }
    s.close();      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, você precisa fazer um laço (nesse caso, usarei um `while`), e só interrompê-lo quando for digitada uma opção diferente de `"Sim"` (ou quando o nome digitado for `"Thanos"`, que é a outra condição que você disse que deve encerrar o programa).

Outro detalhe é que você não precisa criar duas instâncias de [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Isso só faria sentido se cada um estivesse lendo de um *input stream* diferente, mas como ambos estão lendo de [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), só é necessário criar um.

E **no caso específico** do `System.in`, não precisa fechá-lo também (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380696/112052)).

Enfim, o código ficaria assim:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Qual o seu nome?");
    if ("Thanos".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine())) {
        System.out.println("Bem-vindo, pode acabar com geral <3");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Você não é bem-vindo!\nQuer tentar colocar novamente seu nome?");
        if (! "Sim".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine())) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Eu crio um `Scanner` no início do programa e uso ele durante todo o *loop*. Como eu disse anteriormente, não há motivo nenhum para criar outro `Scanner` para ler do mesmo *stream* (no caso, do `System.in`). É redundante e desnecessário.

`while (true)` é um *loop* infinito, que só é interrompido pelo `break`. E o `break` só é chamado se o nome digitado for `"Thanos"`, **ou** se for digitado algo diferente de `"Sim"` na pergunta "quer tentar colocar novamente seu nome" - note que tem um `!` antes da chamada a `equalsIgnoreCase`, que é operador de negação (ou seja, esse `if` verifica se o que foi digitado não é igual a `"Sim"`).

Repare também que, se você só precisa verificar o retorno de [`scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--), e não vai usar esse valor para mais nada depois, nem precisa guardá-lo em uma variável. Basta passar o retorno diretamente para `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Mas se for usar variáveis, procure usar nomes mais significativos do que `t` ou `n`. Por exemplo, elas poderiam se chamar `nome` e `opcao`, ou algo assim, que remeta ao que de fato elas representam no código. Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [dar nomes mais significativos ajuda muito](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) na hora de programar.

---

Lembrando que o [método `equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) faz a comparação *case insensitive*, ou seja, sem diferenciar maiúsculas e minúsculas. Então o código entra no `if("Thanos".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine()))` se você digitar `"thanos"`, `"THAnos"`, `"thANos"`, etc. Se quiser que ele só considere `"Thanos"` (exatamente assim, com `T` maiúsculo e o restante minúsculo), basta trocar para [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). O mesmo vale para a comparação com `"Sim"`.

Comment: Agradeço imensamente a ajuda, vou continuar estudando mediante os pontos citados. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode estar utilizando um laço de repetição, eu apenas coloquei o `while (true)`, quando for falso ele finaliza.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean saida = true;
        while (saida) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Qual o seu nome?");
            String t = s.nextLine();
                if(t.equalsIgnoreCase("Thanos")) {
                    System.out.println("Bem-vindo, pode acabar com geral <3");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Você não é bem-vindo!");
                    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Quer tentar colocar novamente seu nome?");
                    String n = x.nextLine();
                        if(n.equalsIgnoreCase("Sim")) {
                            saida = true;
                        }  else {
                            saida = false;
                            s.close();
                            x.close();
                        }
                }
        }


    }
```