# Ignorar a primeira linha de um arquivo

Tags: java, java-8

Gostaria de saber como ignorar uma linha de um arquivo `.csv`, pois a primeira linha é uma espécie de título.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv"))) {
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            String[] files = line.split(",");

            int numero = Integer.parseInt(files[0]);
            double valor =  Double.parseDouble(files[1]);
            apartamentos.add(new Apartamento(numero, valor));

            System.out.println(line);

            line = br.readLine();
        }
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Acredito que se você está jogando as linhas em um array, logo após você gravar todas a linhas no array você pode fazer um shift para remover a primeira linha.

Answer (score 2):

Você até pode gravar todas as linhas do arquivo em um array, como foi dito [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416007/112052). Mas lembre-se que nesse caso o array terá todo o conteúdo do arquivo carregado em memória. No caso de arquivos muito grandes, isso pode inclusive causar um [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) (para arquivos pequenos, não faz diferença).

Se quer processar linha por linha, sem precisar carregar o arquivo todo em memória, pode usar isso:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {
    br.readLine(); // lê a primeira linha e não faz nada com ela

    // lê o restante das linhas
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // faz o que precisar com a linha
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Usei a sintaxe de [*try-with-resources*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/112052) (disponível a partir do Java 7), que já fecha automaticamente o arquivo. Não coloquei um bloco `catch` correspondente <strike>por preguiça</strike> para deixar o exemplo mais curto (mas procure sempre [tratar os erros da melhor forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052)).

Também especifiquei um [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) (o valor acima é só um exemplo, troque para o encoding no qual o arquivo está), pois se nenhum for especificado, será usado o encoding *default*, que pode não ser o mesmo do arquivo - e isso pode levar a [resultados inesperados](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14918188).

<sup>*Para mais informações sobre o que é um encoding, sugiro começar [por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).*</sup>

Outra alternativa é usar um [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv"), "ISO-8859-1")) {
    scanner.nextLine(); // ignora a primeira linha

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

---

A partir do Java 8, você pode usar as classes do [pacote `java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html), como indicado [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416824/112052). Só não esqueça de [fechar o arquivo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073306) também:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv");
try (Stream<String> linhas = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
    // skip(1) pula a primeira linha
    linhas.skip(1).forEach(linha -> {
        System.out.println(linha);
    });
}
```

[`Files.lines` não fecha automaticamente o arquivo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34072035), mas ao colocá-lo em um bloco *try-with-resources*, eu garanto o fechamento do mesmo. De modo geral, procure sempre fechar os recursos que você abriu ([exceto alguns casos especiais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052)).

Outro detalhe é que `Files.lines`, por *default*, [usa o *encoding* UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-), e se o arquivo não estiver neste *encoding*, será lançado um `MalformedInputException`. Por isso eu especifiquei um [`StandardCharsets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) (o valor acima é só um exemplo, troque para o encoding no qual o arquivo está).

Outra alternativa para o código anterior é usar um `Iterator`:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv");
try (Stream<String> linhas = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = linhas.iterator();
    iterator.next(); // ignora a primeira linha

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String linha = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(linha);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Java 8 você pode fazer assim:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\apartamentos.csv");
Files.lines(path).skip(1L).forEach(linha->{
   System.out.println(linha);
});
```

No `skip` você passa a quantidade de linhas que deseja pular.