# Ler números usando ponto como separador decimal

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um exercício no qual tenho que pegar o raio como valor de entrada e devolver a área do círculo como saída.

O código compila normal sem erros, porém na hora que vai imprimir o valor ele dá erro.

Usei a classe `Locale` para aceitar a entrada com ponto, ex: `"2.00"`. Se eu digito `2.00` de entrada o programa compila mas dá erro, se eu digito `2,00` (com vírgula) ou "2" como inteiro ele compila e imprime corretamente sem erros.

Mas a minha intenção é entrar com valores no padrão US (2.00) utilizando valores com ponto, como manda o padrão internacional e não com vírgula como padrão "BR".

```
package exercicio01;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class dois {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

        double r, area, pi = 3.14159;


        System.out.println("Digite o valor do raio:");
        r = sc.nextDouble();


        area = Math.pow(r, 2) * pi;

        System.out.printf("a área do raio  digitado é % .4f \n : ", area);

        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não adianta setar o *locale default* depois de criar o scanner, pois ele já foi criado com o locale que estava setado anteriormente.

Também não é uma boa opção mudar o *locale default* (`Locale.setDefault`), pois esta mudança é feita para toda a JVM, afetando todas as aplicações que estiverem rodando na mesma JVM.

Se quer que o scanner use um locale específico, basta fazer:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Desta forma ele vai ler os números usando o ponto como separador decimal, independente do *locale default* que estiver setado (e também elimina a necessidade de usar `Locale.setDefault`).

---

Outro detalhe é que você [não deve fechar o `System.in`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052). No caso de um exercício simples como esse, não faz diferença, mas de qualquer forma fica a dica.

Comment: então eu utilizei uma das dicas que você sugeriu, colocando para iniciar o locale antes do scanner, e já solucionou. No caso de fechar o System.in, é porque no curso ele ensinou assim, pelo menos por enquanto, mas vou fazer daqui pra frente como você sugeriu, pois vi que você tem boa experiência.