# Como somar valores de um array

Tags: java, array

Guardando valores em array mas não consigo efetuar a soma dos valores.

```
package primeiro;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testes {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ArrayList<String> nomeLista = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> valorLista = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            /*System.out.println("Digite o " + i + "º " + "nome:");
            String nome1 = scanner.nextLine();
            nomeLista.add(nome1);*/
            System.out.println("Digite " + i + " valor:");
            String valorLendo = scanner.nextLine();
            valorLista.add(valorLendo);

        }

        //System.out.println(nomeLista);    
        System.out.println("Valor: " + valorLista);

        }

    }
```

Comment: você pode usar a String.Join(" " ,valorLista); - tem um post com uma duvida semelhante https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433540/string-join-list-and-items/42433722

Comment: usei o método mas eles está concatenando como string, não consigo efetuar a soma dos valores. (1+2+3=6 e não 1,2,3)

Answer (score 2):

Se você só quer guardar números, por que criou um `ArrayList` de `String`?

Se você cria uma lista de `String`, para somar você terá que converter as `String`'s em números, e caso alguma não seja (por exemplo, se o usuário digitar `xyz`), o que você fará? Ignora, dá erro? Não seria melhor já tratar isso na entrada, e assim garantir que a lista só tem números?

Use o tipo certo para o que você quer - no caso, poderia ser um `Integer`, se for somente números inteiros, por exemplo:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite o " + i + "º valor: ");
    numeros.add(scanner.nextInt()); // ler o dado como um número inteiro
}

int soma = 0;
for (Integer n : numeros) {
    soma += n.intValue();
}
System.out.println("A soma é " + soma);
```

Provavelmente alguém vai sugerir usar *streams* para somar:

```
int soma = numeros.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();

// ou
int soma = numeros.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

Mas já digo que para esse caso é um exagero (sem contar que [*streams* são mais lentas que um *loop* simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052)).

O código acima não faz tratamento de erros, caso se digite algo que não é um número. Uma alternativa é ler o dado como `String` e tentar converter para número:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Digite o " + i + "º valor: ");
            numeros.add(Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()));
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Você não digitou um número inteiro");
        }
    }
}
```

Lendo com `nextLine` evita algumas armadilhas, caso o usuário digite somente <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, por exemplo, entre outros problemas que podem ocorrer ao usar `nextInt` e a entrada não for o valor esperado ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052) para mais detalhes).

---

Outro detalhe é que você usou [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), que apesar do nome, não é um array (não o array propriamente dito [conforme definido pela linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html)), e sim uma [lista](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) (uma das muitas classes que compõem o [*Collections Framework*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)).

A vantagem da lista é que seu tamanho é flexível, e você pode ir adicionando elementos sem se preocupar, pois internamente ela aloca mais espaço caso necessário. Já arrays tem tamanho fixo, e como no seu caso você está usando um tamanho fixo, o código poderia usar arrays também:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numeros[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "º valor: ");
            numeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Você não digitou um número inteiro");
        }
    }
}
int soma = 0;
for (int n : numeros) {
    soma += n;
}
System.out.println("A soma é " + soma);
```

---

Por fim, se quiser que tenha números com casas decimais, basta trocar `int` para `double` e `Integer.parseInt` para `Double.parseDouble`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double numeros[] = new double[3];
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Digite o " + (i + 1) + "º valor: ");
            numeros[i] = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Você não digitou um número válido");
        }
    }
}
double soma = 0;
for (double n : numeros) {
    soma += n;
}
System.out.println("A soma é " + soma);
```

Lembrando que os números devem ser digitados levando-se em conta o separador decimal do *locale* padrão da JVM (ou seja, pode ser `2.5` ou `2,5` dependendo da configuração, [embora dê para mudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427964/112052) isso).

---

Lembrando que você também pode fazer a soma no mesmo *loop* que lê os números, [como fez a outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/441335/112052). Nos códigos acima estou assumindo que já existe uma lista (não importando de onde ela veio) e você quer somar seus elementos (pois se for só para ler os números e exibir a soma, e nada mais, é melhor fazer tudo no mesmo *loop*).

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o que quis dizer mas supondo que queira somar os valores do array:

```java
package primeiro;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testes {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ArrayList<String> nomeLista = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> valorLista = new ArrayList<String>();
        int soma = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            /*System.out.println("Digite o " + i + "º " + "nome:");
            String nome1 = scanner.nextLine();
            nomeLista.add(nome1);*/
            System.out.println("Digite " + i + " valor:");
            String valorLendo = scanner.nextLine();
            valorLista.add(valorLendo);
            soma += Integer.parseInt(valorLendo);

        }

        //System.out.println(nomeLista);    
        System.out.println("Valor: " + valorLista);
        System.out.println("ValorTotal " + soma);

    }

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.